# C++ Double Address Operator? (&&)

Tags: c++, stl, operator-keyword, memory-address

I'm reading STL source code and I have no idea what `&&` address operator is supposed to do. Here is a code example from `stl_vector.h`:

```
vector&
operator=(vector&& __x) // <-- Note double ampersands here
{
    // NB: DR 675.
    this->clear();
    this->swap(__x); 
    return *this;
}
```

Does "Address of Address" make any sense? Why does it have two address operators instead of just one?

Comment: Maybe it's an address of a reference.

Comment: @Gabe; it's a declaration so that would make it a reference to a reference, which doesn't make any sense as the reference itself can't be modified. The address-of can only be used in the code, not when declaring (a parameter as in this case, or otherwise). Never seen anything like this though.

Comment: Even if there was only a single `&`, it would have nothing to do with the address-of operator, but instead signify that `__x` is a reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does T&& (double ampersand) mean in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11)

Comment: The duplicate should be the last one, this question was asked 4 months before.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

This is [C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info) code.  In C++11, the `&&` token can be used to mean an "rvalue reference".

Comment: really? this is a nice explanation! X means Y. But what the heck Y means? oops! Not explained!

Answer (score 345):

`&&` is new in C++11. `int&& a` means "a" is an r-value reference. `&&` is normally only used to declare a parameter of a function. And it *only* takes a r-value expression. If you don't know what an r-value is, the simple explanation is that it doesn't have a memory address. E.g. the number 6, and character 'v' are both r-values. `int a`, a is an l-value, however `(a+2)` is an r-value. For example:

```
void foo(int&& a)
{
    //Some magical code...
}

int main()
{
    int b;
    foo(b); //Error. An rValue reference cannot be pointed to a lValue.
    foo(5); //Compiles with no error.
    foo(b+3); //Compiles with no error.

    int&& c = b; //Error. An rValue reference cannot be pointed to a lValue.
    int&& d = 5; //Compiles with no error.
}
```

Hope that is informative.

Comment: The only example I wish you'd add is how this works with std::move.
Showing what would happen with `int&& c = std::move( b );`, etc.

Comment: It looks like [Sravani S](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/answers/Sravani-S) blatantly plagiarized from you for TutorialsPoint on 15 Feb. 2018, [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-double-address-operator-and-and-in-Cplusplus).

Comment: I just sent TutorialsPoint [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPEYt.png). The article, as plagiarized by them, [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n40nr.png).

Comment: if `foo(b); ` is error, how vector.push_back works in c++11??

Comment: There is another overload `void push_back (const value_type& val);` that takes an l-value.

Comment: The way I remember l- and r-values is by thinking about the left- and right-side arguments to an assignment operator. In `lefty = righty`, lefty needs to be an l-value and righty is used as an r-value.

Comment: It's 2022 and TutorialsPoint still shows the plagiarized content.

Comment: @GabrielStaples it's 2023 and TutorialsPoint STILL shows the plagiarized content. What a disgrace

Answer (score 111):

`&&` is new in C++11, and it signifies that the function accepts an [RValue-Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors) -- that is, a reference to an argument that is about to be destroyed.

Answer (score 42):

As other answers have mentioned, the `&&` token in this context is new to C++0x (the next C++ standard) and represent an "rvalue reference".

Rvalue references are one of the more important new things in the upcoming standard; they enable support for 'move' semantics on objects and permit perfect forwarding of function calls.

It's a rather complex topic - one of the best introductions (that's not merely cursory) is an article by Stephan T. Lavavej, ["Rvalue References: C++0x Features in VC10, Part 2"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/rvalue-references-c0x-features-in-vc10-part-2/)

Note that the article is still quite heavy reading, but well worthwhile.  And even though it's on a Microsoft VC++ Blog, all (or nearly all) the information is applicable to any C++0x compiler.

Comment: The `&&` token itself is not new; its meaning in declarations is.  But you knew that.

Comment: It's new in this context. But it is highly traditional for C/C++ to overload its tokens to have different meaning in different contexts.

Comment: @aschkleper - of course...  the logical-and operator didn't even enter my mind. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Broken Link... So answer is worthless.

Comment: http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

Answer (score 6):

I believe that is is a move operator. `operator=` is the assignment operator, say `vector x = vector y`. The `clear()` function call sounds like as if it is deleting the contents of the vector to prevent a memory leak. The operator returns a pointer to the new vector.

This way,

```
std::vector<int> a(100, 10);
std::vector<int> b = a;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << b[i] << ' ';
}
```

Even though we gave vector a values, vector b has the values. It's the magic of the `operator=()`!

[MSDN -- How to create a move constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx)

Comment: What is your answer adding to this 4 year old question, which hasn't already been covered in the other answers?

Comment: I didn't notice any answer like this so I decided to add on. I came across this question by googling just today.

Answer (score 3):

I believe && is for **move semantics**. It allows something to give up its memory to something else that needs it, avoiding the need for copying.

Move constructor
E.g.

```
String(String&& other) noexcept
{
//...
}
```

20/02/24:
I felt that the && question was relevant to move constructors and is missing explainations on lvalues, rvalues, move semantics and std::move.

I've included a decent video from the Cherno that explains the && better than StackOverflow comments.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbYknr-HPYE