# Writing a source function in c++11 properly

Tags: c++, c++11

My head hurts: I've read so many blogs about C++11x's move semantics that my brain's gone mushy, so please can someone give me a short-but-sweet guide on how to make the following code work efficiently? Given a class `Foo`, I want to be able to write functions that return `Foo` objects in different states (sometimes called source functions), and to do this as efficiently as possible.

```
class Foo {
    // Some methods and members
};

Foo getFirstFoo() {
    Foo foo;
    // Do some things to foo
    return foo;
} 

Foo getSecondFoo() {
    Foo foo;
    // Do some different things to foo
    return foo;
} 

int main() {
    Foo f = getFoo();
    // use f ...
    f = getSecondFoo();
    // use f ...
    return 0;
}
```

I don't want to modify `Foo` much, and the idea is to allow all sorts of `Foo` objects to be created through a variety of non-member source functions, so adding ever more constructors would be missing the point.

In C++03 my options would be to wrap the returned object in an `auto_ptr` (a big downside being that the recipient code needs to know to handle a smart pointer), or to cross my fingers and hope that some sort of optimization might take place (likely for the first line in `main`, less so for the second). C++11x seems to provide something better through move semantics, but how would I take advantage of these? So I need to change the way objects are returns in the source functions, or add some move constructor to `Foo`, or both?

Comment: Have a look at this: [Cpp-Next: Want speed pas by value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already optimal<sup>1</sup>, provided that move constructors are generated<sup>2</sup>:

```
class Foo {
    public: 
        Foo(Foo&&) = default;
        Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = default;
};
```

Returned values are rvalue references by default.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well.... provided that your class Foo benefits from move construction at all. Remember, ***move* is an optimization of *copy***. Some copies cannot be improved! E.g, unsuited:

```
struct Foo  { int data; };
struct Foo2 { int data[5<<10]; };
```

well suited:

```
struct Foo3 { std::vector<std::string> data; };
```

See [Move semantics - what it's all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815685/move-semantics-what-its-all-about) for a more general background on things like this.

---

<sup>2</sup> Not all compilers do support that yet (even if they *do* implement *rvalue references*), so you might have to write the

- move constructor
- move assignment

Comment: I reckon that's what I'm after. Thanks. I'm not too worried about the compiler support - GCC is fairly up to date in this regard, and the others will catch up be the time I finally complete my project...

Comment: It is also worth nothing that the compiler-generated constructors and operators are disabled when you do certain things (like define a constructor of your own).  Therefore, if you've done any of those things, you'll need to explicitly declare the otherwise normally-generated methods.  You can use `= default` in those cases to get the default implementation, as indicated in the answer.