# How do I pass a unique_ptr argument to a constructor or a function?

Tags: c++, arguments, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm new to move semantics in C++11 and I don't know very well how to handle `unique_ptr` parameters in constructors or functions. Consider this class referencing itself:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class Base
{
  public:

    typedef unique_ptr<Base> UPtr;

    Base(){}
    Base(Base::UPtr n):next(std::move(n)){}

    virtual ~Base(){}

    void setNext(Base::UPtr n)
    {
      next = std::move(n);
    }

  protected :

    Base::UPtr next;

};
```

Is this how I should write functions taking `unique_ptr` arguments?

And do I need to use `std::move` in the calling code?

```cpp
Base::UPtr b1;
Base::UPtr b2(new Base());

b1->setNext(b2); //should I write b1->setNext(std::move(b2)); instead?
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/46642 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-mean-in-c0x

Comment: Isn't it a segmentation fault as you are calling b1->setNext on a empty pointer?

Answer (score 1001, accepted):

Here are the possible ways to take a unique pointer as an argument, as well as their associated meaning.

#### (A) By Value

```
Base(std::unique_ptr<Base> n)
  : next(std::move(n)) {}
```

In order for the user to call this, they must do one of the following:

```
Base newBase(std::move(nextBase));
Base fromTemp(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Base(...));
```

To take a unique pointer by value means that you are *transferring* ownership of the pointer to the function/object/etc in question. After `newBase` is constructed, `nextBase` is guaranteed to be *empty*. You don't own the object, and you don't even have a pointer to it anymore. It's gone.

This is ensured because we take the parameter by value. `std::move` doesn't actually *move* anything; it's just a fancy cast. `std::move(nextBase)` returns a `Base&&` that is an r-value reference to `nextBase`. That's all it does.

Because `Base::Base(std::unique_ptr<Base> n)` takes its argument by value rather than by r-value reference, C++ will automatically construct a temporary for us. It creates a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` from the `Base&&` that we gave the function via `std::move(nextBase)`. It is the construction of this temporary that actually *moves* the value from `nextBase` into the function argument `n`.

#### (B) By non-const l-value reference

```
Base(std::unique_ptr<Base> &n)
  : next(std::move(n)) {}
```

This has to be called on an actual l-value (a named variable). It cannot be called with a temporary like this:

```
Base newBase(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Base)); //Illegal in this case.
```

The meaning of this is the same as the meaning of any other use of non-const references: the function may *or may not* claim ownership of the pointer. Given this code:

```
Base newBase(nextBase);
```

There is no guarantee that `nextBase` is empty. It *may* be empty; it may not. It really depends on what `Base::Base(std::unique_ptr<Base> &n)` wants to do. Because of that, it's not very evident just from the function signature what's going to happen; you have to read the implementation (or associated documentation).

Because of that, I wouldn't suggest this as an interface.

#### (C) By const l-value reference

```
Base(std::unique_ptr<Base> const &n);
```

I don't show an implementation, because you *cannot* move from a `const&`. By passing a `const&`, you are saying that the function can access the `Base` via the pointer, but it cannot *store* it anywhere. It cannot claim ownership of it.

This can be useful. Not necessarily for your specific case, but it's always good to be able to hand someone a pointer and know that they *cannot* (without breaking rules of C++, like no casting away `const`) claim ownership of it. They can't store it. They can pass it to others, but those others have to abide by the same rules.

#### (D) By r-value reference

```
Base(std::unique_ptr<Base> &&n)
  : next(std::move(n)) {}
```

This is more or less identical to the "by non-const l-value reference" case. The differences are two things.

1. You *can* pass a temporary:

   ```
   Base newBase(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Base)); //legal now..
   ```
2. You *must* use `std::move` when passing non-temporary arguments.

The latter is really the problem. If you see this line:

```
Base newBase(std::move(nextBase));
```

You have a reasonable expectation that, after this line completes, `nextBase` should be empty. It should have been moved from. After all, you have that `std::move` sitting there, telling you that movement has occurred.

The problem is that it hasn't. It is not *guaranteed* to have been moved from. It *may* have been moved from, but you will only know by looking at the source code. You cannot tell just from the function signature.

#### Recommendations

- **(A) By Value:** If you mean for a function to claim *ownership* of a `unique_ptr`, take it by value.
- **(C) By const l-value reference:** If you mean for a function to simply use the `unique_ptr` for the duration of that function's execution, take it by `const&`. Alternatively, pass a `&` or `const&` to the actual type pointed to, rather than using a `unique_ptr`.
- **(D) By r-value reference:** If a function may or may not claim ownership (depending on internal code paths), then take it by `&&`. But I strongly advise against doing this whenever possible.

#### How to manipulate unique_ptr

You cannot copy a `unique_ptr`. You can only move it. The proper way to do this is with the `std::move` standard library function.

If you take a `unique_ptr` by value, you can move from it freely. But movement doesn't actually happen because of `std::move`. Take the following statement:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> newPtr(std::move(oldPtr));
```

This is really two statements:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> &&temporary = std::move(oldPtr);
std::unique_ptr<Base> newPtr(temporary);
```

(note: The above code does not technically compile, since non-temporary r-value references are not actually r-values. It is here for demo purposes only).

The `temporary` is just an r-value reference to `oldPtr`. It is in the *constructor* of `newPtr` where the movement happens. `unique_ptr`'s move constructor (a constructor that takes a `&&` to itself) is what does the actual movement.

If you have a `unique_ptr` value and you want to store it somewhere, you *must* use `std::move` to do the storage.

Comment: You should make it clear that he last two statements are not real compilable C++ (because of the named temporary).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'm fairly sure that compiles. Just like with `const&`, you can use a `&&` to extend the lifetime of a temporary. Plus, `std::move` doesn't create a temporary; it just returns a `&&` of its argument.

Comment: @Nicol: but `std::move` doesn't name its return value. Remember that named rvalue references are lvalues. http://www.ideone.com/VlEM3

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Fair enough.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your explanation about when and why I should use `const&` for my `unique_ptr` cleared my doubts in one tricky case. I have read many various answers here on stackoverflow, but yours was the easiest to understand and get me to my "aha" moment.

Comment: I basicaly agree with this answer, but have some remarks. (1) I don't think there is a valid use case for passing reference to const lvalue: everything the callee could do with that, it can do with reference to const (bare) pointer too, or even better the pointer itself [and it's none of its business to know ownership is held throught a `unique_ptr`; maybe some other callers need the same functionality but are holding a `shared_ptr` instead] (2) call by lvalue reference could be useful if called function _modifies_ the pointer, e.g., adding or removing (list-owned) nodes from a linked list.

Comment: ...(3) Although your argument favoring passing by value over passing by rvalue reference makes sense, I think that the standard itself always passes `unique_ptr` values by rvalue reference (for instance when transforming them into `shared_ptr`). The rationale for that might be that it is slightly more efficient (no moving to temporary pointers is done) while it gives the exact same rights to the caller (may pass rvalues, or lvalues wrapped in `std::move`, but not naked lvalues).

Comment: Just to repeat what Marc said, and quoting [Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/):
"Don’t use a const unique_ptr& as a parameter; use widget* instead"

Comment: We've discovered [a problem with by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28336411/103167) -- the move takes place during argument initialization, which is unordered with respect to other argument evaluations (except in an initializer_list, of course).  Whereas accepting an rvalue reference strongly orders the move to occur after the function call, and therefore after evaluation of other arguments.  So accepting rvalue reference should be preferred whenever ownership will be taken.

Comment: Passing `unique_ptr` by value only works due to copy constructor elision (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451212/passing-temporary-object-as-parameter-by-value-is-copy-constructor-called) right? Because `unique_ptr` has no copy constructor...

Comment: In the above answer, is `Base(std::unique_ptr<Base> const &n);` equivalent to `Base(const std::unique_ptr<Base> &n);`?

Comment: @kevinarpe Yes, the placement of `const` doesn't matter there.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen There is a valid use-case: As a facade for easier using of the function accepting a raw (observing) pointer when all you have is a smart-pointer.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Please don't argue with some remark someone made from 1.5 years ago. Not unless it's genuinely important. And no, that's not a valid use case; if you have a smart pointer, you also can get a raw pointer. So there's no burden on the user to pass `ptr.get()` instead of just `ptr`.

Comment: For faster writing you can use std::make_unique eg. Base fromTemp(std::make_unique<Base>(...);

C++14

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Comment: @BenVoigt: I must misunderstand the problem you have in mind, then.  What exactly do you not want to happen before every parameter is initialized?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I’ll grant that this is subtle.  If you don’t want lvalue/rvalue overloads, sometimes you want by-value because it lets a function be `noexcept`.  It can also avoid accidentally prolonging the life of resources you expect to have been moved out.  But you’re right that an rvalue reference lets the function control when/whether it moves, and forces the caller to explicitly choose move or copy for their lvalue.  I’ll strike my comment, since it was based on a misunderstanding of the importance of ordering in your concern.

Comment: Shouldn't the advice be to use an RValue parameter when your intention is to take ownership? Its not that it shouldnt be used. Similar to passing by non const ref. This should be done only when your intention is to modify the object. otherwise use const ref.

Comment: Can anyone explain what's the difference between (A) and (D)?
Because in both cases you *must* use `std::move` when passing non-temporary arguments.

Comment: How do you extend the class to have a copy constructor or assignment operator?

`Base another_base = base;`
or
`Base another_base(base);`

Comment: @mercury0114: If it's storing a `unique_ptr`, you generally don't. I mean, you could heap-allocate a new object in the internal one and copy the one from the given object. But generally speaking, if you're storing a `unique_ptr`, then your type is move-only.

Comment: I'm asking, because I have a constructor `Class(int x, std::unique_ptr<AnotherClass>&& y): x_(x), y_(std::move(y))`

where `y_` is a private member of Class of type `const std::unique_ptr<AnotherClass>`

The code doesn't compile, if try to create an object as follows: `Class c(other_c)`, compiler gives an error message: "copy constructor of 'Class' is implicitly deleted because field 'y_' has a deleted copy constructor"

but if I change y_ to `const std::shared_ptr<AnotherClass>`, then everything works.
So is there a way to make it work with unique_ptr rather than shared_ptr in my case?

Comment: @mercury0114: A type which holds a non-copyable class is itself non-copyable. Not unless you do what I suggested.

Answer (score 73):

Let me try to state the different viable modes of passing pointers around to objects whose memory is managed by an instance of the `std::unique_ptr` class template; it also applies to the the older `std::auto_ptr` class template (which I believe allows all uses that unique pointer does, but for which in addition modifiable lvalues will be accepted where rvalues are expected, without having to invoke `std::move`), and to some extent also to `std::shared_ptr`.

As a concrete example for the discussion I will consider the following simple list type

```
struct node;
typedef std::unique_ptr<node> list;
struct node { int entry; list next; }
```

Instances of such list (which cannot be allowed to share parts with other instances or be circular) are entirely owned by whoever holds the initial `list` pointer. If client code knows that the list it stores will never be empty, it may also choose to store the first `node` directly rather than a `list`.
No destructor for `node` needs to be defined: since the destructors for its fields are automatically called, the whole list will be recursively deleted by the smart pointer destructor once the lifetime of initial pointer or node ends.

This recursive type gives the occasion to discuss some cases that are less visible in the case of a smart pointer to plain data. Also the functions themselves occasionally provide  (recursively) an example of client code as well. The typedef for `list` is of course biased towards `unique_ptr`, but the definition could be changed to use `auto_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead without much need to change to what is said below (notably concerning exception safety being assured without the need to write destructors).

## Modes of passing smart pointers around

### Mode 0: pass a pointer or reference argument instead of a smart pointer

If your function is not concerned with ownership, this is the preferred method: don't make it take a smart pointer at all. In this case your function does not need to worry *who* owns the object pointed to, or by what means that ownership is managed, so passing a raw pointer is both perfectly safe, and the most flexible form, since regardless of ownership a client can always produce a raw pointer (either by calling the `get` method or from the address-of operator `&`).

For instance the function to compute the length of such list, should not be give a `list` argument, but a raw pointer:

```
size_t length(const node* p)
{ size_t l=0; for ( ; p!=nullptr; p=p->next.get()) ++l; return l; }
```

A client that holds a variable `list head` can call this function as `length(head.get())`, 
while a client that has chosen instead to store a `node n` representing a non-empty list can call `length(&n)`.

If the pointer is guaranteed to be non null (which is not the case here since lists may be empty) one might prefer to pass a reference rather than a pointer. It might be a pointer/reference to non-`const` if the function needs to update the contents of the node(s), without adding or removing any of them (the latter would involve ownership).

An interesting case that falls in the mode 0 category is making a (deep) copy of the list; while a function doing this must of course transfer ownership of the copy it creates, it is not concerned with the ownership of the list it is copying. So it could be defined as follows:

```
list copy(const node* p)
{ return list( p==nullptr ? nullptr : new node{p->entry,copy(p->next.get())} ); }
```

This code merits a close look, both for the question as to why it compiles at all (the result of the recursive call to `copy` in the initialiser list binds to the rvalue reference argument in the move constructor of `unique_ptr<node>`, a.k.a. `list`, when initialising the `next` field of the generated `node`), and for the question as to why it is exception-safe (if during the recursive allocation process memory runs out and some call of `new` throws `std::bad_alloc`, then at that time a pointer to the partly constructed list is held anonymously in a temporary of type `list` created for the initialiser list, and its destructor will clean up that partial list). By the way one should resist the temptation to replace (as I initially did) the second `nullptr` by `p`, which after all is known to be null at that point: one cannot construct a smart pointer from a (raw) pointer *to constant*, even when it is known to be null.

### Mode 1: pass a smart pointer by value

A function that takes a smart pointer value as argument takes possession of the object pointed to right away: the smart pointer that the caller held (whether in a named variable or an anonymous temporary) is copied into the argument value at function entrance and the caller's pointer has become null (in the case of a temporary the copy might have been elided, but in any case the caller has lost access to the pointed to object). I would like to call this mode **call by cash**: caller pays up front for the service called, and can have no illusions about ownership after the call. To make this clear, the language rules require the caller to wrap the argument in `std::move` if the smart pointer is held in a variable (technically, if the argument is an lvalue); in this case (but not for mode 3 below) this function does what its name suggests, namely move the value from the variable to a temporary, leaving the variable null.

For cases where the called function unconditionally takes ownership of (pilfers) the pointed-to object, this mode used with `std::unique_ptr` or `std::auto_ptr` is a good way of passing a pointer together with its ownership, which avoids any risk of memory leaks. Nonetheless I think that there are only very few situations where mode 3 below is not to be preferred (ever so slightly) over mode 1. For this reason I shall provide no usage examples of this mode. (But see the `reversed` example of mode 3 below, where it is remarked that mode 1 would do at least as well.) If the function takes more arguments than just this pointer, it may happen that there is in addition a [technical reason to avoid mode 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28336207/1436796) (with `std::unique_ptr` or `std::auto_ptr`): since an actual move operation takes place while passing a pointer variable `p` by the expression `std::move(p)`, it cannot be assumed that `p` holds a useful value while evaluating the other arguments (the order of evaluation being unspecified), which could lead to subtle errors; by contrast, using mode 3 assures that no move from `p` takes place before the function call, so other arguments can safely access a value through `p`.

When used with `std::shared_ptr`, this mode is interesting in that with a single function definition it allows the caller to *choose* whether to keep a sharing copy of the pointer for itself while creating a new sharing copy to be used by the function (this happens when an lvalue argument is provided; the copy constructor for shared pointers used at the call increases the reference count), or to just give the function a copy of the pointer without retaining one or touching the reference count (this happens when a rvalue argument is provided, possibly an lvalue wrapped in a call of `std::move`). For instance

```
void f(std::shared_ptr<X> x) // call by shared cash
{ container.insert(std::move(x)); } // store shared pointer in container

void client()
{ std::shared_ptr<X> p = std::make_shared<X>(args);
  f(p); // lvalue argument; store pointer in container but keep a copy
  f(std::make_shared<X>(args)); // prvalue argument; fresh pointer is just stored away
  f(std::move(p)); // xvalue argument; p is transferred to container and left null
}
```

The same could be achieved by separately defining `void f(const std::shared_ptr<X>& x)` (for the lvalue case) and `void f(std::shared_ptr<X>&& x)` (for the rvalue case), with function bodies differing only in that the first version invokes copy semantics (using copy construction/assignment when using `x`) but the second version move semantics (writing `std::move(x)` instead, as in the example code). So for shared pointers, mode 1 can be useful to avoid some code duplication.

### Mode 2: pass a smart pointer by (modifiable) lvalue reference

Here the function just requires having a modifiable reference to the smart pointer, but gives no indication of what it will do with it. I would like to call this method **call by card**: caller ensures payment by giving a credit card number. The reference *can* be used to take ownership of the pointed-to object, but it does not have to. This mode requires providing a modifiable lvalue argument, corresponding to the fact that the desired effect of the function may include leaving a useful value in the argument variable. A caller with an rvalue expression that it wishes to pass to such a function would be forced to store it in a named variable to be able to make the call, since the language only provides implicit conversion to a *constant* lvalue reference (referring to a temporary) from an rvalue. (Unlike the opposite situation handled by `std::move`, a cast from `Y&&` to `Y&`, with `Y` the smart pointer type, is not possible; nonetheless this conversion could be obtained by a simple template function if really desired; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24868376/1436796). For the case where the called function intends to unconditionally take ownership of the object, stealing from the argument, the obligation to provide an lvalue argument is giving the wrong signal: the variable will have no useful value after the call. Therefore mode 3, which gives identical possibilities inside our function but asks callers to provide an rvalue, should be preferred for such usage.

However there is a valid use case for mode 2, namely functions that may *modify* the pointer, or the object pointed to *in a way that involves ownership*. For instance, a function that prefixes a node to a `list` provides an example of such use:

```
void prepend (int x, list& l) { l = list( new node{ x, std::move(l)} ); }
```

Clearly it would be undesirable here to force callers to use `std::move`, since their smart pointer still owns a well defined and non-empty list after the call, though a different one than before.

Again it is interesting to observe what happens if the `prepend` call fails for lack of free memory. Then the `new` call will throw `std::bad_alloc`; at this point in time, since no `node` could be allocated, it is certain that the passed rvalue reference (mode 3) from `std::move(l)` cannot yet have been pilfered, as that would be done to construct the `next` field of the `node` that failed to be allocated. So the original smart pointer `l` still holds the original list when the error is thrown; that list will either be properly destroyed by the smart pointer destructor, or in case `l` should survive thanks to a sufficiently early `catch` clause, it will still hold the original list.

That was a constructive example; with a wink to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19375403/1436796) one can also give the more destructive example of removing the first node containing a given value, if any:

```
void remove_first(int x, list& l)
{ list* p = &l;
  while ((*p).get()!=nullptr and (*p)->entry!=x)
    p = &(*p)->next;
  if ((*p).get()!=nullptr)
    (*p).reset((*p)->next.release()); // or equivalent: *p = std::move((*p)->next); 
}
```

Again the correctness is quite subtle here. Notably, in the final statement the pointer `(*p)->next` held inside the node to be removed is unlinked (by `release`, which returns the pointer but makes the original null) *before* `reset` (implicitly) destroys that node (when it destroys the old value held by `p`), ensuring that one and *only one* node is destroyed at that time. (In the alternative form mentioned in the comment, this timing would be left to the internals of the implementation of the move-assignment operator of the `std::unique_ptr` instance `list`; the standard says 20.7.1.2.3;2 that this operator should act "as if by calling `reset(u.release())`", whence the timing should be safe here too.)

Note that `prepend` and `remove_first` cannot be called by clients who store a local `node` variable for an always non-empty list, and rightly so since the implementations given could not work for such cases.

### Mode 3: pass a smart pointer by (modifiable) rvalue reference

This is the preferred mode to use when simply taking ownership of the pointer.  I would like to call this method **call by check**: caller must accept relinquishing ownership, as if providing cash, by signing the check, but the actual withdrawal is postponed until the called function actually pilfers the pointer (exactly as it would when using mode 2). The "signing of the check" concretely means callers have to wrap an argument in `std::move` (as in mode 1) if it is an lvalue (if it is an rvalue, the "giving up ownership" part is obvious and requires no separate code).

Note that technically mode 3 behaves exactly as mode 2, so the called function *does not have to* assume ownership; however I would insist that if there is any uncertainty about ownership transfer (in normal usage), mode 2 should be preferred to mode 3, so that using mode 3 is implicitly a signal to callers that they *are* giving up ownership. One might retort that only mode 1 argument passing really signals forced loss of ownership to callers. But if a client has any doubts about intentions of the called function, she is supposed to know the specifications of the function being called, which should remove any doubt.

It is surprisingly difficult to find a typical example involving our `list` type that uses mode 3 argument passing. Moving a list `b` to the end of another list `a` is a typical example; however `a` (which survives and holds the result of the operation) is better passed using mode 2:

```
void append (list& a, list&& b)
{ list* p=&a;
  while ((*p).get()!=nullptr) // find end of list a
    p=&(*p)->next;
  *p = std::move(b); // attach b; the variable b relinquishes ownership here
}
```

A pure example of mode 3 argument passing is the following that takes a list (and its ownership), and returns a list containing the identical nodes in reverse order.

```
list reversed (list&& l) noexcept // pilfering reversal of list
{ list p(l.release()); // move list into temporary for traversal
  list result(nullptr);
  while (p.get()!=nullptr)
  { // permute: result --> p->next --> p --> (cycle to result)
    result.swap(p->next);
    result.swap(p);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This function might be called as in `l = reversed(std::move(l));` to reverse the list into itself, but the reversed list can also be used differently.

Here the argument is immediately moved to a local variable for efficiency (one could have used the parameter `l` directly in the place of `p`, but then accessing it each time would involve an extra level of indirection); hence the difference with mode 1 argument passing is minimal. In fact using that mode, the argument could have served directly as local variable, thus avoiding that initial move; this is just an instance of the general principle that if an argument passed by reference only serves to initialise a local variable, one might just as well pass it by value instead and use the parameter as local variable.

Using mode 3 appears to be advocated by the standard, as witnessed by the fact that all provided library functions that transfer ownership of smart pointers using mode 3. A particular convincing case in point is the constructor `std::shared_ptr<T>(auto_ptr<T>&& p)`. That constructor used (in `std::tr1`) to take a modifiable *lvalue* reference (just like the `auto_ptr<T>&` copy constructor), and could therefore be called with an `auto_ptr<T>` lvalue `p` as in `std::shared_ptr<T> q(p)`, after which `p` has been reset to null. Due to the change from mode 2 to 3 in argument passing, this old code must now be rewritten to `std::shared_ptr<T> q(std::move(p))` and will then continue to work. I understand that the committee did not like the mode 2 here, but they had the option of changing to mode 1, by defining `std::shared_ptr<T>(auto_ptr<T> p)` instead, they could have ensured that old code works without modification, because (unlike unique-pointers) auto-pointers can be silently dereferenced to a value (the pointer object itself being reset to null in the process). Apparently the committee so much preferred advocating mode 3 over mode 1, that they chose to *actively break existing code* rather than to use mode 1 even for an already deprecated usage.

## When to prefer mode 3 over mode 1

Mode 1 is perfectly usable in many cases, and might be preferred over mode 3 in cases where assuming ownership would otherwise takes the form of moving the smart pointer to a local variable as in the `reversed` example above. However, I can see two reasons to prefer mode 3 in the more general case:

- It is slightly more efficient to pass a reference than to create a temporary and nix the old pointer (handling cash is somewhat laborious); in some scenarios the pointer may be passed several times unchanged to another function before it is actually pilfered. Such passing will generally require writing `std::move` (unless mode 2 is used), but note that this is just a cast that does not actually do anything (in particular no dereferencing), so it has zero cost attached.
- Should it be conceivable that anything throws an exception between the start of the function call and the point where it (or some contained call) actually moves the pointed-to object into another data structure (and this exception is not already caught inside the function itself), then when using mode 1, the object referred to by the smart pointer will be destroyed before a `catch` clause can handle the exception (because the function parameter was destructed during stack unwinding), but not so when using mode 3. The latter gives the caller has the option to recover the data of the object in such cases (by catching the exception). Note that mode 1 here *does not cause a memory leak*, but may lead to an unrecoverable loss of data for the program, which might be undesirable as well.

## Returning a smart pointer: always by value

To conclude a word about *returning* a smart pointer, presumably pointing to an object created for use by the caller. This is not really a case comparable with passing pointers into functions, but for completeness I would like to insist that in such cases **always return by value** (and *don't use* `std::move` in the `return` statement). Nobody wants to get a *reference* to a pointer that probably has just been nixed.

Comment: +1 for the Mode 0 -- passing the underlying pointer instead of the unique_ptr. Slightly off topic (since the question is about passing a unique_ptr) but it's simple and avoids problems.

Comment: "*mode 1 here does not cause a memory leak*" - that implies that mode 3 does cause a memory leak, which is not true. Regardless of whether `unique_ptr` has been moved-from or not, it will still nicely delete the value if it still holds it whenever destroyed or re-used.

Comment: @RustyX: I cannot see how you construe that implication, and I never intended to say what you think I implied. All I meant is that as elsewhere the use of `unique_ptr` prevents a memory leak (and thus in a sense fulfils its contract), but here (i.e., using mode 1) it might cause (under specific circumstances) something that might be considered even more harmful, namely a loss of data (destruction of the value pointed to) that could have been avoided using mode 3.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen the way you write your code is not particularly readable, maybe you could edit ?

Comment: @kingsjester I have forgotten the precise way in which I wrote my code, but I find the result quite readable. Apart from a few one-liners I have put separate statements on separate lines and indented consistently.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen yes, { size_t l=0; for ( ; p!=nullptr; p=p->next.get()) ++l; return l; }
 or { return list( p==nullptr ? nullptr : new node{p->entry,copy(p->next.get())} ); }
are understandable but why put everything on one line ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you have to if you take the `unique_ptr` by value in the constructor. Explicity is a nice thing. Since `unique_ptr` is uncopyable (private copy ctor), what you wrote should give you a compiler error.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** This answer is wrong, even though, strictly speaking, the code works. I'm only leaving it here because the discussion under it is too useful. This other answer is the best answer given at the time I last edited this: [How do I pass a unique_ptr argument to a constructor or a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-passing-a-unique-ptr-as-argument-of-a-constructor-or-a-method/8114339#8114339)

The basic idea of `::std::move` is that people who are passing you the `unique_ptr` should be using it to express the knowledge that they know the `unique_ptr` they're passing in will lose ownership.

This means you should be using an rvalue reference  to a `unique_ptr` in your methods, not a `unique_ptr` itself. This won't work anyway because passing in a plain old `unique_ptr` would require making a copy, and that's explicitly forbidden in the interface for `unique_ptr`.  Interestingly enough, using a named rvalue reference turns it back into an lvalue again, so you need to use `::std::move` **inside** your methods as well.

This means your two methods should look like this:

```
Base(Base::UPtr &&n) : next(::std::move(n)) {} // Spaces for readability

void setNext(Base::UPtr &&n) { next = ::std::move(n); }
```

Then people using the methods would do this:

```
Base::UPtr objptr{ new Base; }
Base::UPtr objptr2{ new Base; }
Base fred(::std::move(objptr)); // objptr now loses ownership
fred.setNext(::std::move(objptr2)); // objptr2 now loses ownership
```

As you see, the `::std::move` expresses that the pointer is going to lose ownership at the point where it's most relevant and helpful to know. If this happened invisibly, it would be very confusing for people using your class to have `objptr` suddenly lose ownership for no readily apparent reason.

Comment: Named rvalue references are lvalues.

Comment: are you sure it's `Base fred(::std::move(objptr));` and not `Base::UPtr fred(::std::move(objptr));` ?

Comment: To add to my previous comment: this code won't compile. You still need to use `std::move` in the implementation of both the constructor and the method. And even when you pass by value, the caller must still use `std::move` to pass lvalues. The main difference being that with pass-by-value that interface makes it clear ownership will be lost. See Nicol Bolas comment on another answer.

Comment: @codablank1: Yes. I'm demonstrating how to use the constructor and methods in base that take rvalue references.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Oh, interesting. I suppose that makes sense. I was expecting you to be wrong, but actual testing proved you correct. Fixed now.

Comment: I get errors : `In constructor ‘Base::Base(Base::UPtr&&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/unique_ptr.h:207:7: error: deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = Base, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<Base>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<Base>]’`

Comment: @codablank1: Yes, the person who modded me down is correct. I've updated and fixed my code. Also, the other person who answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-passing-a-unique-ptr-as-argument-of-a-constructor-or-a-method/8114339#8114339 is also more correct than I. I should delete my answer, though it would work.

Comment: @Omnifarious if you're interested the rationale for named rvalue refs being lvalues is that it avoids this: `void setNext(Base::UPtr &&n) { next = n; other = n; }` (well, at least it forces you to be explicit, instead of getting nasty surprises)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: That is indeed an excellent rationale. Much better than my vague feeling of "Well, that seems a bit odd, but also feels like more correct behavior than what I was assuming would work.".

Comment: "objptr now loses ownership" No, it does not. `std::move` does not actually _move_ anything. It simply converts it into a `&&`. Movement happens either via a move constructor or move assignment. That's why you shouldn't take `unique_ptr`s as `&&`; take them as *values*. That way, you ensure that the movement happens regardless of whether the function actually wants to claim ownership or not. If the function taking a `&&` doesn't actually invoke a move constructor/assignment, then nothing gets moved and the user still has the pointer.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Exactly, which is why I think I ought to delete my answer. The only thing stopping me is the most interesting discussion that appears under it.

Answer (score 5):

#### tl;dr: Do not use `unique_ptr`'s like that.

I believe you're making a terrible mess - for those who will need to read your code, maintain it, and probably those who need to use it.

**Only take `unique_ptr` constructor parameters if you have publicly-exposed `unique_ptr` members.**

`unique_ptr`'s wrap raw pointers for ownership & lifetime management. They're great for localized use - not good, nor in fact intended, for interfacing. Wanna interface? Document your new class as ownership-taking, and let it get the raw resource; or perhaps, in the case of pointers, use `owner<T*>` as suggested in the [Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-gsl).

Only if the purpose of your class is to hold `unique_ptr`'s, and have others use those `unique_ptr`'s as such - only then is it reasonable for your constructor or methods to take them.

**Don't expose the fact that you use `unique_ptr`s internally.**

Using `unique_ptr` for list nodes is very much an implementation detail. Actually, even the fact that you're letting users of your list-like mechanism just use the bare list node directly - constructing it themselves and giving it to you - is not a good idea IMHO. I should not need to form a new list-node-which-is-also-a-list to add something to your list - I should just pass the payload - by value, by const lvalue ref and/or by rvalue ref. Then you deal with it. And for splicing lists - again, value, const lvalue and/or rvalue.

Comment: Although there are very informative answers about the question and capability of language, point of this answer is so important imho. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Base(Base::UPtr n):next(std::move(n)) {}
```

should be much better as

```
Base(Base::UPtr&& n):next(std::forward<Base::UPtr>(n)) {}
```

and

```
void setNext(Base::UPtr n)
```

should be

```
void setNext(Base::UPtr&& n)
```

with same body.

And ... what is `evt` in `handle()` ??

Comment: There's no gain in using `std::forward` here: `Base::UPtr&&` is **always** an rvalue reference type, and `std::move` passes it as an rvalue. It's already forwarded correctly.

Comment: I strongly disagree. If a function takes a `unique_ptr` by value, then you are *guaranteed* that a move constructor was called on the new value (or simply that you were given a temporary). This _ensures_ that the `unique_ptr` variable the user has is now _empty_. If you take it by `&&` instead, it will only be emptied if your code invokes a move operation. Your way, it is possible for the variable that the user has to not have been moved from. Which makes the user's use of `std::move` suspect and confusing. Using `std::move` should always ensure that something was _moved_.

Comment: @NicolBolas: You're right. I will delete my answer because while it works, your observation is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

To the top voted answer. I prefer passing by rvalue reference.

I understand what's the problem about passing by rvalue reference may cause. But let's divide this problem to two sides:

- for caller:

I must write code `Base newBase(std::move(<lvalue>))` or `Base newBase(<rvalue>)`.

- for callee:

Library author should guarantee it will actually move the unique_ptr to initialize member if it want own the ownership.

That's all.

If you pass by rvalue reference, it will only invoke one "move" instruction, but if pass by value, it's two.

Yep, if library author is not expert about this, he may not move unique_ptr to initialize member, but it's the problem of author, not you. Whatever it pass by value or rvalue reference, your code is same!

If you are writing a library, now you know you should guarantee it, so just do it, passing by rvalue reference is a better choice than value. Client who use you library will just write same code.

Now, for your question. How do I pass a unique_ptr argument to a constructor or a function?

You know what's the best choice.

http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/07/should-move-only-types-ever-be-passed.html