# How to capture std::unique_ptr "by move" for a lambda in std::for_each

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I am learning the new features in c++11 and came across this problem.  I'd like to capture an unique_ptr by moving it inside a lambda as an argument for for_each.

set up:

```
std::array<int,4> arr = {1,3,5,6};
std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int);  (*p) = 3;
```

attempt 1 - doesn't work because unique_ptr doesn't have a copy constructor.  c++0x doesn't specify the pass by move syntax.

```
std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [p](int& i) { i+=*p; });
```

attempt 2 - use bind to bind a moved copy of p to a function that takes int&:

```
std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
     std::bind([](const unique_ptr<int>& p, int& i){
          i += (*p);
     }, std::move(p))
);
```

Compiler complains that `'result' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template.`

The main purpose of the exercise is to understand how a movable variable be captured in a lambda that's cached for later use.

Comment: This question has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8640393/20984). However, I don't vote to close since your question contains an alternative (though not-working) solution.

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8236521/20984).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Update: you can capture a movable variable in a lambda from C++14 onwards.

```
std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [p=std::move(p)](int& i) { i+=*p; });
```

---

You cannot capture a movable variable into a lambda in any straightforward way in C++11.

Lambdas capture by copy or by reference. Thus, to capture a move-only variable, you have to wrap it in an object where copying => moving (such as `std::auto_ptr`). This is a nasty hack.

In your example, you can just capture by reference, but if this was just simplified code it may not do what you wanted with the real code:

```
std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [&p](int& i) { i+=*p; });
```

Here's a copy-move-only wrapper:

```
template<typename T>
struct move_on_copy_wrapper
{
    mutable T value;

    move_on_copy_wrapper(T&& t):
        value(std::move(t))
    {}

    move_on_copy_wrapper(move_on_copy_wrapper const& other):
        value(std::move(other.value))
    {}

    move_on_copy_wrapper(move_on_copy_wrapper&& other):
        value(std::move(other.value))
    {}

    move_on_copy_wrapper& operator=(move_on_copy_wrapper const& other)
    {
        value=std::move(other.value);
        return *this;
    }

    move_on_copy_wrapper& operator=(move_on_copy_wrapper&& other)
    {
        value=std::move(other.value);
        return *this;
    }

};
```

You can then use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(3));
    move_on_copy_wrapper<std::unique_ptr<int>> mp(std::move(p));

    [mp]()
    {
        std::cout<<"*mp.value="<<*mp.value<<std::endl;
    }
    ();

    std::cout<<"p="<<p.get()<<", mp="<<mp.value.get()<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you really *need* to implement the move-semantic functions, i.e `move_on_copy_wrapper(move_on_copy_wrapper&&)` and `move_on_copy_wrapper& operator=(move_on_copy_wrapper&&)`? The compiler generated ones are not enough?

Comment: The compiler won't generate them due to the existence of the copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: "Note that std::bind also requires that its arguments are copyable." That's not true. `std::bind` is usable with move-only types.

Comment: AFAIK, std::bind should work on movable arguments. However, MSDN's documentation says all arguments should be copy constructible. Anthony, which compiler do you use?   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982702(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: OK, I checked: `std::bind` should be usable with move-only arguments, it just creates a move-only result. However, it fails in practice with MSVC 2010 and g++ 4.7.

Comment: Sample code didn't compile: error C2558: struct 'move_on_copy_wrapper<T>' : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit' with [T=std::unique_ptr<int>]

Comment: Interesting. It appears MSVC 2010 requires the copy constructor to take `const` arg. Easily fixed: make `value` `mutable`, and add `const` to the copy constructor and copy-assignment operator.

Comment: GCC 4.7 can certainly correctly deal with move-only types with `std::bind`. However be careful of the peculiar way `std::bind` forwards the bound arguments to the functor: try for instance `pointer_type p; auto f = std::bind([](pointer_type& p) {}, std::move(p)); f();` with some appropriate `pointer_type`.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams, you defined the move ctors by hand.  Doesn't `=default` force the compiler to generate the move ctors for you?

Comment: Yes, I could have used `=default` for the move constructor and move assignment operator.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt 2 will almost work.

What's missing is you haven't told your `bind` call to expect a parameter:

```
std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
   std::bind([](const unique_ptr<int>& p, int& i){
      i += (*p);
   }, std::move(p), std::placeholders::_1)
);
```

The `placeholders::_1` is necessary to tell the result of `bind` that it should expect a parameter passed to it for its `operator()`.

This is also the suggestion given in @marton78's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744621/751061).