# Using C++11 lambdas asynchronously, safely

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, shared-ptr

I've come to C++11 from an Objective-C background, and one thing I'm struggling to come to terms with is the different capturing semantics of C++11 lambdas vs Objective-C "blocks". (See [here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-06-03-objective-c-blocks-vs-c0x-lambdas-fight.html) for a comparison).

In Objective-C, like C++, the `self`/`this` pointer is implicitly captured if you refer to a member variable. But because all objects in Objective-C are effectively "shared pointers", to use the C++ terminology, you can do this:

```
doSomethingAsynchronously(^{
  someMember_ = 42;
});
```

... and you're guaranteed that the object whose member you're accessing will be alive when the block executes. You don't have to think about it. The equivalent in C++ seems to be something like:

```
// I'm assuming here that `this` derives from std::enable_shared_from_this and 
// is already owned by some shared_ptr.
auto strongThis = shared_from_this();

doSomethingAsynchronously([strongThis, this] {
  someMember_ = 42;   // safe, as the lambda holds a reference to this
                      // via shared_ptr.
});
```

Here, you need to remember to capture the shared_ptr in addition to the this pointer. Is there some less error-prone way of achieving this?

Comment: *"You don't have to think about it."* Start thinking about it. It leads to better design.

Comment: @Pubby But the thing is, it's the effortlessness of using blocks that makes them so useful and so pervasive for one-shot asynchronous tasks in the Obj-C world. If they had the C++11 semantics, and you had to ask yourself "will this object be alive, will this object be alive, will this object be alive..." every single time, I think many people would be tempted to say "screw it, I'll do it synchronously."

Comment: Creating a shared pointer from `this` doesn't guarantee it will still exist, unless the object itself was already owned by a shared pointer and you are copying it. Creating a new shared pointer (by `new shared_ptr<T>(this)` or `make_shared<T>(this)`) will only serve to get a double-delete, unless the memory would have leaked otherwise. So, in your case, how does `this` get deleted if you don't create a shared pointer at this point?

Comment: @Agentlien I've clarified the question.

Comment: @NickHutchinson: The problem is **ownership is important**. Look up Rust, for example -> new language created by enlightened people -> ownership is *explicit*. Hiding ownership issues from the user encourages her not to think about it, and soon you get space leaks and bloated memory "for no good reason I can see".

Comment: IIRC the C++11 lambda syntax is `[](){}`, not `([]{})`. Also, a lambda is an expression, so you can't form a declaration with just `doSomethingAsynchronously [](){}`. That's equivalent to just `Foo 4`.

Comment: @MSalters The parentheses can be omitted if there are no arguments. (So `[]{}` is the shortest lambda)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the founding principles of C++ is that you don't pay for what you don't use.  That means in this case that contexts where taking a `shared_ptr` to `this` is unnecessary shouldn't incur any reference counting overhead.  This also means that it shouldn't happen automatically even e.g. as a feature of `enable_shared_from_this`, since you might want to pass a short-lived lambda to an algorithm (`for_each`, etc.) in which case the lambda doesn't outlive its scope.

I'd suggest adapting the [lambda-wrapper pattern](http://jrb-programming.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/another-alternative-to-lambda-move.html); in that case it's used for `move` capture of a large object ([How to capture std::unique_ptr "by move" for a lambda in std::for_each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280937/how-to-capture-stdunique-ptr-by-move-for-a-lambda-in-stdfor-each)), but it can equally be used for shared capture of `this`:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
class shared_this_lambda {
  std::shared_ptr<T> t;  // just for lifetime
  F f;
public:
  shared_this_lambda(std::shared_ptr<T> t, F f): t(t), f(f) {}
  template<class... Args>
  auto operator()(Args &&...args)
  -> decltype(this->f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

template<typename T>
struct enable_shared_this_lambda {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<std::enable_shared_from_this<T>, T>::value,
    "T must inherit enable_shared_from_this<T>");
  template<typename F>
  auto make_shared_this_lambda(F f) -> shared_this_lambda<T, F> {
    return shared_this_lambda<T, F>(
      static_cast<T *>(this)->shared_from_this(), f);
  }
  template<typename F>
  auto make_shared_this_lambda(F f) const -> shared_this_lambda<const T, F> {
    return shared_this_lambda<const T, F>(
      static_cast<const T *>(this)->shared_from_this(), f);
  }
};
```

Use by inheriting `enable_shared_this_lambda` in addition to `enable_shared_from_this`; you can then explicitly request that any long-lived lambdas take a shared `this`:

```
doSomethingAsynchronously(make_shared_this_lambda([this] {
  someMember_ = 42;
}));
```

Comment: Yes, but you also need to have someMember_ atomic or mutexed if threads are involved.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll adopt this pattern. Still not entirely convinced it's a good thing that shared_ptr is a library-level feature given that it makes this so cumbersome, but them's the breaks, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Boost uses:

```
auto self(shared_from_this());
auto l = [this, self] { do(); };
```

Mentioned here: [What's the reason of using auto self(shared_from_this()) variable in lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368012/whats-the-reason-of-using-auto-selfshared-from-this-variable-in-lambda-func)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's one right answer to this problem. The answer has the exact same effect of binding with `shared_from_this()` (like when you do it with `boost::asio::io_service`). Think about it; what does binding with `shared_from_this()` do? It simple replaces `this`. So what prevents you from replacing `this` with `shared_from_this()` totally?

Following your example, which I updated to make the difference clearer, instead of this:

```
auto strongThis = shared_from_this();

doSomethingAsynchronously([strongThis, this] () {
  this->someMember_ = 42; //here, you're using `this`... that's wrong!
});
```

Do this:

```
auto strongThis = shared_from_this();

doSomethingAsynchronously([strongThis] () //notice, you're not passing `this`!
{
  strongThis->someMember_ = 42;            
});
```

The only cost here is that you're gonna have to prefix everything with `strongThis->`. But this is the most meaningful way to do it.