# What's the reason of using auto self(shared_from_this()) variable in lambda function?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, lambda, boost-asio

I read the boost asio http server example code (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/http/server/connection.cpp) and find the `auto self(shared_from_this());` variable is been used in the capture scope (`[this, self]`). But the self variable is not been used in the lambda function. Then what's the benefit of doing so?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is done in order to make sure that `connection` object outlives the asynchronous operation: as long as the lambda is alive (i.e. the async. operation is in progress), the `connection` instance is alive as well.

Comment: Good explanation. May you by any chance have an opinion on the follow-up question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613178/836097 ?

Comment: May you explain why `auto self(shared_from_this());` isn't used in [client](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/client.cpp) example (while [server](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/server.cpp) used that) ?

Comment: @SAMPro  because in client example there's nothing that would be managed via `shared_ptr`. The `client` instance in that example has an automatic storage.