# Why the boost example calls `shared_from_this()` again instead of using the closure variable

Tags: boost, boost-asio

In the connection object at the [boost asio HTTP server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/http/server/connection.cpp) in methods `do_read` and `do_write` the `shared_from_this()` is captured to address the connection object lifespan issue, [as been answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19368188/836097). It is still not clear why on lines 67 and 88 the code calls `shared_from_this()` again, instead of using `self`:

````
40  auto self(shared_from_this());
41  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
42      [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
43      {
....
67          connection_manager_.stop(shared_from_this());
```
````

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no practical reason for that (I guess it's just a leftover from older C++03 example that was refactored to C++11 style). Using `self` would be preferable, as it's already captured anyway.

The only "educational" reason I can think of could be to demonstrate that the explicitly captured `self` is stored within the lambda, even if it's unused.