# Calling function in capture list of a lambda function

Tags: c++

In this boost asio [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/http/server/connection.cpp) I see:

```
auto self(shared_from_this()); //boost::shared_ptr<connection>

boost::asio::async_write(socket_, reply_.to_buffers(),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t)
    {
        //...
    }
);
```

In Visual Studio 2015, if I write

```
[this, shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t)
```

I receive the following error:

> Error C2059   syntax error: ')'

Why can't the lambda function capture the `boost::shared_ptr` variable directly from the call to the `shared_from_this()`? Isn't it the same thing? I can't find anywhere an explanation. I've read other examples (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872798/using-c11-lambdas-asynchronously-safely) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368012/whats-the-reason-of-using-auto-selfshared-from-this-variable-in-lambda-func), but they don't ask this question).

Comment: Try using the correct syntax for named captures: `[this, self=shared_from_this()]( ... )`

Comment: This actually compiles successfully, but it still doesn't make sense for me. In your example, `self` is not declared (like in the example `auto self(shared_from_this())`), so how does the lambda know its type?

Comment: The lambda uses the type `auto` for named captures, the same type you used in an explicit declaration. Named types use `auto`, and the compiler figures out the type from the expression that's used to initialize it.

Comment: OK, you can add this as an aswer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for named captures, in your case, would be:

```
[this, self=shared_from_this()]( ... )
```