# How to move a variable into a lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11

I see the C++11 documentation (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for lambda expressions states capture by value and reference are supported but not rvalue reference. The closest SO question I could find related to this is: [How to capture a unique_ptr into a lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236521/how-to-capture-a-unique-ptr-into-a-lambda-expression), but it seems like my use case doesn't require the use of `std::bind`.

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
public:
    explicit Foo(int value = 0) : mValue(value) {}

    // The following items are provided just to be explicit
    Foo(Foo &&other) = default;
    Foo &operator=(Foo &&other) = default;
    Foo(const Foo &other) = delete;
    Foo &operator=(const Foo &other) = delete;
    ~Foo() {}

    int mValue;
};

void bar(std::unique_ptr<Foo> f)
{
    std::cout << "bar:  " << std::dec << f->mValue << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Foo> f(new Foo(22));
        std::cout << "main: " << std::hex << f.get() << "\n";

        // Call the bar function directly (requires using std::move)
        bar(std::move(f));
        std::cout << "main: " << std::hex << f.get() << "\n";
    }

    {
        std::unique_ptr<Foo> f(new Foo(99));
        std::cout << "main: " << std::hex << f.get() << "\n";

        // Lamda expression captures 'f' by reference and then calls the bar function (again, requires using std::move)
        auto fn = [&f](){ bar(std::move(f)); };
        fn(); // Execute the closure
        std::cout << "main: " << std::hex << f.get() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Example Output

```
main: 0x92e010
bar:  22
main: 0
main: 0x92e010
bar:  99
main: 0
```

By examining the output it *appears* this program is *running correctly* (i.e., the observed results are what I expected. However, I have the following questions.

### Questions

1. Is using the closure equivalent to the code that calls the `bar` function directly?

   - I'm asking explicitly since the documentation (see beginning of the question) about lambda expressions didn't state anything about using `std::move` on captured references (i.e., I want to make sure this doesn't run afoul of `undefined behavior` or similar bad outcomes).
2. If the answer to the first question is "you can't use `std::move` on the captured reference", then what is the right way to do this (e.g., the `std::bind` solution, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is using the closure equivalent to the code that calls the bar function directly?

Yes, they're equivalent in this code.  Captured references aren't special in any way that I can think of: you have fully defined behavior, as long as `f` is in scope and can be moved from.