# Why it's a bad idea to take std::unique_ptr by &&?

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw Nicol Bolas said

> never take unique_ptr by &&, unless you are actually writing its move constructor

in [his anwser post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236521/how-to-capture-a-unique-ptr-into-a-lambda-expression).

I thought force the explicit calling of `std::move` on `unique_ptr` by `&&` should be a good practice, which notice the coder: from here on, the unique_ptr got moved into another place, don't touch it anymore.

So why did Nicol Bolas say that?

Comment: Duplicate post was referenced in comments by @Nicol Bolas himself.

Comment: related: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/07/should-move-only-types-ever-be-passed.html