# Should/Can smart pointers be passed by reference in functions

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Should/Can smart pointers be passed by reference in functions?

Ie:

```
void foo(const std::weak_ptr<bar>& x)
```

Comment: Can is easy to find out, may i ask why you think it shouldnt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass smart pointers into functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519812/how-do-i-pass-smart-pointers-into-functions)

Comment: @5gon12eder: Nearly, but no cookie. This is can/should, that is how.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think [Nicol Bolas's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519812/how-do-i-pass-smart-pointers-into-functions/12520022#12520022) explains the “should” part very well. Don't you? The “can” part might be a different story but then again, it's the same answer as for any other type.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Well, I don't see how it addresses the case if ownership-transfer is really not meant. It is a nice answer for that question though.

Comment: The additional explanation in [Emilio Garavaglia's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924727/emilio-garavaglia) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519812/how-do-i-pass-smart-pointers-into-functions/12520014#12520014) might also be relevant.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Actually, Mark Ransom's answer is the one touching on this question.

Comment: Another interesting reading http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can pass a smart-pointer by `const&`.

There is also a reason to do so:
If the function accepting said smart-pointer is just a front for one accepting a raw (observing) pointer for manipulating the (potential) pointee.
**Never force anyone to use a smart-pointer for anything but transfering / sharing ownership, they might not be managing it with the one you insist on.**

In all other cases, using a smart-pointer implies *transfer / sharing of ownership*, and avoiding a cheap copy (just a test whether it owns anything and reference-counting, as well as two pointer copies) doesn't actually buy you anything.

Comment: As a clarification: Writing `unshared_ptr` is easy (that pretends to be a shared ptr to something, but lies), as is wrapping a different smart pointer.  The problem is that by taking particular semantics, you imply use of them, and fully obeying semantics can be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No, if we are talking about `std` smart pointers. `const T &` can't transfer/share ownership, so raw non-owning `T *` is always better and more efficient.