# Passing std::unique_ptr to helper function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Is this a proper way?

```
void helperFunc(MyClass *ptr)
{
    // do something with ptr,
}

unique_ptr<MyClass> p(new MyClass());
helperFunc(p.get());
```

or should I use shared_ptr for such operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If helpFunc takes the ownership you pass std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr otherwise just pass by reference:

```
  void helperFunc(MyClass& my_class)
  {
  }
```

call:

```
 helperFunc(*p);
```

Comment: This is silly. If the function doesn't want to take ownership *why the heck is ownership* (i.e. unique_ptr) *even in the interface*? The way to take non-owning references has always been to take MyClass& or MyClass* or const variants. *That has no reason to change now*.

Comment: The only potential issue with raw pointers is if you work with an  application that mixes libs supporting smart pointers (and using them consistently) and libraries that are not using them (because they target an older standard). In such a case, you might find yourself with similar raw-pointer functions that may or may not take ownership. See my blog post on [unique_ptr usage](http://wp.me/p2Bia3-2U)

Answer (score 7):

Unless you want to take ownership of the memory (in which case you should pass either a `shared_ptr` or a `unique_ptr`), why are you working with a pointer at all?

Pass by reference.

```
void helperFunc(MyClass& obj)
{
    // do something with ptr,
}

unique_ptr<MyClass> p(new MyClass());
helperFunc(*p);
```

Using raw pointers when you don’t want to take ownership is fine in general but unnecessary here, unless you explicitly want to allow `nullptr`s (in which case, yes, use a raw pointer).

Answer (score 4):

When you use the `get()` functions, you get a raw pointer and lose the allocation-tracking that you're using the `unique_ptr` class to have in the first place.

I would avoid using `get()`, unless `helperFunc` really is so trivial that it does not take ownership of the pointer, and can be guaranteed not to leak it or leave a dangling reference in some other state.

If you really mean to pass the `unique_ptr` itself to the function, take a look at: [How do I pass a unique_ptr argument to a constructor or a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function)

Comment: yes, I assume helperFunc does not need "full" ownership... but that way I leave door open for some troubles in the future.

Comment: @fen: yes that very much leaves potential for future trouble.