# Getter and setter for unique_ptr object (dependency injection)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dependency-injection, getter-setter, unique-ptr

I have a class `MyClass` that owns an instance of some `DataProvider` class and has a getter for this.

For the sake of Dependency Injection I would prefer to have a getter and a setter. Additionally the `DataProvider` should be contained in a `std::unique_pointer`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class DataProvider
{
public:
    DataProvider() {}
    virtual ~DataProvider() {}
    /* stuff */

private:
    /* more stuff */

};

class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass() {}

    virtual inline const DataProvider &getDataProvider() const
    {
        return *data;
    }
    void setDataProvider(std::unique_ptr<DataProvider> newData)
    {
        data = std::move(newData);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<DataProvider> data;
};
```

I've read this: [How do I pass a unique_ptr argument to a constructor or a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function/8114913#8114913)

But it does not cover the getter part. Is this (above) the right way to do this? What are alternatives to think of?

Comment: full example would be better then code snippets

Comment: [Works fine here](http://ideone.com/enarAS). What vtable? We don't have any virtual functions.

Comment: @sftrabbit You're right, I had to add some more info about DataProvider and the way that it is broken in the end.

Comment: Does the default constructor of `DataProvider` set `xyz`?

Comment: DataProvider has a setter for xyz. edit: No, wait ... yes the default constructor sets it to 0 AND there is a setter for it.

Comment: @user1916893: "*the default constructor sets it to 0 AND there is a setter for it*" I don't see any of that in the code you provided. So how can we be expected to know things you haven't shown us?

Comment: Sorry, DataProvider is 1500+ lines of legacy code. I have to extract the lines which I think are important.

Comment: @user1916893 Okay, extract the lines you think are important and make a new small program using them. When you experience the same problem, post it here. For all we know, the problem is in the 1500 lines of legacy code.

Comment: Status update: In a small test project everything works fine. At least it seems to me that using a unique_ptr together with getter and setter as seen above is OK. I will keep you informed.

Comment: Ah, the solution is too embarrassing. I rebuilt the whole solution (production). Now everything is fine. Thank you all for your time and effort, I learned a lot this morning.

Comment: Be careful with this approach.  If `MyClass` is destroyed before a class using the getter, you will have problems.  Consider using a `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you wrote

```
virtual inline const DataProvider &getDataProvider() const
{
    return *data;
}
void setDataProvider(std::unique_ptr<DataProvider> newData)
{
    data = std::move(newData);
}
```

is perfectly OK. In the setter the class gets ownership of the DataProvider instance and never let go (as far as seen here).

A full example has been given by sftrabbit here: http://ideone.com/enarAS

Comment: Can you explain this whole thing `virtual inline const DataProvider &getDataProvider() const` (the use of `virtual`, `inline` and the two `const`) for a newbie? :)

Comment: @toggy `getDataProvider` is the name of the method, that's an easy one I guess. `const` in general means "there is something constant here, a variable which has a value that cannot be changed" (it can be bypassed but in this comment I assume that `const` means "not changeable"). The second `const` just means that in this method no class member will be changed. The `this` pointer itself is `const`. The first `const` is part of the return type `const DataProvider&` - a reference to a DataProvider object and this object cannot be changed.

Comment: @toggy A method declared as `virtual` is best explained with an example: Say you have a base class A and a class B deriving from A. A has a public method f(). So you can call f() on objects of type A and on objects of type B. Now B has a method f(), too. Consider a pointer c to an object of type A: `A* c;`. If c actually points to an object of type B and you write 'c->f();', the f() of A will be called *unless* f() is virtual in which case the f() of B will be called. That's the difference.

Comment: @toggy 'inline' means that while building your project the optimizer shall *prefer*(!) to substitue the method body at each place where the method is called. In fact I normally don't use this keyword and let the compiler decide for itself. Anyway I found a good explanation here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: I didn't mean 'that' newbie x) I just wanted to know why they were 2 const keywords and why it was useful to use virtual and inline here. Thanks :p

Comment: In the getter method you're returning a reference to a temporary object, is that _safe_?

Comment: @KillKRT `*data` is casted to a reference to a `member`, not a temporary. So, yes, it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure if this really is what you need this is a starting point:

```
const DataProvider &getDataProvider() const
{
    return *data.get();
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand unique_ptr IMHO this makes no difference.