# unique_ptr to a derived class as an argument to a function that takes a unique_ptr to a base class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use a `unique_ptr` to derived class in a function that takes a `unique_ptr` to a base class. Something like:

```
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

void f(unique_ptr<Base> const &base) {}

…

unique_ptr<Derived> derived = unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived);
f(derived);
```

If I understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114913/41071) correctly, this code should work, but it causes the following compile errors:

> error C2664: 'f' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' to 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty> &'
>
> IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::unique_ptr<Derived, std::default_delete<Derived>>" to "const std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base>>" exists

If I change `f` to take `unique_ptr<Derived> const &derived`, it works fine, but that's not what I want.

Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to work around this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Give up ownership. This will leave your local variable without access to the dynamic object after the function call; the object has been transferred to the callee:

   ```
   f(std::move(derived));
   ```
2. Change the signature of `f`:

   ```
   void f(std::unique_ptr<Derived> const &);
   ```
3. Change the type of your variable:

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<base> derived = std::unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived);
   ```

   Or of course just:

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<base> derived(new Derived);
   ```

   Or even:

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<base> derived = std::make_unique<Derived>();
   ```
4. **Update:** Or, as recommended in the comments, don't transfer ownership at all:

   ```
   void f(Base & b);

   f(*derived);
   ```

Comment: In that case, I'm considering going with 4. Use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: How about just using a reference instead of a unique_ptr for the function call?

Comment: @svick, why pass in a smart pointer to the function if it doesn't take ownership of the pointer? That's not what smart pointers are for.

Comment: @ltjax How exactly would I do that?

Comment: @JonathanWakely So, what else am I supposed to do? Because I don't like any of the alternatives in this answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Say one has a factory function: `std::unique_ptr<Base> MakeDerived() { auto p = std::unique_ptr<Derived>( new Derived() ); /*...*/ return p; }` My intuition says I shouldn't need `std::move(p)` for the return, but my compilers tell me I do. Is this intended behavior or a defect in the standard?

Comment: Done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018115/converting-stdunique-ptrderived-to-stdunique-ptrbase).

Comment: @metal: Great, thanks - yeah, important detail, the return types have to match. I missed that. Good stuff. You could have said `return std::unique_ptr<Base>(std::move(p))`, I suppose.

Comment: _"This will destroy the object at the end of the function call"_: But we don't know what `f()` is doing (assuming that it's actually not empty) - it might pass the ownership elsewhere. Isn't all we can say that we give up or transfer the ownership ?

Comment: @Zitrax: You're right, that isn't phrased very well. Let me edit it.

Answer (score 58):

I had option #1 of the accepted answer and I still had the same compile error. I banged my head on the wall for over an hour and I finally realized that I had

```
class Derived : Base {};
```

instead of

```
class Derived : public Base {};
```

Answer (score 14):

A possibile solution is to change the type of the argument to be a `Base const*`, and pass `derived.get()` instead. There is no transfer of ownership with `unique_ptr const<Base>&` (and the `unique_ptr` is not being modified), so changing to a `Base const*` does not change the meaning.

---

Herb Sutter discusses passing smart pointer arguments at length in [Smart Pointer Parameters](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/). An extract from the linked article refers to this exact situation:

> Passing a `const unique_ptr<widget>&` is strange because it can accept only either `null` or a `widget` whose lifetime happens to be managed in the calling code via a `unique_ptr`, and the callee generally shouldn’t care about the caller’s lifetime management choice. Passing `widget*` covers a strict superset of these cases and can accept “`null` or a `widget`” regardless of the lifetime policy the caller happens to be using.

Comment: Doesn't `Base const*` mean that the function could store the pointer somewhere? I though smart pointers are trying to avoid that.

Comment: @svick, the function could store `base.get()` just as easily (`get()` is `const` member function).

Comment: @svick No. Smart pointers are to avoid memory leaks by making clear who is the owner of an object. If you pass raw pointer as argument to a function you just give access to read/modify it. Smart pointers are to avoid using raw `new` and `delete`, not pointers at all.

Answer (score -2):

Another way is change the signature of `f` and use it in a slightly different way:

```
void f(Base* base_ptr) {
    // take ownership inside the function
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base {base_ptr};
    // ...
}

// ...
auto derived = std::make_unique<Derived>();
f(derived.release());  // release ownership
```