# Move-only type returned into converting constructor

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, move-semantics, rvalue

The following code returns a move-only type that should then be converted to another type by a converting constructor.

```
#include <utility>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() {}
  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo(Foo&&) = default;
};

class Other
{
public:
  Other(Foo foo) {}
};


Other moo()
{
  Foo foo;
  return foo;
}

int main()
{
  moo();
}
```

This threw me an error with my compiler and could only be fixed by adding `std::move` to the return statement which is considered bad practice, because in general it prevents return value optimization. Shouldn't the identifier of a return statement be treated as rvalue first to satisfy conversions?

Is this code valid and which compiler is right here?

- g++, c++14: compiles: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f25ae94e8ca9c5c8
- g++-4.8, c++11: does not compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0402e3ebf97fd0e7
- clang++, c++14: does not compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/682d8ca93d3e2f6a

Comment: IIRC, C++11 and C++14 differ on this point.

Comment: @Jarod42 In that case I would expect both compilers to agree in C++14 mode.

Comment: The compilers don't have to agree on this. The sad thing is, that this sort of copy elision is only something they *may* do. Not something they *have* to do. Clang is allowed to completely disregard the fact it can substitute the copy for a move.

Comment: @user2079303 - It is very much optional. `[class.copy]` where this whole thing is described, doesn't obligate an implementation to elide anything. It only specifies pre-conditions for when an implementation is *allowed*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move  related

Comment: @StoryTeller I think you refer to the fact that some compilers may compile ill-formed code fine when they elide the copy of a non-copyable type. My question here focuses more on why the variable is not moved.

Comment: @StoryTeller and I didn't say that eliding would be obligated. I said that `foo` must be treated as an rvalue.

Comment: @StoryTeller [class.copy]/32 in the draft that I'm looking at.

Comment: Related to [why-is-move-constructor-not-picked-when-returning-a-local-object-of-type-derived](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039379/why-is-move-constructor-not-picked-when-returning-a-local-object-of-type-derived)

Comment: @StoryTeller note the **or** before that. It means that the conditions are logically disjunctive. It is sufficient that `return statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body` is satisfied, which it is.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not sure if I understood right, but does this mean only `Other(Foo&&)` would work? It still doesn't http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04d43c9257b9c78c It even tells explicitly: `no known conversion from 'Foo' to 'Foo &&'`, so it does not treat foo as rvalue.

Comment: @StoryTeller while I don't agree that standard uses or in an exclusive manner *exclisively*, it is a moot point. Only one of the possible conditions is satisfied, so it is irrelevant whether the "or" is inlcusive or exclusive. It only matters that it is not "and".

Comment: @user2079303 - You know what. We are mincing water over this for naught. The OP isn't returning an object that is of the same (possibly cv-qualified) type as the functions return value. The criteria for elision as specified in p31 are not met. So this is moot.

Comment: As I understand from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33972072/2684539 and [DR-9R5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1579). gcc would be correct, and clang seems to not have implemented the defect.

Comment: @StoryTeller that is exactly my point :) This is not about whether copy elision is optional; that is irrelevant. *If* copy elision were allowed, then treating `foo` as rvalue would be mandatory, which depends on whether copy elision allowance applies.

Comment: @user2079303 - You could have saved us both a lot of typing if you had just said my last comment directly.

Comment: @Jarod42 - The wording proposed by the DR still keeps *"overload resolution to select the **constructor for the copy**"*. If we are meant to return `Other` instead of `Foo` then this isn't a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't the identifier of a return statement be treated as rvalue first to satisfy conversions?

Yes and no. From [[class.copy]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#elision-3), as a result of [CWG 1579](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1579) (the wording here is copied from C++17, although it's the same in [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.copy#32). I find the bullets easier to read than the earlier grammar choice that would make James Joyce blush... ):

> In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> - If the expression in a `return` statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, or
> - [...]
>
> overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, or **if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object's type** (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue.

The first bullet applies here, so we first do overload resolution as if `foo` was an rvalue. This gets is to the `Other(Foo )` constructor by way of `Foo(Foo&& )`.

The first parameter of `Other(Foo )` is not an rvalue reference, so we should do overload resolution again considering the `foo` as an lvalue, which fails. This seems like an unnecessary restriction, but I'd call clang correct here. If you change the constructor to `Other(Foo&& )`, clang accepts it.

Comment: I give up. I'm not in any shape to make heads or tails of the wording here ATM. +1 (though you are quoting C++17, not C++14).

Comment: @StoryTeller It's the same wording in [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.copy#32), just much harder to read.

Comment: Hardly the same, or I wouldn't be so exasperated. My point being that it may be more pertinent to help decipher the wording in C++14 than bring the clearly stated C++17 quote.

Comment: @StoryTeller It's the same. "when the expression in a return statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body [...] overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object's type (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue."

Comment: Yeah, well... I say the preceding *"In the following copy-initialization contexts"* is sorely missing in C++14.

Comment: @Barry Thanks this seems to get close, but for me the change to `Other(Foo&&)` is not accepted by clang (3.8) (or the old gcc). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097854/move-only-type-returned-into-converting-constructor#comment79159327_46097854

Comment: @typ1232 *That*'s a clang bug, fixed by 3.9.1 at least.

Answer (score 2):

Barry's fine answer covers the standard rules, but I have a practical suggestion:

> and could only be fixed by adding `std::move` to the return statement which is considered bad practice, because in general it prevents return value optimization.

Your worry is unjustified. NRVO does not apply to conversions anyway, and RVO on the result of the move is allowed. The explicit move is fine.