# Convert unique_ptr<Derived> to unique_ptr<Base>

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

A simple code

```
class Base {};
class Derived : Base {};

unique_ptr<Base> Create() {
    unique_ptr<Base> basePtr = make_unique<Derived>(); // compile error
    return basePtr;
}
```

produce a compile error ("no suitable conversion"). I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018115/converting-stdunique-ptrderived-to-stdunique-ptrbase) where the solution is to use `std::move`. I tried this

```
unique_ptr<Derived> derived = make_unique<Derived>();
unique_ptr<Base> basePtr = std::move(derived); // compile error
```

but now `std::move` produces compile error. I also found [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401999/is-unique-ptrderived-to-unique-ptrbase-up-casting-automatic) where (if I understood it well) the cast should be automatic if we use

```
unique_ptr<Base> basePtr = make_unique<Derived>(new Derived()); //compile error
```

but this is also not working (compile error), and it is also not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514509/advantages-of-using-stdmake-unique-over-new-operator) to use `new` with smart pointers.

What would be the proper solution?

The only working solution I found so far

```
unique_ptr<Base> basePtr = unique_ptr<Base>((Base*)new Derived());
```

looks really ugly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your class is inheriting privately from the base class. This is the default for `class`, whereas the default for `struct` is public inheritance. This makes outside derived-to-base conversions invalid. `unique_ptr` handles derived-to-base conversions fine with public inheritance ([live example](https://godbolt.org/g/kRoznM)):

```
 class Base {};
 class Derived : public Base {};
                 ^^^^^^
```

As noted below, it's also important to add a virtual destructor to the base class when using `unique_ptr`, as polymorphic destruction relies on this for well-defined behaviour. `shared_ptr` wouldn't require this, but that's getting off-topic.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I didn't see that the other question uses struct.

Comment: Chris, it might be worth adding the virtual destructor to Base. As it stands, this is would result in UB in the above use case as Derived would not be properly destructed.

Answer (score -1):

The pattern is often used in pimpl idiom, so virtual destructor is necessary.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).