# Add unique_ptr of derived class to vector of base class unique_ptr

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I have a `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` that I want to add to a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`.

```
std::unique_ptr<Derived> derivedObject;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec;

vec.push_back(derivedObject) // Invalid arguments
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unique\_ptr to a base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473900/unique-ptr-to-a-base-class)

Answer (score 9):

unique_ptr guarantees that it's only one pointer that points to the memory, so you can't just copy it to the vector, you need to move it:

```
vec.push_back(std::move(derivedObject));
```

If you look at the unique_ptr constructors (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) you see, that this class doesn't implement the copy constructor, but implements move constructor (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

Answer (score 5):

This is because you cannot copy a `std::unique_ptr`. The problem is solvable using `std::move()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Base {
};

struct Derived : public Base {
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> derivedObject;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec;

    vec.push_back(std::move(derivedObject));    
               // ^^^^^^^^^^             ^
}
```

Here's a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7419e7e4d80c4056).

Comment: If this solution doesn't seem to be working, ensure the class inheritance is public.

Answer (score 3):

[cppreference about unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

> If T is a derived class of some base B, then std::unique_ptr < T > is implicitly convertible to std::unique_ptr < B >.

So, the problem is not of conversion failure.

> The class satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but not the requirements of either CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable.

This is what causes the failure.  `unique_ptr` can be *moved* but can't be *copied*, as that would break the single-ownership agreement.

---

So either use `std::move`, or use [**make_derived**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) directly:

```
vec.push_back(std::move(derivedObject));  //Option 1. When unique_ptr is already created.
OR,
vec.push_back(make_unique<Derived>());    //Option 2. New unique_ptr
```

Using option #2, you can **avoid** having a local variable for no purpose. Anyway upon performing `move` on `unique_ptr`, the object owned by the `unique_ptr` is disposed. [Demo.](http://ideone.com/rpPfDJ)

Comment: If you want to create object and push it to the vector at the same time, I'd rather recommend to use emplace_back function:
vec.emplace_back(new Derived());

Comment: @Marcin lose the `new`, and you're right.