# How to initialize std::unique_ptr in constructor?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, ifstream, unique-ptr

A.hpp:

```
class A {
  private:
   std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream> file;
  public:
   A(std::string filename);
};
```

A.cpp:

```
A::A(std::string filename) {
  this->file(new std::ifstream(filename.c_str()));
}
```

The error that I get is thrown:

```
A.cpp:7:43: error: no match for call to ‘(std::unique_ptr<std::basic_ifstream<char> >) (std::ifstream*)’
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why this is occurring? I've tried many different ways to get this to work but to no avail.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function) is related

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to initialize it through the *member-initializer list*:

```
A::A(std::string filename) :
    file(new std::ifstream(filename));
{ }
```

Your example was an attempt to call `operator ()` on a `unique_ptr` which is not possible.

Update: BTW, C++14 has [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique):

```
A::A(std::string filename) :
    file(std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(filename));
{ }
```

Comment: Alternatively call the `reset()` function on `file` to assign the `unique_ptr` if you need to do some checking in the constructor beforehand.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use member-initializer list. It is more preferable though.

Comment: @JohnJohn, if you're using Pimpl, you should use member-initializer list, since your std::unique_ptr is const.

Comment: Regarding the use of `file(new ...)` vs. `file(std::make_unique...)`: Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
A:A(std::string filename)
    : file(new std::ifstream(filename.c_str())
{
}
```