# How do I efficiently remove_if only a single element from a forward_list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, forward-list

Well I think the question pretty much sums it up. I have a forward_list of unique items, and want to remove a single item from it:

```
std::forward_list<T> mylist;
// fill with stuff

mylist.remove_if([](T const& value)
  {
    return value == condition;
  });
```

I mean, this method works fine but it's inefficient because it continues to search once the item is found and deleted. Is there a better way or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: you can simply `return value == condition;` in your lambda.

Comment: @Geoffroy yeah you're right, I just did it this way so I could add that `exit if this happens` line to clarify what I was after.

Comment: well it will look for other elements too, Is there's only one unique element to be deleted ?

Comment: You need a functionality like remove_first, but there is no such built-in function. Why not write one on your own? It is quite simple.

Comment: [`std::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of)

Comment: @P0W Returns an iterator *to* the element. To erase it, you need one *before* the element.

Comment: @P0W `adjacent_find` followed by `erase_after` does the trick, see my answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only want to remove the first match, you can use `std::adjacent_find` followed by the member `erase_after`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <iterator>

// returns an iterator before first element equal to value, or last if no such element is present
// pre-condition: before_first is incrementable and not equal to last
template<class FwdIt, class T>
FwdIt find_before(FwdIt before_first, FwdIt last, T const& value)
{
    assert(before_first != last);
    auto first = std::next(before_first);
    if (first == last) return last;
    if (*first == value) return before_first;
    return std::adjacent_find(first, last, [&](auto const&, auto const& R) { 
        return R == value; 
    });
}

int main() 
{
    auto e = std::forward_list<int>{};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (++e.before_begin() == end(e)) << "\n";
    std::cout << (find_before(e.before_begin(), end(e), 0) == end(e)) << "\n";

    auto s = std::forward_list<int>{ 0 };
    std::cout << (find_before(s.before_begin(), end(s), 0) == s.before_begin()) << "\n";

    auto d = std::forward_list<int>{ 0, 1 };
    std::cout << (find_before(d.before_begin(), end(d), 0) == d.before_begin()) << "\n";
    std::cout << (find_before(d.before_begin(), end(d), 1) == begin(d)) << "\n";
    std::cout << (find_before(d.before_begin(), end(d), 2) == end(d)) << "\n";

    // erase after
    auto m = std::forward_list<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5 };
    auto it = find_before(m.before_begin(), end(m), 3);
    if (it != end(m)) 
        m.erase_after(it);
    std::copy(begin(m), end(m), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/279fc613e705ed9e)

This will stop as soon as a match is found. Note that the `adjacent_find` takes a binary predicate, and by comparing only the second argument, we get an iterator before the element we want to remove, so that `erase_after` can actually remove it. Complexity is `O(N)` so you won't get it more efficient than this.

Comment: Nice use of `adjacent_find` (I wasn't even aware of this function). Have an upvote :-)

Comment: @Angew I used it before, but I also just read about it a few days ago on the std-proposals forum where it was used to show that a sequence was strictly increasing with `<` (instead of `<=`, as `std::is_sorted` would show). So it was kind of "fresh" in working memory.

Comment: hold on a second, you are going around down voting other answers when you are actually *hacking* `adjacent_find` to do what you want here? That's new...

Comment: @Angew ah, good point. It didn't, but now it does using `mylist.before_begin()`

Comment: @Nim the Standard says for `erase_after`: "Requires: The iterator following position is dereferenceable". An empty list has `begin() == end()` and dereferencing the `end()` (or any invalid) iterator is UB.

Comment: @Nim, no the `find_first_of` works fine with an empty list, and returns an iterator 1 after `before_begin()` (i.e. it returns `end()`), see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00f87cb7f5e74a60 Note that I only derefence the 2nd element in the lambda, and `adjacent_find` guarantees not to dereference if `std::next(first)==last`

Comment: @Nim btw, I don't consider this a hack of `adjacent_find`. Forward iterators are born to be processed by `adjacent_find` because you really need to do a look-ahead-by-one all the time because you can't look backwards in `O(1)`.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, that will work in practice. However, technically the `mylist.before_begin()` iterator is being dereferenced to produce the first (unused) argument to the lambda expression (third argument) in the first call to `std::find_first`, and since that is a non-dereferenceable iterator, this triggers undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I updated the answer with a small modification as discussed earlier to remove the UB. I also added a few more test cases for empty, singleton and doubleton lists, testing for first, last and missing elements. Thanks again for your input!

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, here's another short version

```
template< typename T, class Allocator, class Predicate >
bool remove_first_if( std::forward_list< T, Allocator >& list, Predicate pred )
{
    auto oit = list.before_begin(), it = std::next( oit );
    while( it != list.end() ) {
        if( pred( *it ) ) { list.erase_after( oit ); return true; }
        oit = it++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Good solution +1. I would have written `it=list.begin()` as initialisation to be somewhat more explicit, and `oit=it,++it;` at the end of the loop, but this is obviously just equivalent to what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Going to have to roll your own...

```
template <typename Container, typename Predicate>
void remove_first_of(Container& container, Predicate p)
{
  auto it = container.before_begin();
  for (auto nit = std::next(it); ; it = nit, nit = std::next(it))
  {
    if (nit == container.end())
      return;
    if (p(*nit))
    {
      container.erase_after(it);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

A more complete example...

Comment: @TemplateRex, this is a specialized algorithm for a special container, the OP is quite welcome to change the container type to be specific. Here though the *begin* is not the standard begin and would therefore be confusing to accept a simple range. Additionally, don't forget the `erase_after`!

Comment: I don't understand why you don't put nit != container.end() in the second statement of the for loop instead of a test at the beginning of the for-block. but it looks like the best answer

Answer (score 1):

<s>There is nothing in the standard library which would be directly applicable.</s> Actually, there is. See @TemplateRex's answer for that.

You can also write this yourself (especially if you want to combine the search with the erasure), something like this:

```
template <class T, class Allocator, class Predicate>
bool remove_first_if(std::forward_list<T, Allocator> &list, Predicate pred)
{
  auto itErase = list.before_begin();
  auto itFind = list.begin();
  const auto itEnd = list.end();
  while (itFind != itEnd) {
    if (pred(*itFind)) {
      list.erase_after(itErase);
      return true;
    } else {
      ++itErase;
      ++itFind;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: @TemplateRex This is a special algorithm for a special container, really. It's just a convenience wrapper for `erase_after` combined with the search. I've reflected your answer which uses a pure-`std` solution, but if you find yourself doing `erase_before(find_before_first())` over and over again, you might as well want to wrap this combo in a function.

Comment: writing a function is OK, but not with a hardcoded container parameter when a pair of forward iterators is all that is required. It's the `find_before_first` that is the essential primitive that needs to be wrapped, and that is not really specific for `forward_list`.

Comment: @TemplateRex If you want to wrap the `erase_after()` call as well, you *have to* pass the container. Yes, this function could just call your `find_before_first()` inside (and be much shorter), but it still could have a valid reason for existence.

Comment: OK, if you can  make a token edit, I'll remove the upvote. Still, the erase_after / find_first_before is short should enough that I wouldn't wrap it. But I can see your point that you might want to, although I'd rather SFINAE it on the existence of an `erase_after` member than to hardcode the `forward_list` as a parameter ;-)

Comment: @TemplateRex Done, thanks. Now the OP has 3 approaches to choose from: your `std` library usage, Nim's for generic container, and mine for `forward_list`. I think that's a nice result :-)

Comment: choices, schmoices... What happened to the One True Way? :-)

Comment: @TemplateRex Ask [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). They claim sites should have more than 1 answer per question to be healthy :-)

Comment: @TemplateRex can before_begin() be dereferenced, even though it does not use the value?

Comment: @abir [No](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf), `before_begin()` returns a "Returns: A non-dereferenceable iterator that, when incremented, is equal to the iterator returned by
`begin()`."

Answer (score 1):

This kind of stuff used to be a standard exercise when I learned programming way back in the early '80s. It might be interesting to to recall the solution, and compare that with what one can do in C++. Actually that was in Algol 68, but I won't impose that on you and give the translation into C. Given

```
typedef ... T;
typedef struct node *link;
struct node { link next; T data; };
```

one could write, realising that one needs to pass the *address* of the list head pointer if is to be possible to unlink the first node:

```
void search_and_destroy(link *p_addr, T y)
{
  while (*p_addr!=NULL && (*p_addr)->data!=y)
    p_addr = &(*p_addr)->next;
  if (*p_addr!=NULL)
  {
    link old = *p_addr;
    *p_addr = old->next; /* unlink node */
    free(old); /* and free memory */
  }
}
```

There are a lot of occurrences of `*p_addr` there; it is the last one, where it is the LHS of an assignment, that is the reason one needs the address of a pointer here in the first place. Note that in spite of the apparent complication, the statement `p_addr = &(*p_addr)->next;` is just replacing a pointer by the value it points to, and then adding an offset (which is 0 here).

One could introduce an auxiliary pointer *value* to lighten the code a bit up, as follows

```
void search_and_destroy(link *p_addr, T y)
{
  link p=*p_addr;
  while (p!=NULL && p->data!=y)
    p=*(p_addr = &p->next);
  if (p!=NULL)
  {
    *p_addr = p->next;
    free(p);
  }
}
```

but that is fundamentally the same code: any decent compiler should realise that the pointer value `*p_addr` is used multiple times in succession in the first example, and keep it in a register.

Now with `std::forward_list<T>`, we are not allowed access to the pointers that link the nodes, and get those awkward "iterators pointing one node before the real action" instead. Our solution becomes

```
void search_and_destroy(std::forward_list<T> list, T y)
{
  std::forward_list<T>::iterator it = list.before_begin();
  const std::forward_list<T>::iterator NIL = list.end();

  while (std::next(it)!=NIL && *std::next(it)!=y)
    ++it;
  if (std::next(it)!=NIL)
    list.erase_after(it);
}
```

Again we could keep a second iterator variable to hold `std::next(it)` without having to spell it out each time (not forgetting to refresh its value when we increment `it`) and arrive at essentially the answer by Daniel Frey. (We could instead try to make that variable a pointer of type `*T` equal to `&*std::next(it)` instead, which suffices for the use we make of it, but it would actually be a bit of a hassle to ensure it becomes the null pointer when `std::next(it)==NIL`, as the standard will not let us take `&*NIL`).

I cannot help feel that since the old days the solution to this problem has not become more elegant.