# Returning a lambda function with a move-capture

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I have a function that constructs a lambda function with a move-capture (C++1y only) and returns it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

function<int ()> makeLambda(unique_ptr<int> ptr) {
    return [ ptr( move(ptr) ) ] () {
        return *ptr;
    };
}

int main() {
    // Works
    {
        unique_ptr<int> ptr( new int(10) );
        auto function1 = [ ptr(move(ptr)) ] {
            return *ptr;
        };
    }

    // Does not work
    {
        unique_ptr<int> ptr( new int(10) );
        auto function2 = makeLambda( std::move(ptr) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, it seems as though upon returning, `unique_ptr<int>`'s copy constructor is called. Why is this/how can I get around this?

Link to paste: 
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b21c358db10c3933

Comment: What happens if you change `auto function1 = ...` to `function<int()> function1 = ...`. I think the problem is with using `std::function`, not with using return types.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00a26f08aef8944c

Comment: Well, it makes a difference. If I make the change, the first part no longer works.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: By the way, your code is very noisy. In modern C++, I would probably prefer to write it [like this](http://pastebin.com/ukHbXMqb).

Comment: @KerrekSB : Thanks. I do not usually write code like the above; just figured it would get more answers if it was easier to read.

Comment: @par: Hmm... I don't know if the extra text adds anything. You might argue that more people get bored and abandon the question if it's too long and too little of it pertains to the actual problem (which is your first function template). But it's your question :-)

Comment: The real question is why `std::function` isn't movable. Urgh.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Haha, that's true. Thanks. Minimize length, maximize legibility. Inversely proportional objectives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `std::function<int ()>` return type, which is attempting to make a copy of the lambda. This will fail because the copy constructor is implicitly deleted due to the presence of the `std::unique_ptr`. Instead of storing the lambda in a `std::function` object, use return type deduction, now the lambda will be moved.

```
auto makeLambda(unique_ptr<int> ptr) {
    return [ ptr( move(ptr) ) ] () {
        return *ptr;
    };
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4987f5ecb2cc4d0)

You should also probably change the argument type of `makeLambda` to `unique_ptr<int>&&`

Comment: Thanks. As for the &&, there is a pretty good argument for passing unique_ptr by value here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function

Comment: @par Thanks for that link, I'd not seen that before. Nicol does make a good argument for passing by value. However, in case of a move-only type, which is being passed to a function that unconditionally moves the object, I think I still prefer the rvalue reference argument. IMHO, the error message is a little clearer if someone attempts to pass an lvalue to the function.