# Seg. fault with std::unique_ptr and ctor

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, smart-pointers, move-semantics, unique-ptr

For a parser I am actually implementing I partially have these private functions within the parser:

**Parser private methods:**

```
    Token const* current_token() const;
    Token const* next_token();
    Token const* peek_token();

    std::unique_ptr<ast::Expression> parse_expression();
    std::unique_ptr<ast::TypeSpecifier> parse_type_specifier();
    std::unique_ptr<ast::VariableDeclarationStatement> parse_variable_declaration();
    std::unique_ptr<ast::Statement> parse_function_definition();
    std::unique_ptr<ast::Statement> parse_top_level_statement();
```

the implementation of the parse_variable_declaration method is this:

**parse_variable_declaration():**

```
std::unique_ptr<ast::VariableDeclarationStatement> Parser::parse_variable_declaration() {
    next_token(); // consume 'var'

    if (current_token()->get_type() != TokenTypes::identifier) {
        throw parser_error(current_token(), "", "expected identifier\n");
    }
    const auto id = current_token(); // store identifier
    next_token(); // consume identifier

    std::unique_ptr<ast::TypeSpecifier> type;
    std::unique_ptr<ast::Expression> expr;

    auto assignment_required = true;
    if (current_token()->get_type() == TokenTypes::op_colon) { // optional type specifier
        next_token(); // consume ':'

        type = parse_type_specifier();
        assignment_required = false;
    }

    if (assignment_required && current_token()->get_type() != TokenTypes::op_equals) {
        throw parser_error(current_token(), "", "expected equals operator\n");
    }

    if (current_token()->get_type() == TokenTypes::op_equals) {
        next_token(); // consume '='

        expr = parse_expression();
    }

    if (current_token()->get_type() != TokenTypes::op_semi_colon) {
        throw parser_error(current_token(), "", "expected semi-colon\n");
    }

    next_token(); // consume ';'

    DEBUG_STDERR("parsed: variable_declaration_statement\n");
    return std::make_unique<ast::VariableDeclarationStatement>(
        id->get_string(), std::move(type), std::move(expr));
}
```

the last line (the return) ends in a segmentation fault.
it basically calls the constructor of VariableDeclarationStatement:

**VariableDeclarationStatement ctor:**

```
VariableDeclarationStatement::VariableDeclarationStatement(
    std::string const& name,
    std::unique_ptr<TypeSpecifier> type_specifier,
    std::unique_ptr<Expression> expr
):
    m_name{name},
    m_type_specifier{std::move(type_specifier)},
    m_expr{std::move(expr)}
{}
```

I am debugging this things since yesterday and can't seem to find out why this does not work as intended. I want to build the Abstract Syntax Tree (parser output) with unique pointers to their child nodes (because they are the only owner of their childs which makes sense) - this is why I am try-harding to work with them.

**Console output: DEBUG_STDERR**

```
parsed: primitive_type_int // from parse_type_specifier()
parsed: integral_expression // from parse_expression()
parsed: variable_declaration_statement
[1]    12638 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./cion_compiler
```

Comment: Can't you run under a debugger? Should be pretty easy to track down what's going if you do. And how you use the return value of `Parser::parse_variable_declaration()` is probably relevant too.

Comment: why ctor parameter is not `std::unique_ptr<TypeSpecifier> &&type_specifier` ?

Comment: I'm wondering if you could make a [small, complete program](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces your problematic `return` statement.  Otherwise, you're just hoping that the source of your problem happens to be in the code you've chosen to show us.

Comment: @Slava Why should it be? It's a sink parameter, and the current signature makes it clear that the constructor takes onwership of the argument unconditionally.

Comment: @Praetorian I think when parameter is rvalue reference then it is clear that constructor moves the argument, is it not?

Comment: `id->get_string()` Your id is a pointer; are you sure it isn't null?

Comment: @Slava No, not really. All that makes clear is that the function takes an rvalue reference. What if I decide to test some condition internally and `move` based on the outcome? Admittedly, that may be indicative of a design flaw, but ignore that for now. [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114913/241631) discussing the various options when it comes to passing `unique_ptr`s around.

Comment: @Praetorian, good to know, thanks. I am pretty new for move semantics and rvalue references.

Comment: There isn't nearly enough specific code here, but I'm genuinely curious. How does your token engine *emit* tokens? Are they dynamically allocated with each invoke to `next_token()`, and if so, how can you possibly manage the memory of the *last* token when all you have left is a `const * const` dynamic link to it? This seriously needs to be run *in a debugger.*

Comment: @Slava For the sake of full disclosure, Scott Meyers has a different opinion on this, he prefers making the parameter type an rvalue reference because taking the argument by value might incur an additional move. IMHO, the default should be to take it by value and you fall back to taking it by rvalue reference if you know that moving the type is expensive, and you cannot afford that in your program.

Comment: @Slava I think that forcing the parameter to be an r-value reference prevents the compiler from performing copy/move elision when the parameter is constructed from a temporary (can someone correct me if I am wrong?). Passing sink arguments by value is actually the accepted way to do it.

Comment: You obtain your "id" from the `current_token()` function and then, you call `next_token()` several times to "consume" the tokens, as the comments say. Are you sure that "id" is still valid at the return statement? Are you sure that "id" has the correct type, since it is being inferred by "auto", maybe it resolves to a proxy that becomes invalid after `next_token` is called? Moving a unique-pointer is basically a trivial pointer copy operation, it should work regardless of whether the pointer is valid or not, that cannot be the source of the seg-fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move operations on unique pointers basically boil down to simple pointer copies. There is no reason why any implementation of `unique_ptr` would dereference the pointers in the process of moving them. Therefore, the likelihood that this operation is responsible for the seg-fault is virtually zero.

In your return-statement / constructor-call, you do have one (or more) very obvious pointer de-referencing, as part of the `id->get_string()` call.

For one, the `id` pointer is created as so:

```
  const Token* const id = current_token(); // store identifier
  next_token(); // consume identifier
```

Unless there is a guarantee that any pointer returned by `current_token()` will be valid until the end of time (or within the life-time of the current parsing operation), it is very possible that after the call to `next_token()`, the `id` pointer is invalid, i.e., pointing to a non-existent or defunct `Token` object.

Even if the `id` pointer still points to an existing `Token` object, it is possible that it is in a "zombie" state, and that obtaining a string from it, through `get_string()`, is an invalid operation.

If I were you, that is where I would be looking for the source of the seg-fault. You might also want to run this in a (memory-)debugger to get to the source of it, it will likely point you to the `get_string` function as the source of it, either during the dereferencing of the `this` pointer (the `id` pointer) or during the construction of the string itself. It could also point you towards the virtual-table look-up, if `get_string` is a virtual function in the `Token` class. Either way, I highly suspect that this is the cause of the seg-fault, because it is the only overtly dangerous code in what you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

As you guys correctly suggested the error was hidden in the suspicious id pointer.
The parser in my program receives Tokens via unique_ptr from the lexer and stores them right as the current token.
Therefore the method current_token() returned a pointer to a unique_ptr which gets removed as soon as the next call to next_token() takes place.
Storing the invalid pointer to the already removed Token in id caused the problem.

I fixed the code in several different ways.

First I changed the return types from the helper methods above from "Token const*" to "Token const&" and the id variable now only copies the get_string value and does no other pointer related operations.

With these changes the segmentation fault problem was successfully solved! =)