# access and move unique_ptr in a function call

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a segment similar to the following.

```
struct derive : base{
    derive(unique_ptr ptr): base{func(ptr->some_data), std::move(ptr)}{}
};
```

In theory, it should work. But since the compiler (vs2015) does not strictly follow the standard, the order of `func(ptr->some_data), std::move(ptr)` is undefined, i.e. `ptr` may be moved before accessed.

So my problem is how to make this segment work as expected?

**Complete code like this:**

```
#include <memory>

struct base {
    virtual ~base() = 0 {}

protected:
    base(std::unique_ptr<base> new_state) :
        previous_state{ std::move(new_state) } {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<base> previous_state;
};

struct derive_base : base {
    int get_a() const noexcept {
        return a;
    }
protected:
    derive_base(int const new_a, std::unique_ptr<base> new_state) :
        base{ std::move(new_state) }, a{ new_a } {}
private:
    int a;
};

struct final_state : derive_base {
    final_state(std::unique_ptr<base> new_state) :
        derive_base{ dynamic_cast<derive_base&>(*new_state).get_a(), std::move(new_state) } {}
};
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: I saw one just a second ago... honest. the last edit wiped it.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes.  My parenthesis stack got corrupted.

Comment: And what does the `base` constructor look like? Depending on that this call may already be safe.

Comment: @DrewDormann: I read it that way first as well

Comment: @Praetorian: No, it's safe regardless of the `base::base()` implementation, barring very serious compiler bugs (far worse than Visual C++'s usual level of noncompliance)

Comment: @BenVoigt How so? If `base` is also taking the `unique_ptr` by value, and VS2015 does not ensure left-right evaluation for list initialization, then the pointer might get moved before the first argument is evaluated. That won't be the case if the parameter type is `unique_ptr&&`

Comment: @DrewDormann not a day goes by mine doesn't do the same at some point.

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, it may be if the second parameter is used following the first. But it can be any order in general.

Comment: @Praetorian: Oh so you're thinking there may be an issue if there is NO base constructor at all?  Not what your comment said.  I have to think about this case some more...

Comment: @BenVoigt Now I'm confused (an SSCCE would avoid all of this!). I was thinking of the case where the `base` constructor in question is `base(result_of_func_type, unique_ptr)` as opposed to `base(result_of_func_type, unique_ptr&&)`. If VS is non-compliant in order of evaluation the former is not safe but the latter is.

Comment: @Praetorian: And aggregate initialization could behave still differently (but the new comment concerning order of declaration rules this out)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix it using constructor chaining:

```
struct derive : base
{
  private:
    derive(const D& some_data, unique_ptr<X>&& ptr) : base{some_data, std::move(ptr)} {}
  public:
    derive(unique_ptr<X> ptr): derive(func(ptr->some_data), std::move(ptr)) {}
};
```

Reason: As explained in my other answer, the call to `func` definitely takes place before the delegated constructor call, while actually moving the `unique_ptr` (as opposed to merely changing its value category) definitely takes place inside.

Of course, this relies on another C++11 feature which Visual C++ may or may not have gotten right.  Happily, [delegating constructors are listed as supported since VS2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx).

---

An even better thing to do is just **always accept `std::unique_ptr` arguments by reference, and by rvalue reference if you plan to steal from them**.  (And if you won't steal the content, why do you care what type of smart pointer the caller has?  Just accept a raw `T*`.)

If you used

```
struct base
{
    virtual ~base() = 0 {}

protected:
    base(std::unique_ptr<base>&& new_state) :
        previous_state{ std::move(new_state) } {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<base> previous_state;
};

struct derive_base : base
{
    int get_a() const noexcept {
        return a;
    }
protected:
    derive_base(int const new_a, std::unique_ptr<base>&& new_state) :
        base{ std::move(new_state) }, a{ new_a } {}
private:
    int a;
};

struct final_state : derive_base
{
    final_state(std::unique_ptr<base>&& new_state) :
        derive_base{ dynamic_cast<derive_base&>(*new_state).get_a(), std::move(new_state) } {}
};
```

you wouldn't have had the problem in the first place, and the caller requirements are completely unchanged (an rvalue must be provided, since `unique_ptr` is uncopyable anyway)

---

The rationale for making this a universal rule is as follows: pass by value allows either copying or moving, whichever is more optimal at the call site.  But `std::unique_ptr` is non-copyable, so the actual parameter MUST be an rvalue anyway.

Comment: It is a solution. I will accept this without better solutions.

Comment: With your new edit, I would wonder whether it is better to accept `unique_ptr` by rvalue reference in general?

Comment: @user1535111: Yes, if you plan to steal from them.  Otherwise use `const unique_ptr&`.  That's why I said "always".

Comment: You already got a +1 from me for the first half, but I disagree with the second. I'm of the opinion that you should take the `unique_ptr` by value if you plan on taking ownership, taking by rvalue ref leaves it ambigous whether you actually moved from it or not. See NicolBolas' [excellent answer on this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8114913/241631).

Comment: @Praetorian: This of course is the case that Nicol didn't address, and probably will change his answer.  I left a comment there to bring it to his attention.

Comment: I guess the bug is now fixed, so there's no longer any reason to consume a smart-pointer by rvalue-reference?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Pass-by-rvalue reference is still the best practice when taking over ownership.

Comment: @BenVoigt: why is it best practice to use pass-by-rvalue reference? I saw you mention https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function#comment45019080_8114913 that the undefined order of argument evaluation was the reason. But I don't see how that affects functional behavior in the general case. So why would pass-by-rvalue-ref be better than pass-by-value? Especially given the fact that pass-by-value gives a strong guarantee that the passed argument will be moved from, whereas rvalue-ref just permits it.

Answer (score 1):

The order is indeed undefined, but that doesn't matter because `std::move` doesn't actually move from the pointer, it only changes the value category.

<strike>The call to `func(ptr->some_data)` **will** take place before the pointer is moved, because the first is argument evaluation and the latter happens inside the base constructor, and argument evaluation always is ordered before a function call.</strike>

If it makes you feel better, you can write it as the 100% equivalent:

```
derive(unique_ptr<X> ptr): base{func(ptr->some_data), (unique_ptr<X>&&)ptr}{}
```

Edit: the actual move *doesn't* take place inside the called function, if the parameter is pass by-value.  But who does such a thing with `unique_ptr`s?

Comment: @AMostMajestuousCapybara: It's not supposed to be pretty.  Just clear.  The elegant way is to keep using `std::move`

Comment: In fact, `move` takes place in first in my case.

Comment: @user1535111: The call to `std::move`, which is non-destructive?  Or the call to the move-constructor of `unique_ptr`?  The two are very different things.

Comment: @BenVoigt I mean the variable (e.g. `m_ptr`) that accepts `std::move(ptr)` is declared in the base of `base`, i.e. `m_ptr` is declared before `m_other_data`.

Comment: @user1535111 Can you please post these details in the question? And preferably make it compilable.