# Why does calling a function on seperate lines change the result in c++?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

It seems that for some reason when I try to call two functions on the same line, the first function receives an nullptr from ".get()" as the first argument

```
getSomePtr(someUniquePtr.get(), someArray)->moveUniquePtr(std::move(someUniquePtr));
```

But when separating these functions in to two separate lines, everything seems to work:

```
auto* somePtr = getSomePtr(someUniquePtr.get(), someArray);
somePtr->moveUniquePtr(std::move(someUniquePtr));
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you try with brackets enclosing getSomePtr(someUniquePtr.get(), someArray)?

Comment: Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336207/access-and-move-unique-ptr-in-a-function-call).  Depending on your C++ version, it may be unspecified whether your pointer is moved first or accessed first.

Comment: What are the types involved? The function prototypes? The effect of `moveUniquePtr(std::move(someUniquePtr)` can be vastly different depending on the parameter type that function expects.

Comment: @DrewDormann I am unaware that the standard has changed regarding evaluation order of function arguments. AFAIK, all C++ versions allow them to be evaluated in any order prior to invocation.

Comment: @Dúthomhas • see the [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) section, which mentions that the C++17 standard changed regarding the order of evaluation of function arguments.

Comment: I've read that page many, many times. All C++17 adds is language specifically stating that the order of argument evaluation is unspecified. It didn’t actually change anything.

Comment: @Dúthomhas the changes are described, perhaps in clearer language, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15168020/16287)

Comment: OK, I, in my very tired state, was talking only about arguments to functions. You all are talking about the special case that is, not surprisingly, completely on-topic here... Sorry about that. Yes, C++17 clarifies that everything LHS of -> is sequenced before RHS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When evaluating an expression, function arguments are evaluated before the function that takes those arguments is called.

However, outside that rule, the compiler gets to choose the order of evaluation.  It looks like, in your first case, it chose to evaluate `moveUniquePtr` before evaluating `someUniquePointer.get()`.  Because one sub-expression modifies the state used in the other sub-expression, the result of the overall expression is not well-defined.

Splitting the expression into sequential statements, as in your second case, explicitly chooses the order of evaluation, and is the right thing to do in cases like this.

Comment: Splitting the expression into sequential statements also make it much easier to read. <g>