# How do I construct an object that has a unique_ptr member?

Tags: c++, inheritance, unique-ptr

I have a base class:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(??? new_p) : p(new_p) {} 
    std::unique_ptr<MyType> p;
}
```

And a derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base {
    Derived(??? new_p) : Base(new_p) {}
}
```

What type do I replace the question marks with if I want to construct `Derived`? Other changed are also fine. I want to make sure `Derived` can be constructed without copying the `MyType` that is pointed to by `p`.

Comment: How about `MyType *`?

Comment: I tried that and had errors with the `MyType` getting `free`d before I expected it. Maybe that was a different problem,

Comment: Ownership of MyType* will guide decision for what you should use for ???. This will range from using std::unique_ptr to just MyType*. In both cases you may also like to check if MyType needs to be deep copied or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want to support - either or both of the constructors below make sense, from `MyType*` or a `std::unique_ptr<MyType>&&`, which requires a movable `unique_ptr` be supplied by the caller.  Simply using `std::unique_ptr<MyType>` works too, because `std::unique_ptr` has a constructor from other movable instances... just a matter of taste whether you want to emphasise the necessarily-transient nature of the caller's incoming `unique_ptr` in your own code.

```
class Base
{
  public:
    Base(MyType* new_p) : p(new_p) { } 
    Base(std::unique_ptr<MyType>&& new_p) : p(std::move(new_p)) { } 

    std::unique_ptr<MyType> p;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    Derived(MyType* new_p) : Base(new_p) { }
    Derived(std::unique_ptr<MyType>&& new_p) : Base(std::move(new_p)) { }
};
```

See it running [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13de3a9e6b52345f)

Comment: When I try `Base(std::unique_ptr<MyType>&& new_p) : p(std::move(new_p)) { }` I get an error about `Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<MyType>`, maybe due to MyType being abstract? I didn't think that would be relevant, but maybe it is.

Comment: @Drew Is the error happening when your caller's passing a named variable without `std::move()`?  It should work for temporaries (technically, expiring values) and when `std::move()` explicitly grants it permission to steal the caller's variable's state.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize I had to `move` in the caller as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace `???` with `std::unique_ptr<MyType>` and then `std::move` it in the mem-initializer.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(std::unique_ptr<MyType> new_p) : p(std::move(new_p)) {} 
    std::unique_ptr<MyType> p;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    Derived(std::unique_ptr<MyType> new_p) : Base(std::move(new_p)) {}
};
```

You could also use `std::unique_ptr<MyType>&&` instead of `std::unique_ptr<MyType>` and avoid the `std::move`s but I prefer the by-value approach for the reasons listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114913/241631).

I would recommend against taking a `MyType *` argument. The problem with that solution is that it doesn't convey to the user your intent of taking ownership of the pointer passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Edit to note I'm using string as the type only to make it easier to read, you must replace it with your type.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Base {
public:
    Base(std::unique_ptr<std::string> new_p) 
      : p(std::move(new_p)) {} 
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> p;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(std::unique_ptr<std::string> new_p) 
      : Base(std::move(new_p)) {}
};

int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> text(new std::string("Hello world"));

    Derived a(std::move(text));

    std::cout << *(a.p);
}
```

Comment: you  should use std::move instead of std::forward. You have rvalue references not forwarding one

Comment: Modified already, but consider that forward by definition keeps the "value type", lvalue or rvalue. "When used according to the following recipe in a function template, forwards the argument to another function with the value category it had when passed to the calling function"