# In c++ how do I go about using pointers to get the average of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm new to programming and I'm still having trouble with arrays, pointers, and functions. I'd like to know whats wrong with this and how I can fix it. Specifically why the pointer isn't working with the function. Here is the program I'm trying to write: Write a program that DYNAMICALLY creates a pointer to an array large enough to hold a user-defined number of test scores. Once all the scores are entered (in the main function), the array should be passed to a function that  RETURNS a DOUBLE for the average score. In the user output, the average score should be formatted with two decimals. Use pointer notation; do not use array notation .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

double getAverage(int, int);

int main()
{ 
    int size = 0;
    cout << "How many scores will you enter? ";
cin >> size;

unique_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[size]);


cout << endl;
int count = 0;

//gets the test scores

for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter the score for test " << (count + 1) << ": ";
    cin >> ptr[count];
    cout << endl;
}
//display test scores
cout << "The scores you entered are:";
for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    cout << " " << ptr[count];
cout << endl;

double avg;
avg = getAverage(ptr, size);
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint << endl;

cout << "The average is " << avg << endl;

return 0;
}

double getAverage(int *ptr, int size)
{
double average1;
double total = 0;
for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
{
    total = total + *(ptr + count);
}
average1 = total / size;

return average1;
}
```

Comment: There are two distinct functions named `getAverage` in your program. One is declared to take two `int`s but never implemented; this is the one you are trying to call from `main`, with wrong argument types. The other one takes `int*` and `int` - this one is implemented, but never called.

Comment: [How can I pass unique_ptr into a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30905487/669576)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your function `getAverage()` has different prototype than that you defined. And secondly you try to pass `std::unique_ptr<int []>` object into a function that instead expects a `int*`. But `std::unique_ptr<int []>` is a different type than `int*` and not implicitly convertible. 
So to pass `int *`use `std::unique_ptr::get` function.
like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

double getAverage(int *, int);

int main()
{ 
    int size = 0;
    cout << "How many scores will you enter? ";
cin >> size;

unique_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[size]);


cout << endl;
int count = 0;

//gets the test scores

for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter the score for test " << (count + 1) << ": ";
    cin >> ptr[count];
    cout << endl;
}
//display test scores
cout << "The scores you entered are:";
for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    cout << " " << ptr[count];
cout << endl;

double avg;
avg = getAverage(ptr.get(), size);
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint << endl;

cout << "The average is " << avg << endl;

return 0;
}

double getAverage(int *ptr, int size)
{
double average1;
double total = 0;
for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
{
    total = total + *(ptr + count);
}
average1 = total / size;

return average1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It's frustrating how the little things can really upset a program.

Answer (score 0):

In the assignment there is written

> Use pointer notation; do not use array notation

This means that you should not use subscripting.

In main the variable `ptr` is declared as having the type `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`.

```
unique_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[size]);
```

You are trying to pass it to the function `getAverage`

```
avg = getAverage(ptr, size);
```

that has the corresponding parameter of the type `int`.

```
double getAverage(int, int);
```

Though then you defined the function as having the parameter of the type `int *` in any case there is no explicit conversion from the type `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` to the type `int *`. You should use method `get` of the smart pointer.

Also the function parameter should be declared like `const int *` because the array is not changed in the function.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>

double getAverage(const int *a, size_t n)
{
    double total = 0.0;

    for (const int *p = a; p != a + n; ++p) total += *p;

    return n == 0 ? total : total / n;
}

int main()
{
    size_t n = 0;

    std::cout << "How many scores will you enter? ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[n]);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( int *current = ptr.get(); current != ptr.get() + n; ++current )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the score for test " << ++i << ": ";
        std::cin >> *current;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The scores you entered are:";
    for (const int *current = ptr.get(); current != ptr.get() + n; ++current)
    {
        std::cout << " " << *current;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    double avg = getAverage( ptr.get(), n );

    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << std::showpoint;

    std::cout << "\nThe average is " << avg << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
How many scores will you enter? 10

Enter the score for test 1: 1
Enter the score for test 2: 2
Enter the score for test 3: 3
Enter the score for test 4: 4
Enter the score for test 5: 5
Enter the score for test 6: 6
Enter the score for test 7: 7
Enter the score for test 8: 8
Enter the score for test 9: 9
Enter the score for test 10: 10

The scores you entered are: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

The average is 5.50
```

Answer (score -1):

You almost had it.  Just need to change this chunk:

```
using namespace std;

double getAverage(int*, int); // <--here

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    cout << "How many scores will you enter? ";
    cin >> size;
    int *ptr = new int[size]; //<--and here (but you'll need to delete it later)
    //unique_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[size]);
```

I don't recommend mixing smart pointers and standard pointers until you have a better understanding of standard pointers.  edit:  I mean mixing them in terms of the *same* effective pointer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with handing out a raw pointer from `std::unique_ptr::get()`.

Comment: Unless the unique_ptr goes out of scope while the raw pointer is being used.  But you're certainly right for this example.