# Error C2664 'BOOL CryptBinaryToStringW(const BYTE *,DWORD,DWORD,LPWSTR,DWORD *)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'std::unique_ptr' to 'LPWSTR'

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I am getting the below error when compiling the C++ project.

> Error C2664   'BOOL CryptBinaryToStringW(const BYTE *,DWORD,DWORD,LPWSTR,DWORD *)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'std::unique_ptr>' to 'LPWSTR'

at the below line of code:

```
CryptBinaryToString(reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(strData.c_str()), dwSize,
        dwOptions, pwszBuffer, &dwLength);
```

And also I am getting the below error:

> Error C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::unique_ptr>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

at the below line:

```
sBase64 = pwszBuffer;
```

**Below is the complete code:**

```
bool EMRReader::EncodeBase64(DWORD dwSize, const std::string& strData, wstring& sBase64)
{
    DWORD dwOptions = CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 | CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF;
    DWORD dwLength = 0;

    BOOL bRet = CryptBinaryToString(reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(strData.c_str()), dwSize,
        dwOptions, 0, &dwLength);

    if (!bRet)
        return bRet;

    std::unique_ptr<std::wstring> pwszBuffer = std::make_unique<std::wstring>(dwLength + 1);
    if (!pwszBuffer)
        return FALSE;

    SecureZeroMemory(pwszBuffer.get(), (dwLength + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    CryptBinaryToString(reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(strData.c_str()), dwSize,
        dwOptions, pwszBuffer, &dwLength);

    sBase64 = pwszBuffer;

    return TRUE;
}
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve these errors?

Comment: 1) Why `std::unique_ptr<std::wstring>` instead of `std::wstring`? 2) What's unclear about the error? `pwszBuffer->data ()` instead of `pwszBuffer` in `CryptBinaryToString` call (note, to use it, you need to compile your program with C++-17)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)`<wstring>` object to a variable of type `wstring` that is not allowed. If you want to assign the value of `pwszBuffer` to a variable of type `wstring`, you should get the `unique_ptr`'s value and then assign it to the variable.

You can get the value of `std::unique_ptr` by calling its `*` operator:

`sBase64 = *pwszBuffer;`

---

Edit: If you want to pass a `std::unique_ptr` to a function, you have two ways:

1. Pass it by reference:

```cpp
void func(std::unique_ptr<std::wstring>& input_ptr) {
    // Do something...
}
```

and then use it simply:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<std::wstring> function_input;
func(function_input);
```

Or 2. If you want to pass it by value, move it:

```cpp
void func(std::unique_ptr<std::wstring>& 
input_ptr) {
    // Do something...
}
```

and then pass it with [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move):

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<std::wstring> function_input;
func(std::move(function_input));
```

You should be aware that in this case after moving the `function_input`, It owns nothing and holds a `nullptr` and you **shouldn't use** it out of the `func`.

[related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905560/9200752)

Comment: Thank you @Mrazimi, I am also getting the below error:   Error C2664 'BOOL CryptBinaryToStringW(const BYTE *,DWORD,DWORD,LPWSTR,DWORD *)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'std::unique_ptr<std::wstring,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'LPWSTR'

Comment: In the below line of code:                CryptBinaryToString(reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(strData.c_str()), dwSize,
  dwOptions, pwszBuffer, &dwLength);

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder I've edited the answer and added the solution for this error.