# c++ auto_ptr destroyed when passed into a function

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, auto-ptr

Suppose that we have

```
void UsePointer (auto_ptr <CSomeClass> spObj)
{
    spObj->DoSomething();
}
```

and we have a main function:

```
int main()
{
    auto_ptr <CSomeClass> spObject (new CSomeClass ());
    UsePointer (spObject);
    // spObject->DoSomthing (); would be invalid.
}
```

The book says "the object was destroyed when UsePointer() returned, because variable spObj went out of scope, hence destroyed"

My question is:

1. Is the pointer copied when passed into UsePointer function? Hence the owernship is transferred?
2. What do I need to if want spObject not be destroyed? Do I need to pass this pointer by reference?

Also this book is a bit outdated - does the same hold for unique_ptr in c++ 11?

Comment: Forget that `std::auto_ptr` ever existed. It's just bad.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen does std::unique_ptr behave the same way if we change auto_ptr to unique_ptr?

Comment: Whether you are using auto_ptr or unique_ptr, there is no reason to pass it as such to the function if you are not changing the reference count. Just passing the raw pointer is more effective. See also https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/ and yes, I agree with @Yksisarvinen, don't use auto_ptr

Comment: Regarding your question - `unique_ptr` wouldn't compile snd report and error instead. `unique_ptr` as its name stands is "unique" and there must not be two unique_ptr to the same object. `shared_ptr` has reference counter and it can be copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the pointer copied when passed into UsePointer function? Hence the owernship is transferred?

Yes. Unless the function parameter is reference qualified, arguments pass by value. For `auto_ptr` that involves copying, and thus passing ownership.

> What do I need to if want spObject not be destroyed? Do I need to pass this pointer by reference?

You could. But better yet, pass a reference to the object itself. A function shouldn't accept smart pointers unless manipulation of the ownership is involved. If it just needs to do something with pointee, accept a `CSomeClass const&` and pass `*spObject`.

> Also this book is a bit outdated - does the same hold for unique_ptr in c++ 11?

Yes. With the difference that `unique_ptr` is not copyable, and so cannot pass its ownership away implicitly. To pass a `unique_ptr`, it must be moved explicitly. The appearance of `std:move` in the code that passes the pointer into the function gives an explicit visual cue that ownership changes.

Comment: I don't 100% understand the last bit -  what happens  if we have "void UsePointer (auto_ptr <CSomeClass> spObj)" - is the object destroyed? (or is this use case completely forbidden because)

Comment: @Lost1 - I'm not sure I understand you. The function parameter `spObj` exists only during the function call. When the function returns, the parameter is destroyed. If the parameter was initialized to own a pointer to another object, then that object gets destroyed too along with the parameter. That's the same for both `auto_ptr` and `unique_ptr`. The only difference is in how they can get initialized.

Comment: What I meant is that - is "void UsePointer (unique_ptr <CSomeClass> spObj)" disallowed because unique_ptr cannot be copied?

Comment: I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905487/how-can-i-pass-stdunique-ptr-into-a-function answers my question?

Comment: @Lost1 - Of course it's not disallowed. You can declare the function and call it just fine. Only difference is that to construct the function parameter you'd need to pass in `UsePointer(std::move(spObject));`

Comment: Yes. I understand this now - cannot pass in the unique_ptr directly.