# std::vector - why does the element still exist after invoking delete?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector

I have this code I don't understand why I need to `delete` and then `pop_back()`.
Can I do it in 1 operation only ?

```
struct T
 {
    T(int n):x(n){};
    int print() {
       return x; 
    };
    private:
        int x;
 };

int main(int argv,char** argc)
{
    std::vector t = { new T(1),new T(2)};
    delete t.back();
    std::cout << t.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.back()->print() << std::endl;

    t.pop_back();
    std::cout << t.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.back()->print() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output - as you can see after `delete` it looks like the vector is still holding the element witout the object:

```
2
179185600
1
1
```

My question is why do I need `delete` and then remove , can't same operation be done in single command ?

Comment: @ynn and who's going to free the memory from the calls to `new`??

Comment: Did you intend to create a vector of pointers?

Comment: you do not *have to* use `new` and `delete`. Whoever told you that was wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1. The issues in your code:**

This line:

```
delete t.back();
```

Is not removing any element from the `std::vector`. Your `std::vector` is holding pointers, and it will continue to hold the same pointers.
What the line above does is deallocate the object **pointed by** the element in the `std::vector`.

This line (the 1st occurance):

```
std::cout << t.back()->print() << std::endl;
```

Invokes UB ([Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) because you derefernce a pointer after it has beed `delete`ed.

Then after:

```
t.pop_back();
```

The last pointer (the one that you `delete`ed, i.e. freed) is removed from the `std::vector`, and `t.back()` is the other pointer you inserted, which is still valid.

---

**2. A different approach - avoid pointers:**

Having wrote all that, in this case you do not actually need to deal with pointers at all.
You can use `std::vector<T>`, (instead of `T*` like you did) and store the elements by value. You will not need to `new` or `delete` anything.

Code example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    T(int n) :x(n) {};
    int print() { return x; };
private:
    int x;
};

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    std::vector t = { T{1}, T{2} };
    std::cout << t.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.back().print() << std::endl;
    t.pop_back();
    std::cout << t.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.back().print() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
2
1
1
```

---

**3. Using smart pointers:**

If you need to use pointers, use smart pointers (like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) instead of raw ones. The benefit is that the deallocation is done automatically.
`std::unique_ptr` is the more light-weight and should be the default one. Use `std::shared_ptr` if you need shared ownership.

Code example (with the same output as above):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct T
{
    T(int n) :x(n) {};
    int print() { return x; };
private:
    int x;
};

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> t;
    t.push_back(std::make_unique<T>(1));
    t.push_back(std::make_unique<T>(2));
    std::cout << t.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.back()->print() << std::endl;
    t.pop_back();
    std::cout << t.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.back()->print() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so if i understand you right the delete only delete the object created , not the poiner which points to the object , right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Added an example how to avoid pointers at all in this case.

Comment: The problem is that this object is huge and i do not want to copy it by value on each operation , i like it to be created one in memory . also this object in the original code hold state which i like to manage in 1 palce

Comment: In this case you can use a smart pointer like `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @user63898 Then you should use a smart pointer (`unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`). Or maybe look at move semantics and avoid copying that way.

Comment: what is the best to use ?

Comment: @user63898 or use [PIMPL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) to store dynamically allocated internal state managed by object itself.

Comment: @user63898 They all do slightly different things, which is best depends on the details of what you are trying to do. I guess `shared_ptr` is the most generally applicable.

Comment: so now if i convert it to unique_ptr , what is better to pass it as fun argument using std::move or pass by reference i mean looking at this acceptble answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905487/how-can-i-pass-stdunique-ptr-into-a-function

Comment: It depends on the case. But if you have a `std::vector` storing some smart pointers you usually don't want to `move` them into a function. You can either use a `std::shared_ptr` which manages ref-count via copy semantics, or pass the `.get()` method of the `unique_ptr` if this function just need to access the pointer without keeping it. Maybe you'd like to post a new question (because it is actually a new issue) with details about your case.

Comment: good advice here the new question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75333777/convert-c98-code-to-new-c17-code-when-using-stdvector-of-pointers

Answer (score 3):

In your code there are two distinct types of objects to be considered.

The elements in the vector are pointers to `T`, `T*`. The lifetime of those pointers is managed by the vector. You can add or remove them via member methods of the vector.

Then there are the objects you decided to manage manually via the raw pointers in the vector. They are instances of `T`. Because you used `new` to create them you must use `delete` to delete them.

The vector cannot know about this relation between the pointers (the elements in the vector) and the `T` objects. It was your decision to manage them manually. You do not have to do that.

Chances are high that you either want a `std::vector<T>`. Or if for some reason (there is none in your code) you need to have the `T`s allocated dynamically, then you would use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`.

---

Now this line:

```
delete t.back();
```

deletes the `T`, but the pointer is still in the vector. It is an invalid pointer, the object is was pointing to is no longer alive. When you call `t.back()->print()` your code invokes undefined behavior. You cannot use an already deleted object. If you do, anything can happen. This has nothing to do with the vector, it is similar to

```
T* t = new T();   // create object
delete t;         // delete it 
t->print();       // use it -> !!! undefined behavior !!!
```

Instead of this you should write

```
T t;
t.print();
```

---

In case you are coming from Java, you must unlearn to use `new` to create objects. The way to create objects in C++ is not via `new`.

Comment: Tnx , what do you mean the way to create object not via new ? so via what ?

Comment: @user63898 like in the other answer. I considered to rewrite your code but it would be just the same as in the other answer.

Comment: @user63898 for now you can forget that `new` exists. It is very advanced, by the time you need it you will know. If you find a beginners tutorial that uses `new` [but not telling you how not to use it], you know that the tutorial is not worth its price

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why i need delete and then remove , can't same
> operation done in single command ?

There would be 6 answers from me to your question and Let this be your introduction to Pointers , Stack and the Heap.

1.) `new` operator "Allocates" memory on the **heap** not the **stack**,Create that Object (Using it's Constructors) then return a **Pointer** to the Object that is now on the Heap, hence the need for using the `delete` operator to "De-allocate" the memory you have requested and "Destroy" the created Object.

2.) `delete` "De-Allocates" the memory from heap and "Destroy" the created Object, and it **does not** remove it from the vector

3.)`t.pop_back()` will remove the Pointer element from the vector but **will not** de-allocate and Destroy the object the Pointer is Pointing too.

4.) It can't be done with one line since you have requested to allocate a **Memory on the heap** that can fit `struct T` inside via the `new` keyword. By using the keyword `new`  the vector `std::vector t` is not storing an Object `struct T`,[`std::vector<T>`] instead storing **Pointers** to an Object of `struct T` [`std::vector<T*>`] since you did not explicitly Say what the Vector would Hold.

5.) Heap Allocated memory is perpetual , meaning it will always be there and labeled "In Use". Neither the Program, Runtime nor the O.S. can use it to allocate a new Memory Region on the heap unless you explicitly de-allocate and destroy it when using `delete`, Essentially saying *"I'm done with this memory location thank you You may now destroy this object and re-use the memory)".* or the Program Closes / Ends. So every `new` or `new[]` **must** be accompanied by `delete` or `delete[]` somewhere in the code when that variable is no longer in use anywhere in the program.

6.) After you understand the behavior of **Heap** / **Dynamic** Variables have a look at **Smart Pointers**. Which Handles the destruction of an object for you automatically. If you are coming from Managed Languages, you might want to read up on "Object Lifetimes" on C++.

The following Code will help you visualize my answer.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct T
 {
    T(int n):x(n){};
    int print() {
       return x; 
    };
    // Replaces the Value of X
    void SetX(int n){x=n;};
    private:
        int x;
 };

 int main(int argv,char** argc)
{

    // We explicitly Say that the Vector is holding a Pointers to an object struct T
    std::vector<T*> t;
    // Insert New Elements to the Vector
    t.push_back(new T(1));
    t.push_back(new T(2));

    // Will show that there are 2 elements in the vector.
    std::cout << "Size of Vector Is " << t.size() << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Assign the Last Element to a Pointer of T.
    T* pointerToT = NULL;
    pointerToT = t.back();

    // Print the Memory Address and value of pointerToT and the Last Element
    // And we can see they are the same location and holds the same value.
    std::cout << "The Memory Location of pointerToT is " << pointerToT << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The Memory Location of t.back() is " << t.back() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The Value of X in pointerToT is " << pointerToT->print() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The Value of X in t.back() is " << t.back()->print() <<std::endl << std::endl;
    
    //Removes the Last Element of the Vector
    t.pop_back();

    // Will show that there is only 1 element in the vector.
    std::cout << "Size of Vector Is " << t.size() << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Print the Memory Address of pointerToT and the Value of X
    // And as we can see pointerToT is still holding the same location
    // and still holding the value 2, since the program knows that
    // The memory Location is "Still" in use and not yet De-Allocated 
    // ready to be re-used and the object not yet destroyed.
    std::cout << "The Value of X after pop_back() is " << pointerToT->print() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The Memory Location of pointerToT after pop_back is " << pointerToT << std::endl << std::endl;
    
    
    //De-Allocate the Memory and Destroy the Object that was created by t.push_back(new T(2));
    delete pointerToT;
    
    // Prints the value of X, that is stored in the memory on the heap that it's pointing to. 
    // This Value may or may not be 2 if it is now used other parts of the Code 
    // which we call an Undefined Behaviour.
    // On a Larger Program this could and would Cause a Segmentation fault or 
    // an Access Violation since this is now a Memory Region that is not explicitly
    // Allocated for pointerToT , to the Member Variable X, nor
    // The Last Element of the Vector and may now be in use by other variables and that the object is Destroyed already destroyed.
    std::cout << "The Memory Location of pointerToT after delete is " << pointerToT << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The Value of X after Delete is " << pointerToT->print() << std::endl;
    
    // This is also an undefined Behaviour since you are now accessing and modifying 
    // a Memory Location that is not Allocated for pointerToT . But would show 
    // that the value of X is now 10. So only delete(Destroy)when you are sure you are not going to be
    // accessing that variable again.
    pointerToT->SetX(10);
    std::cout << "The Value of X after SetX() is " << pointerToT->print() << std::endl;
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fwiw, "stack" and "heap" are colloquial terms in this context. C++ never mentions them. Official terms are automatic vs dynamic storage duration.

Comment: also your explaination is not complete. From what you write there would be no difference to `malloc` and `free`, but there is. `new` not only allocates memory and `delete` not only deallocates memory.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You are Correct. Hence number 6, explaining the very nature of Dynamic Memory Allocation including the Nature of Object Destruction to someone who barely understands C++ at once would overwhelm them. Might even sway them to another language. And I did say the nature of  `new` in number 1. You may have the Educational background for it but I do not, so forgive me for using the "Wrong Term" for Dynamic and Automatic Storage Durations. I have never read a book on Programming hence the "Ambiguity" on my terminologies.

Comment: using stack and heap as terms is so common, that was a minor nitpick. But imho your explanation of `new` and `delete` is not ok. It leaves out details that do not make the explanation simpler, but wrong. What it means to call a constructor must be learned befre calling `new`, hence I dont see the point of leaving it out (especially to a beginner).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number When you put it that way, Yes I Did miss and it and Does make my answer wrong to the point of mistaking it for `malloc` and `free`. Leaving out the Construction via the Constructor and the Destruction via the Destructor is a Major Booboo. I edited my answer to reflect it.

It's my First answer in S.O.  and as someone who only had Experience in C++,Basic and VB. forgot that other Languages doesn't Share the same "Constructs" that C++ have. I may have taken that "Construct"  for granted! Thank you for teaching me a thing or two about answering questions.

Comment: you do not need to add `EDIT` to the question. In fact it makes it harder to read. If someone wants to know about the edit history they can see it here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75334454/revisions

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks again! I've only done what others have done on my Threads so. I thought that would be a good practice.