# Convert c++98 code to new c++17 code when using std::vector of pointers

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, raw-pointer

i dont what to manage or less as i can manage raw pointers note in the example i have to delete the object before removeing it from the vector i want to avoid it it here and later
what will be good case to convert this code to using unique_ptr or shared_ptr

```
class GameState
{
    public:
        virtual bool onEnter() = 0;
        virtual bool onExit() = 0;
        virtual std::string getStateID() const = 0;
};

class MenuState : GameState
{
        public:
             MenuState(){};
             virtual ~MenuState(){};             
             bool onEnter(){};
             bool onExit(){};
             std::string getStateID() const;
        private:
             static const std::string s_menuId;

};

class StateMechine
{
    
    public:
        void pushState(GameState* pState)
        {
            m_gameStates.pop_back(pState);
            m_gameStates.back()->onEnter();
        }

        void changeState(GameState* pState)
        {
            if(!m_gameStates.empty())
            {
                if(m_gameStates.back()->onExit())
                {
                    delete m_gameStates.back();
                    m_gameStates.pop_back();
                }
            }
        }

         
    private:
        std::vector<GameState*> m_gameStates;
}

int main(int argc ,char** argv)
{
    GameState *gs  = new MenuState();
    StateMechine sm;
    sm.pushState(gs);
    sm.changeState(gs);
}
```

Comment: `m_gameStates.pop_back(pState);` was never valid code, did you mean `push_back`?

Comment: `class MenuState : GameState` also looks wrong. Do you mean `class MenuState : public GameState` ?

Comment: `MenuState` should publicly inherit `GameState` in order to assign `new MenuState()` to a `GameState* gs`.

Comment: please post the actual code. Errors in code that are unrelated to the question are not nice. It looks like you never actually tried to compile this code, so why bother to translate it to newer standard?

Comment: `bool onEnter(){};` is also something that my compiler refuses to let pass. if you want to present a dummy make it `bool onEnter(){ return true; };`, because the empty implementation `{}` spoils the whole code with undefined behavior

Comment: don't forget the virtual destructor for GameState (required)

Answer (score 1):

The `std::vector<GameState*>` can be replaced with a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameState>>`. That way a call to `m_gameStates.pop_back()` will delete the corresponding object.

```
class StateMechine
{
    
    public:
        void pushState(std::unique_ptr<GameState> pState)
        {
            m_gameStates.push_back(std::move(pState));
            m_gameStates.back()->onEnter();
        }

        void changeState()
        {
            if(!m_gameStates.empty())
            {
                if(m_gameStates.back()->onExit())
                {
                    m_gameStates.pop_back();
                }
            }
        }

         
    private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameState>> m_gameStates;
};

int main(int argc ,char** argv)
{
    StateMechine sm;
    sm.pushState(std::make_unique<MenuState>());
    sm.changeState();
}
```