# How to destroy a smart pointer prematurely

Tags: c++, c++11, setter, unique-ptr

I have a class that has a setter method which takes a unique_ptr as an argument. That unique_ptr is saved as a class member.

```
class TestClass {
    std::unique_ptr<Tester> sp;

    void setTester_Way1(std::unique_ptr<Tester> te) {
         auto deleter=std::move(sp);
         sp=std::move(te);
    }

    void setTester_Way2(std::unique_ptr<Tester> te) {
         sp=std::move(te);
    }
};
```

Which way is the correct way to set the smart pointer? Does Way2 leak the original pointer of sp?

Comment: There's only one way to leak a `unique_ptr`: the `release()` member function

Comment: I think this answer explains everything http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function

Comment: @zenith is that a challenge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Way2 is fine, when you assign to a `unique_ptr` any existing owned pointer will be safely deleted.

Answer (score 1):

As [Chris Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422652/chris-drew) said Way2 is fine.  One thing though is that `unique_ptr` is not copyable/assignable so the only ways to pass a `unique_ptr` is by reference, r-value reference or by value with `move()`.  Trying to do:

```
int main()
{
    TestClass t;
    auto p = std::make_unique<int>(10);
    t.setTester_Way2(p);
}
```

[Will fail to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7dbc9573abd817e).  Although you can `move()` `p` into the function([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c92abb4fc37e8fab)).

If you change `setTester_Way2()` to `void setTester_Way2(std::unique_ptr<int>& te)` [then it will compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/588d6bd814cccc01).  If you change the function to take an rvalue reference and `std::move()` the pointer into the funcnction:

```
class TestClass {
    std::unique_ptr<int> sp;
public:

    void setTester_Way1(std::unique_ptr<int> te) {
         auto deleter=std::move(sp);
         sp=std::move(te);
    }

    void setTester_Way2(std::unique_ptr<int>&& te) {
         sp=std::move(te);
    }
};

int main()
{
    TestClass t;
    auto p = std::make_unique<int>(10);
    t.setTester_Way2(std::move(p));
}
```

[Then it will also compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd3420734a89396d).

Comment: Are you suggesting they _should_ be passing by reference instead? Because I think pass-by-value [is fine](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) in this case.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I personally like by r-value reference as it makes it clear that you are going to move it.  Unless I still am of base on move semantics.

Comment: pass by r-value reference _does not_ make it clear you are going to move it. It is just a reference, it is not moved until the function decides to move it, it may not. By by value _guarantees_ it will be moved, there is no other way of getting the parameter in there

Comment: Anyway, there are many arguments for and against pass-by-value for `unique_ptr` just see the comments on [this blog post](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/should-move-only-types-ever-be-passed.html)! I think the jury is still out.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I just fell that if a function takes an r-value reference then it is saying that I may do something I may not but since it is an r-value I can do whatever I want so don't complain if something happens.

Comment: Think about it, passing a `unique_ptr` by reference is like passing a pointer to pointer. No reason to do that unless you want to modify the pointer itself. One use case is when the function that takes an `unique_ptr` *might or might not* take the ownership of the pointed object. Then passing by rvalue-reference would be advisable.