# how can i move std::unique_ptr for constructor argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

My aim is to be able to create an object with a different kind of member object of from same class family; in `Java` it seems like this:

```
public class Interface {
    public void test();
}

public class MyImpl1 implements Interface {
    @Override
    public void test() {System.out.println("I am impl 1");}
}

public class MyImpl2 implements Interface {
    @Override
    public void test() {System.out.println("I am impl 2");}
}

public class A {
    public A(Interface myinter) {
        _myinter = myinter;
    }

    Interface _myinter;
}
```

So that I can create an object with different implementation:

```
A a(new MyImpl1());
```

or

```
A a(new MyImpl2());
```

(Sorry if there is syntax error in this botched code, it is just to explain what I want)

So, in C++ I think I would implement this with smart pointer to benefit from RAII. Thus, I wrote [this](http://ideone.com/LuLxWN) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Interf {
    virtual void test() {cout << "I am Interf" << endl;}
};

struct A {
    A(std::unique_ptr<Interf> e) : _e(std::move(e)) {}

    std::unique_ptr<Interf> _e;

    void test() {_e->test();}
};

struct Impl : public Interf {
    void test() {cout << "I am Impl;" << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Interf> b(new Impl);

    A a(std::move(b));

    a.test();

    cout << "fine!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- It seems to me working. But, is this a correct way to implement it, or there are errores, or better practices?
- Also, in this code, I am not sure if I needed to use `std::move` twice. Is this the correct way to pass `unique_ptr` to constructor?
- Another thing I did not understand is why this code does not compile if I remove `_e(std::move(e))` from memberwise init list and put inside the constructor; some one please could also explain what is going on here?

.

```
struct A {
    A(std::unique_ptr<Interf> e) {
        _e(std::move(e));
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass a unique\_ptr argument to a constructor or a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function)

Comment: This is a fine question, do note however that the [codereview.se] stack is specifically meant for working code in need of a double-check. StackOverflow here rather deals with non-woking code.

Comment: "In need of a double-check" is maybe an unlucky formulation. Code Review requires code to be working to the best of your knowledge. Basically you should be confident your code works as intended in all cases. A double-check should happen **before** posting to CR.

Comment: @Quentin Mm yes right. But also here there are lots of "best practice", "how does it work" questions, and also they are those with most upvotes.

Comment: @Mert Only because people like them. But that is irrelevant. They are still off-topic.

Comment: @Vogel612 it is, thanks for the clarification. Mert : Just a heads up because you're going that way. I personally think this question is fine here.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I saw your intent and told that you are right. Though I doubt why SO persists on this if lots of users like that and practically disregards it.

Comment: @MertMertce human bias, or historical reasons (CodeReview is much younger than SO). Also because migrating questions between stacks is inconvenient, as users don't necessarily have a matching account on the other side, so it's reserved to completely off-topic questions.

Comment: Java exemple need edition as implementations of interface must extend it.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès done! Although I didn't mean it.

Comment: As a side note: it is a good practice to use `override` (so `void test() override {std::cout << "I am Impl;" << std::endl;}`), and avoid `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah, I like to use Override. I didn't know that in c++ existed. Thanks.

Comment: @MertMertce: It exists since C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three `std::unique_ptr`s that pass your `Interf` around :

- `b`, the local variable in `main()`;
- `e`, the parameter of `A`'s constructor;
- `_e`, the member of the constructed `A` instance.

It makes complete sense that moving the `Interf` instance across three different pointers needs two successive `std::move()` operations (`b` to `e`, then `e` to `_e`).

Slightly off-topic : C++14 encourages the use of `std::make_unique`. This is C++11 though.

Your code is absolutely fine :)

#### Edit :

Member variables are initialized in the member-initialization list only. In the constructor's body, `_e(std::move(e));` means to call `_e`'s `operator ()` as if it was a functor.

Assigning to `_e` should be done with `_e = std::move(e);`, although it's always better to simply initialize it directly.

Comment: Do you have also an idea about my 3rd question?

Comment: @MertMertce because `e` and `_e` are different objects, `_e(e)` would invoke the copy constructor, but `unique_ptr` is not copiable.

Comment: @MertMertce I read it wrong (twice !) so I thought I had answered it. Now it's answered :)

Comment: @Quentin right. That was a poor question. I have confused about syntax.

Comment: @MertMertce I blame my lack of coffee :p

Comment: I'd rather used a reference passing to the ctor `A(std::unique_ptr<Interf> &e) : _e(std::move(e)) {}` to eliminate the unnecessary explicit first move as the semantic for your `A` class is clearly to *stole* the ptr...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès actually, a *sink* parameter should be passed by value. A non-const reference denotes an *out* parameter. And you definitely **want** to make the "stealing" explicit at the calling site.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès My aim is absolutely to get the ownership of ptr.

Comment: Ok, I should have think twice.

Comment: Scott Mayer's http://scottmeyers.blogspot.fr/2014/07/should-move-only-types-ever-be-passed.html is interesting regarding that question...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I'm not convinced by Meyer's idea here, for the reason [this comment](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.fr/2014/07/should-move-only-types-ever-be-passed.html#c2886270106405549594) brings up : ambiguity as to whether the object has actually been moved.