# Passing std::unique_ptr to constructor to take ownership

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to pass a `std::unique_ptr` to the constructor of a class that will take ownership of the data owned by the `std::unique_ptr`.

Are there any differences between the approaches `foo` and `bar` below in terms of how the compiler handles them that would make one of them preferable?

`foo` class:

```
template <class T>
class foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> data_;

public:
    foo(std::unique_ptr<T>&& data) :
        data_{ std::forward<std::unique_ptr<T>>(data) }
    {
    }
};
```

`bar` class:

```
template <class T>
class bar
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> data_;

public:
    bar(std::unique_ptr<T> data) :
        data_{ std::move(data) }
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Does the second one even works?

Comment: If your team gets less confused by the latter and will waste less time asking you to explain it, use the latter.

Comment: @KerrekSB did OP ask about team confused and waste of time?

Comment: @101010 of course it does! `bar<int> b{ std::make_unique<int>(69) };`

Comment: OK but what if try to enter an already existant std::unique_ptr (e.g., `std::unique_ptr<int> uptr {new int}; bar<int> b(uptr);`)

Comment: @101010 you will need to move it

Comment: @101010 Then neither would compile. Which is a good thing.

Comment: @101010 `bar<int> b{ std::move(other) };` - who's asking the question here?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that passing `std::unique_ptr` by copy is not a good thing IMHO. You give wrong signals.

Comment: @101010 Yep, passing by copy is certainly not a good thing because it won't compile. Possible dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function?rq=1)

Comment: @Slava: The OP asked about "any differences". The purpose of using C++ is to get stuff done, so if there's an impact on the ability to get stuff done, I'd consider that noteworthy.

Comment: related/maybe dupes: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935393/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-rvalue-reference), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140495/accept-move-only-parameter-by-value-or-rvalue-reference)

Comment: @KerrekSB OP asked "any differences ... in terms of how the compiler handles them". If you consider that noteworthy you skip answering, I think this is legit question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Binding to a reference requires one less move:

```
void f(std::unique_ptr<T>&& p) { g(std::move(p)); }

f(std::make_unique<T>());  // no move, g binds directly to the temporary
```

Binding to an object parameter requires one actual move:

```
void f(std::unique_ptr<T> p) { g(std::move(p)); }

f(std::make_unique<T>());  // p constructed (= moved) from temporary,
                           // g binds to p
```

The extra move involves one pointer copy, one setting of a pointer to null, and one destructor with a condition check. This is not a big cost, and the question of which style to use depends on the kind of code you're writing:

The more leaf your code is and the less it is used, the more the simple version with by-value passing buys you simplicity. Conversely, the more library your code is and the less you know your users, the more there is value in not imposing avoidable cost, no matter how small.

You decide.

Comment: In C++17, that extra move will be guaranteed to be elided right?

Comment: @NathanOliver: no, that's nothing to do with that. That's why I *hate* the term "guaranteed copy elision", it just confuses everyone.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Basically, you should reject all blanked "X will solve all Y" claims, they're all nonsense.

Comment: What term would you give it then

Comment: @GillBates: Maybe "Simplified value categories", something like that. "Prvalues are not objects". The latter describes the change precisely. (Since there are no objects, no objects are copied.) Now it's also immediately clear why that has nothing to do with the present question. And it doesn't advertise with the absence of something that doesn't exist in the first place.