# Why copy constructor is being called two times in below code?

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain why the copy constructor here is called two times?

```
class  A 
{
    int i;
    public:
    A(){cout<<"IN constr"<<endl;};
    A(int x):i(x) {};
     A (A &a)
     {
         cout<<"in copy"<<endl;
         i= a.i;
     }
};

class MyClass {
    A var;
public:
    MyClass(A a):var(a) {
                     }
};

int main() {

    A a1;
    MyClass m(a1);
    return 0;
}
```

When i run the code out put is:

```
IN constr
in copy
in copy
```

I can understand one time when it copies `a` into the variable `var`, but when it gets called second time?

Comment: 1st copy - object being passed to constructor of `MyClass` by value; 2nd time - member variable `var` being copy-initialized.

Comment: to avoid one copy, you can make MyClass accept reference of A, than by value.. MyClass(A& a):var(a)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing the constructor argument **by value**, which is where your second copy comes from.  You'll get just one copy if you change the constructor signature to the more canonical C++:

```
MyClass(const A& a)
  : var(a)
{
}
```

That's called argument passing by **const reference**, and pre-C++11 it was basically the go-to way of passing arguments to functions.

If you know you will be dealing with temporary objects passed as function arguments though, then C++11 and onwards also have **pass-by-rvalue-reference** - see e.g. [Pass by value vs pass by rvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935393/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-rvalue-reference) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The first copy is from `a1` to the parameter `a` of the MyClass constructor, the second one is from the parameter `a` to the member `var`.

If you want to reduce the number of copies, you have (at least) two options:

Pass a const reference to the constructor as mentioned by Joris:

```
MyClass(A const &a) : var(a) {
}
```

If A can be efficiently moved, take `a` by value and move to the member:

```
MyClass(A a) : var(std::move(a)) {
}
```

That way, a user that does not need his `A` anymore can move it into the new MyClass instance, while a user that still needs the A can pass it by value.

```
void useA(A &a);
void doSomethingWithM(MyClass & m);

void functionThatNeedsAAgain() {
    A myImportantA;
    MyClass m {myImportantA}; // copy myImportantA once
    useA(myImportantA);
    doSomethingWithM(m);
}

void functionThatDoesNotNeedAAgain() {
    A tempA;
    // no copy needed, as tempA will never be used again
    MyClass m {std::move(tempA);
    doSomethingWithM(m);
}
```

The third option would be to provide constructors from both `const A&` and `A&&` but I would weigh the code duplication against the benefit.

If you want to know how far this can be taken if `A` happens to be `std::string` and you want to cover the construction of temporary `A`s, watch this [excellent talk](https://youtu.be/PNRju6_yn3o) by Nicolai Josuttis.