# Functions taking rvalue parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

I've seen quite a lot of code in my company where functions take rvalue arguments.

Example:

```
void Notifier::PostEvent(std::unique_ptr<IEvent>&& event)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
    m_events.push_back(std::move(event));
    m_conditionVariable.notify_all();
}
```

There are no templates here. This could easily have written like this:

```
void Notifier::PostEvent(std::unique_ptr<IEvent> event)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
    m_events.push_back(std::move(event));
    m_conditionVariable.notify_all();
}
```

Since the parameter 'event' is a sink value in both cases they are effectively the same. I think the only advantage with the first version is that it saves one move constructor for the unique_ptr. Is that correct? Is it really worth it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass by value vs pass by rvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935393/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-rvalue-reference)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a unique\_ptr argument to a constructor or a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Now I understand better after reading [How do I pass a unique_ptr argument to a constructor or a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function)

What's happening is that in my first example, where I am passing by rvalue reference, it's more or less similar to passing by *non-const lvalue reference*. Although you might expect the parameter to be empty after the function call there is no guarantee. It all depends on what the function actually does with it. By pushing/moving it into a vector like what I am doing here the unique_ptr will be empty. However, if I don't do any moving (say I just call a method of the IEvent class) then the unique_ptr is not empty.

The unique_ptr rvalue reference parameter, therefore, actually does not **guarantee** what happens to the value after the call, i.e. whether it is a sink or not. It could be empty after the call or it may not be. Only by inspecting the code can you determine what will happen.

I think in retrospect the second function definition where it takes a unique_ptr by value is better. That ensures that the unique_ptr has been moved and should no longer be used afterward.