# Can you perfectly forward without templates

Tags: c++, constructor, forwarding

I have a class that has multiple constructors:

```
class Obj
{
    public:
        Obj(int x, int y)           {}
        Obj(std::string const& str) {}
        Obj(char v, int s)          {}
};
```

Now I want to add an Options object to the constructor that is stored in the object. But to make this work well I want to move the options when I can but copy when I have to. It seems like I have to double up the number of constructors to support both move and copy of the options.

```
class Options {};

class Obj
{
    Options options;

    public:
        Obj(Options const& o, int x, int y):          options(o) {}
        Obj(Options const& o, std::string const& str):options(o) {}
        Obj(Options const& o, char v, int s)         :options(o) {}

        Obj(Options&& o, int x, int y):          options(std::move(o)) {}
        Obj(Options&& o, std::string const& str):options(std::move(o)) {}
        Obj(Options&& o, char v, int s)         :options(std::move(o)) {}
};
```

If I had used templates I could have used perfect forwarding and got the correct affect.

```
template<typename Options>
class Obj
{
    Options options;

    public:
        Obj(Options&& o, int x, int y):          options(std::forward<Options>(o)) {}
        Obj(Options&& o, std::string const& str):options(std::forward<Options>(o)) {}
        Obj(Options&& o, char v, int s)         :options(std::forward<Options>(o)) {}
};
```

The trouble with this is that I know the type `Options`.

Comment: Do you really need perfect forwarding? Just copy it by value should be fast enough (assuming that the cost of a move is negligible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forwarding references only work with templates, you could templatize the constructors and impose restriction on template parameter.

```
class Obj
{
    Options options;
    template<typename Opt>
    using ValidOption = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Options, std::decay_t<Opt>>, bool>;


    public:
        template <typename X = Options, ValidOption<X> = true>
        Obj(X&& o, int x, int y):          options(std::forward<Options>(o)) {}
        template <typename X = Options, ValidOption<X> = true>
        Obj(X&& o, std::string const& str):options(std::forward<Options>(o)) {}
        template <typename X = Options, ValidOption<X> = true>
        Obj(X&& o, char v, int s)         :options(std::forward<Options>(o)) {}
};
```

Comment: That has a down side in usage: `Obj a({}, 1, 2);` Does not work as the compiler can not deduce the type of `{}` were it would work if I had used `Options` directly. This means I shifting the burden from myself onto the user of the class (something I would prefer not to do).

Comment: @MartinYork Does `template <typename X = Options, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Options, X>>* = nullptr>` work?

Comment: @songyuanyao If you add NathanOliver's trick (and remove the template around the class) that makes it work like I want. Still ugly but works.

Comment: BTW, the constraint `std::is_same` is very restrictive, [`std::is_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) seems more adapted.

Answer (score 1):

Your last snippet:

```
template <typename Options>
class Obj
{
    Options options;

public:
    Obj(Options&& o, int, int):            options(std::forward<Options>(o)) {}
    Obj(Options&& o, std::string const&) : options(std::forward<Options>(o)) {}
    Obj(Options&& o, char, int)          : options(std::forward<Options>(o)) {}
};
```

is not perfect forwarding, as it is your class which is template, not your function.

Perfect forwarding would be:

```
class Obj
{
    Options options;

public:

    template <typename T> Obj(T&& o, int, int):            options(std::forward<T>(o)) {}
    template <typename T> Obj(T&& o, std::string const&) : options(std::forward<T>(o)) {}
    template <typename T> Obj(T&& o, char, int)          : options(std::forward<T>(o)) {}
};
```

I summarize (performance) options in [Taking sink parameters by rvalue reference instead of by value to enforce performant usage of interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61601352/2684539)

So unless performance is really important and even an extra move is important, I would go for

```
Obj(Options o, int x, int y) : options(std::move(o)) {}
```

or

```
Obj(Options&& o, int x, int y) : options(std::move(o)) {}
```

(depending how important you want to avoid implicit copy).

If you target performance, you have indeed to go with forwarding reference.

Comment: I am not so worried about efeciency. I am trying to remove code duplication (or I am experiementing with removing code duplication). I have a library with lots of classes and the `Options` being passed down through multiple layers. Then having to have multiple constructors for objects at each layer. The amount of code duplication (with the only difference being a move or pass by ref) increases exponentially. The code is usually trivial but if I was to come along later and change something small the cascade of changes to push that trough could be huge (and error prone).

Comment: So take by value or r-value reference is a good option.

Comment: What happens if the object is const? Is that going to invoke the value version and force a copy.

Comment: If your initial object is const, a copy is needed somewhere. with const lvalue reference constructor, it happens inside the constructor: with by value, it happens at call-site. with rvalue reference, it happens at call site and should be explicit.