# Pass a std::string ctor parameter to impl in pimpl with move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Is this a correct approach to pass std::string parameters to the Impl's constructor with move semantics?

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    struct Impl;
    unique_ptr<Impl> impl_;
public:
    Foo(string s);
};

struct Foo::Impl
{
    string s_;
    Impl(string s) : s_(std::move(s)) {}
};

Foo::Foo(string s) : impl_(make_unique<Foo::Impl>(move(s)))
{
}
```

Or should the Impl's ctor be defined as:

```
Impl(string&& s) : s_(std::move(s)) {}
```

Comment: Using an rvalue reference might make the code a little faster as it cuts out a move.  As always, try both and measure the results.  Depending on the sizes of the strings, and if your implementation using SSO, cutting out a move could make a big difference, or it might not really matter.

Comment: Do I need std::move() in the Impl's ctor for the rvalue reference case? It compiles either way with or with out the move call.

Comment: Yes, you will still need to use `std::move`.  Anything with a name is an lvalue, and that includes rvalue references, so if you want the move to happen, you need to convert it back to an rvalue with `std::move`.

Comment: I see, so without the std::move() s_ will just be copy constructed?

Comment: Yep.  Without it, you have an lvalue, and those are never moved unless you use `std::move`.  There are a couple edge cases to that statement, but those deal with local objects with automatic storage duration and either being returned or thrown out of the local scope.

Comment: Ok, it clicked now :)

Comment: Related to [pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-rvalue-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935393/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-rvalue-reference)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a correct approach
>
> ```
> Impl(string s) : s_(std::move(s)) {}
> ```

This is fine.

> Or should the Impl's ctor be defined as:
>
> ```
> Impl(string&& s)
> ```

This would generally be less useful because you wouldn't be able to pass lvalue strings as arguments. That said, if the `Foo::Foo(string s)` is the only context where `Impl`'s constructor is called, then that lack of general usefulness wouldn't be a problem in practice and thus this would also be fine.

---

P.S. Once you actually define `Impl` in a separate translation unit, you'll find that you need to have user declared special member functions (destructor, move, assignment) of `Foo` because their definition depends on the definition of `Impl`.