# Why does std::unique_ptr not have a const get method?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, smart-pointers

I understand that [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is the way it is and probably won't be changed to break backwards compatibility but I was wondering if anyone has a good reason why the writers of the spec didn't overload the `get` method with a const variant that looks like

```
const T* get() const;
```

to follow the intent of the `unique_ptr` being `const`.

My best guess is that it is trying to mirror pointers and act like a `T* const` instead of a typical class. As a follow-up question, if I wanted to hold a pointer in a const-like fashion in a const instance of my class, should I be using something else other than `std::unique_ptr` to hold the data?

**Update**

In my case I want to protect myself from misusing the pointer in the class itself. I was writing a const move constructor `MyClass(const MyClass&& other)` and was copying the data from the new instance into other via `std::copy`. It took a long time to track down the bug because I had assumed the copy must be correct because of const protection. I'm trying to figure out what I could have done to protect myself from this outside of providing a const getter and using that within the class when doing the copy.

Comment: Regarding the latter question, wouldn't `std::unique_ptr<YourClass const>` do what you seek? Or did I misunderstand that part of the question.

Comment: In my case my let's say I'm just wrapping some data like struct so all it is is a `char[]` and an `int` to represent the length. I want to pass it around and let consumers manipulate the bytes unless they have a const instance. Even if I provide const and non-const getters for the data, I want to ensure my internal methods don't mess with data on a const instance passed in to a method on my class

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24428465/103167

Comment: `std::unique_ptr::get()` is already const

Comment: I do not understand your update. It seems like an XY problem, or completely different question. Why on earth do you want a const move constructor? And what is "const protection"?

Comment: @Oktalist I'm sorry if I'm confusing, my update is trying to get to back to the problem I'm trying to solve, which is how do I prevent myself from having the same bug again.  The const move constructor may be a bad design on my part but consider any member function that take a const instance by reference where I would extract data from it. By "const protection", I meant that I was safe from modifying anything controlled by the const reference so that when debugging I could skip looking at the const method as a culprit because the compiler would have stopped me from doing any modification.

Comment: Your const move constructor does not make any sense, if I understand you correctly, you just implemented a copy constructor. If a move constructor does not make sense in your class that's fine, just don't create one, no need to hack anything...

Comment: @Slava He is saying that it returns a non-`const` pointer -- meaning from a `const` member function, you could potentially mutate a `std::unique_ptr` member since its `get` method is `const`, violating the expectation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smart pointers are pretending to be a raw pointer.
If you have class member which is raw pointer and use it in `const` method that you can't update a pointer, but you can modify object which is pointed.
Same behavior is desired for smart pointer. So `std::unique_ptr::get` is a `const` method, but doesn't force to return pointer to `const` object.

Note also that you can have a pointer to `const` object.

```
MyClass *pointerToObject
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> smartPointerToObject;

// but you can have also a case
const MyClass *pointerToConstObject
std::unique_ptr<const MyClass> smartPointerToConstObject;
```

In last case `std::unique_ptr::get` will return something you are expecting.

---

Based on comment below:

Just provide private methods:

```
InnerClass& GetField() { return *uniquePtrToInnerClass; }
const InnerClass& GetField() const { return *uniquePtrToInnerClass; }
```

And use it in your code and you will have const object of inner class in const method.

Comment: I want the contents to be mutable event the instance is mutable and non-mutable when it isn't so I can't know when instantiating the class or storing the data whether or not to store it as a const or non-const version.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<const MyClass>` doesn't fulfill your needs? Also you write such complex sentence in comment that I'm unable to understand it.

Comment: it doesn't fulfill by needs. Consider there's `Outer` and `Inner` and `Outer` contains a `unique_ptr<Inner>`.  Outer needs to manipulate the Inner instance sometimes but it would go against functionality of Outer to manipulate Inner within a const method.

Answer (score 5):

There's no point to giving read-only access to an object via its `unique_ptr`.  You only pass `unique_ptr` around when you are transferring ownership, for access to the object without an ownership transfer, call `up.get()` and pass a `const T*` to the function that should only read (or if the pointer is never `nullptr`, it's also reasonable to evaluate `*(up.get())` and pass a `const T&`).

As a bonus, this allows you to use that function with objects stored on the stack, embedded inside another object, or managed with a smart pointer other than `unique_ptr`.

There's a good discussion of all the unique_ptr parameter passing cases (in/out, const/non-const, etc) here:

- [How do I pass a `unique_ptr` argument to a constructor or a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428465/103167)

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is not passing the unique_ptr around, it's protecting me from myself within the class when accessing a const instance. I could add a const get for every smart pointer in every class to always protect myself, but that's a lot of extra code.

Comment: I guess what he's getting at is you can mutate the internals of a `unique_ptr` member from a `const` member function, even though that member function is marked `const`. You couldn't do that if it weren't for the `unique_ptr` (eg if you stored a raw pointer instead of the `unique_ptr`)

Comment: @bobobobo: If you had a raw pointer, you could still mutate the pointed-to object.  The pointer type would be `T* const` not `const T*`.  You couldn't replace the pointer (but `get()` is not proposing to replace the pointer)

Answer (score 5):

For the same reason a `T*const` when dereferenced is a `T&`, not a `T const&`.

Constness of *pointer* is distinct from pointness of *pointed-to*.

`get` is const, it does not modify the *state* of `unique_ptr`.

Its constness does not impact the constness of the contents.

There is the idea of smart pointers that propogate constness, but `unique_ptr` is not that beast.

`std::experimental::propogate_const` wraps a pointer-like object and makes `const` travel through it.

It, or something like it, may solve your problem.

Note that I find half the time when I try to have const propogate like this, I discover I was wrong.  But this may not be the case here.

In general, the proper way to handle the guts of a `T*const` in a `const` manner is to pass a `T const&` (or the nullable variant `T const*`).

Comment: `std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<T>>` ?

Comment: You're just repeating the question, which said "My best guess is that it is trying to mirror pointers and act like a `T* const` instead of a typical class. "

Comment: propogate_const looks somewhat promising but in my case using it would result in the strange pattern of always wrapping calls to unique_ptrs in this call when accessing them in const methods. That is a bit closer to what I want but still rather verbose to use across every class that uses a unique_ptr

Comment: @quittle This "deep const" is not supposed to be an "everywhere thing"?  You can write an alias in any case -- `template<class T> using flat_ptr = std::experimental::propotate_const<std::unique_ptr<T>>`.  This class only makes sense to use within classes that contain a logically const pointer; other uses of `unique_ptr` shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this concern is valid,
there should be 2 versions for each de-referencing functions,

```
e.g.
    const T* get() const;
    T* get();
    enter code here
```

I know that purpose of providing "T* get() const" is to ease replace existing raw pointer usages.

But since uniq ptr denotes ownership, it is incorrect that some one being able to modify some thing OWNED by the object via a immutable(const) reference [assuming modifying something fully owned by a object is same as modifying the object itself - which is true if this was an object instead of a ptr].

May be best option would be std to provide another version of Uniq ptr which holds to above idiom (only other option may be to derive a new class from uniq ptr and provide 2 versions for de-referencing )

Answer (score 0):

Because as far as the `unique_ptr` is concerned, *getting the internal raw pointer reference is a `const` operation*. Calling `.get()` and retrieving the internal raw pointer of a `std::unique_ptr` does not change the internal state of the `std::unique_ptr` object itself. So it seems the library designers elected to mark it `const` without attention to what could happen to the underlying object if they just return a straight non-`const` reference to it.

In fact, if you have a `std::unique_ptr` inside an object, and you call a `const` member function of that object, you *can still call non-`const` member functions on the internal `std::unique_ptr` inside that object*. For example:

```
struct A {
    void Const() const { }
    void nonConst() { }
};

struct B {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
    void go() const {
        a->nonConst(); // OK
    }
};
```

Although you cannot perform non-`const` operations on the internal state variables of an object from one of its `const` member function, there is no rule that says you cannot perform non-`const` operations on *other* objects.

What you may be expecting is the `const`ness promise to carry over from the `unique_ptr` to also apply to access to what it internally points to, so you'd expect `unique_ptr` to be written something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class cunique_ptr {
    T* ptr;
public:
    cunique_ptr() {
        ptr = new T;
    }
    ~cunique_ptr() {
        delete ptr;
    }

    // You can only get a non-const pointer to the internals from a non-const object
    T* get() { return ptr; }

    // The const member function carries over the const promise to access to its internals
    const T* get() const { return ptr; }
};

void test() {
    cunique_ptr<A> a;
    a.get()->nonConst();

    const cunique_ptr<A> ca;
    //ca.get()->nonConst(); //X fails: cannot call non-const member functions from const object
    ca.get()->Const();
}
```

However, it seems the library designers elected against that type of protection and let the `const` promise be kind of shallow as it were.