# C++ Smart Pointer Lost in std::make_unique

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am in the process of converting some legacy code to take advantage of smart pointers in C++.  However, I ran into a runtime issue that I'm struggling to figure out.  I have code such as the following:

```
struct foo {
    int field;
};

class SomeClass {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<foo> m_Foo;
    int m_Field;
public:
    SomeClass(std::unique_ptr<int> ctorArg)
        : m_Field(ctorArg->field), m_Foo(std::move(ctorArg)) {
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<foo> fooPtr{ new foo() };
auto const classInstance{ std::make_unique<SomeClass>(std::move(fooPtr)) };
```

If I put a breakpoint prior to calling the `SomeClass` constructor, I can verify that `fooPtr` is not null.  However, once I am within the `SomeClass` constructor, the application is crashing when trying to initialize `m_Field`, since `ctorArg` is null (empty).  Is this expected?  If I change the constructor signature to take `std::unique_ptr<int> &&`, I see the same issue.  Can someone please explain what the issue is with this code, and how to go about fixing it?

Comment: You can only have one unique_ptr (one ownership). When you move it, you are passing this ownership forward, so the behind is assigned as nullptr

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function/8114913

Comment: Unfortunately your code has two variables called `ctorArg` so it's not completely clear which you are talking about. If you are talking about the second occurance then that is expected behaviour for `unique_ptr`.

Comment: I have updated the code to use separate variable names, since @Amadeus comment indicated that the original wording of this question was unclear about the behavior it exhibited.

Comment: Declare SomeClass constructor as public. Else code is ok.

Comment: @Mat I fail to see how that link is relevant.  Is my code in any way violating the recommendations?  It appears to me I am 100% compliant with the recommendations in that post, yet the code isn't working.

Comment: From @Mat link, "After newBase is constructed, nextBase is guaranteed to be empty. You don't own the object, and you don't even have a pointer to it anymore. It's gone.

This is ensured because we take the parameter by value. std::move doesn't actually move anything; it's just a fancy cast. std::move(nextBase) returns a Base&& that is an r-value reference to nextBase. That's all it does."

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez Yes, I understand that.  But the problem is that the parameter is null by the time it reaches my constructor, NOT that the `intPtr` variable is null after the call to my constructor.  It appears that `std::make_unique` is eating the pointer enroute to my constructor.  Is that expected?

Comment: @AhmedMasud no, `std::unique_ptr<int> intPtr { new int() };` creates a dynamic `int`, and initialises `intPtr`. Your snippet isn't valid C++

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Dies the program (*not your debugger*) behave differently from what you expect? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m.  You are correct.  This code doesn't reproduce the issue.  I am looking into what is different in my actual use case so I can get real help.  I think it has something to do with the class I am passing not having a move constructor, but am looking into it.  Standby...

Comment: I finally figured it out... it was a field order initialization issue (trying to use the passed `ctorArg` after it was moved, due to initialization being done in the order of declaration within the class).  I have updated the question to reflect the issue more accurately.

Comment: Hopefully a lesson in pushing a MCVE up-front!!

Comment: BTW my compiler has had warnings for this since 1066 AD! Do you have warnings turned off? Why?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just built the above example with the "Warning Level" set to "All" in VS2017u2, and although I got 606 warnings, not one of them was for out-of-order initialization.  Still, your comment made me think of release notes in old English, and I immediately thought of the holy hand grenade user instructions.  Thou shalt not initialize the second declared member variable within a constructor, unless thou immediately preceedith such declaration by initialization of the first declared member variable.  I want a Monty Python C++ user's guide in the worst way.

Comment: I suggest warning level 2. Warning level 4 will give you craptons of spam from their own standard library implementation, go figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of [member-initializer-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) is irrelevant, the members will be initialized in the order of their declaration.

So, first `m_Foo(std::move(ctorArg))` will zero out `ctorArg` **then** `m_Field(ctorArg->field)` will attempt to derefence an empty `ctorArg`.

Change your code to:

```
class SomeClass {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<foo> m_Foo;
    int m_Field;
public:
    SomeClass(std::unique_ptr<int> ctorArg)
        : m_Foo(std::move(ctorArg)), m_Field(m_Foo->field) {
    }
};
```

That is, always mention initializers in the order the fields are declared, and don't use input arguments which have been moved-out from.

Comment: The order issue only applies if the globals are in different source files.

Comment: @rustyx I have updated the example code so it now *actually* breaks in the way I was observing.