# How to fix 'no overloaded function takes 2 arguments' error C++

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I'm trying to create a class for a hash table to contain unique pointers, but whenever I try to add a pointer to the table I get an error which points to a different file from a library I am using.

I've tried using `.insert()` instead of `.emplace()`. I've tried passing in a pair of the key and the pointer.

Both of these have resulted in a different error to the original

here is the Hash_Table class:

```cpp
///<summary>
/// A struct for a hash table
///</summary>
template <typename T>
struct Hash_Table
{
public:
    ///<summary>
    /// Add an item to the hash table & return the item key
    ///</summary>
    int addItem(T newItem) {
        // Make the item into a unique pointer
        std::unique_ptr<T> itemPtr = std::make_unique<T>(newItem);

        //std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<T>> pair = std::make_pair(tailPointer, itemPtr);

        while (!Table.emplace(tailPointer, itemPtr).second) {
            tailPointer++;
            //pair.first++;
        }

        tailPointer++;

        return tailPointer--;
    };

private:

    ///<summary>
    /// The actual hash table
    ///</summary>
    std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<T>> Table;

    ///<summary>
    /// Points to the key of the last item added to the hash table
    ///</summary>
    int tailPointer;
};
```

The issue happens in `addItem()` function when I try to `table.emplace()`.

Error in file xmemory for code as shown above:

> C2661:  'std::pair::pair': no overloaded function
>   takes 2 arguments

Error  in file HashTable.h for when using `table.insert()`:

> C2664: 
>   'std::_List_iterator>>
>   std::_Hash>,std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::_List_const_iterator>>,const
>   std::pair>>
>   &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to
>   'std::_List_const_iterator>>'

Error in file utility for when using `table.insert` or `table.emplace(std::make_pair(tailPointer, itemPtr))`:

> C2440: '': cannot convert from 'initializer list'
>   to '_MyPair'

Comment: `Table.emplace(tailPointer, itemPtr)` -> `Table.try_emplace(tailPointer, std::move(itemPtr))` (but C++17).

Comment: `tailPointer++;` followed by `return tailPointer--;` is confusing me a bit...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a unique\_ptr argument to a constructor or a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function)

Comment: Jarods fix did work and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to fix your issue:

**Solution 1:**

```
int addItem(T newItem) {
    // Make the item into a unique pointer
    std::unique_ptr<T> itemPtr = std::make_unique<T>(newItem);

    // Unique_ptr doesn't have assignment operator instead it has move-assignment.
    // So it need to be moved only
    std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<T>> pair = std::make_pair(tailPointer++, std::move(itemPtr));

    // For same above reason, it must be moved
    Table.insert(std::move(pair));

    return tailPointer;
};
```

**Solution 2:**

```
int addItem(T newItem) {
    Table.insert(std::make_pair(tailPointer++, std::make_unique<T>(newItem)));
    return tailPointer;
}
```

**Solution 3:**

```
int addItem(T newItem) {
    Table[tailPointer++] = std::make_unique<T>(newItem);
    return tailPointer;
}
```

Non of the above solutions will require C++ 17. All are from C++11. You should understand why you are getting the compilation error. With your existing code you are trying to assign or copy the unique_ptr which is not allowed. It can only be **moved**. This is what your compiler is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Using this, will resolve the unique_ptr problems, in c++11

```
int addItem(T newItem) {    
    // Make the item into a unique pointer
    while (!Table.emplace_hint(tailPointer, newItem).second) {
        tailPointer++;
        //pair.first++;
    }
    tailPointer++;
    return tailPointer--;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42), your fix did work.

The fix:
`Table.emplace(tailPointer, itemPtr)` -> `Table.try_emplace(tailPointer, std::move(itemPtr))` (but C++17).  - Jarod42