# Unique_ptr out of scope

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'm having an issue passing unique_ptrs to functions, it seems they go out of scope when I pass to askQuestion.

hears my code.

```
char askQuestion(string *questions[8], unique_ptr<binaryBase>answered) {
    bool asked = false;
    char input = '0';
    while (!asked) { // loop until you find a question that has not been asked
        int randomQuestion = (rand() % 8); // generate a random number
        if (!(answered->getBit(randomQuestion))) { // check if the question has been answered 
            getInput(input, *questions[randomQuestion]);
            answered->toggleBit(randomQuestion);
            asked = true;
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

these two functions access unique_ptrs, function below relies on function above for input.
when I call askQuestion I get "(variable) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function"

```
bool checkAnswer(char answer, int place, binaryBase* reference) {
/*  if the answer is T and the correct answer is true, returns true
    if the answer is F and the correct answer is false, returns true
    return false otherwise
*/ return((answer=='T'&&reference->getBit(place))||(answer=='F'&&!reference->getBit(place)));
}
```

binaryBase is a simple custom class and only has a 8 int as data and getters and setters for bits, this treats the 8 bit int as a byte to store "boolean" answers for the program.

Comment: I'm not seeing a call to `askQuestion()` in the code you posted.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Why does `askQuestion` require a smart pointer instead of a reference?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing a call to `askQuestion()` in your example. However, I can see that `askQuestion()` is an "observer" of the `answered` parameter. A unique_ptr is used to transfer ownership of a pointer, not for just observing it. So you should define that function as:

```
char askQuestion(string *questions[8], binaryBase& answered)
```

instead. Use a reference here instead of a pointer to make it clear that passing null is not allowed. (Of course change all occurrences of `answered->` to `answered.`)

When you call that function and want to pass an object managed by a `unique_ptr<binaryBase> ptr`, then pass the managed object, not the unique_ptr itself with `*ptr`.

In cases where you actually do want to transfer ownership of the pointer, then you need to *move* the pointer:

```
void func(std::unique_ptr<binaryBase>);

// ...
std::unique_ptr<binaryBase> ptr = /* ... */
func(std::move(ptr));
```

After the call to `func()`, `ptr` does not contain an object anymore. `func()` took ownership of it.

`unique_ptr` is a "move-only type". It cannot be copied because its copy constructor and copy assignment operator have been deleted, which is the reason of your original compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char askQuestion(string *questions[8], unique_ptr<binaryBase>answered)
> ```

You are attempting to pass a `std::unique_ptr` by value to `askQuestion()` but it's a *move-only* type. It represents a dynamically allocated object that is not shared by more than one object at a time. You can only *move* a unique_ptr or pass it by reference. If you intend to pass ownership of the unique pointer then you have to use `std::move`:

```
askQuestion(questions, std::move(answered));
```

where `answered` is a `std::unique_ptr<binaryBase>`. Once ownership has transferred to a function then the caller cannot use that unique pointer again.

If you do not want to pass ownership then it can be passed by reference. Change `askQuestion()` to do that:

```
 char askQuestion(string *questions[8], unique_ptr<binaryBase> &answered); //non-const lvalue reference
```

or

```
char askQuestion(string *questions[8], const unique_ptr<binaryBase> &answered);  //const lvalue reference
```

When passing by reference the function can use the pointer but not own it, unless you explicitly use `std::move` within the function with a non-const lvalue reference unique pointer (a const lvalue reference can't be moved).

---

> ```
> bool checkAnswer(char answer, int place, binaryBase* reference)
> ```

In your code you are passing a pointer to `binaryBase` to the function `checkAnswer()`. Again there's no need for this function to own the unique pointer, so you can pass the unique pointer by reference as shown above or use `std::unique_ptr`'s `get()` method to get a pointer to the object.

You might like to check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function), which deals with different ways of passing a unique pointer comprehensively.