# auto from const std::vector<>&; object or reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

suppose we have an object with the following interface:

```
struct Node_t {
 ... const std::vector< something >& getChilds() const;
 } node;
```

Now, i access the property with an `auto` variable like this:

```
auto childs = node->getChilds();
```

what is the type of `childs`? a `std::vector< something >` or a reference to one?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `const std::vector<something>`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The type of `childs` will be `std::vector<something>`.

`auto` is powered by the same rules as [template type deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). The type picked here is the same that would get picked for `template <typename T> f(T t);` in a call like `f(node->getChilds())`.

Similarly, `auto&` would get you the same type that would get picked by `template <typename T> f(T& t);`, and `auto&&` would get you the same type that would get picked by `template <typename T> f(T&& t);`.

The same applies for all other combinations, like `auto const&` or `auto*`.

Comment: what is auto&& ? reference to reference ? what does it mean ?

Comment: `&&` denotes an rvalue reference. It's a C++11 feature, just like `auto` is. `auto&&` can become either an lvalue reference (i.e. a "normal" reference like `&`) or an rvalue reference.

Comment: Here's a question that explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-mean-in-c0x

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that reference collapsing rules apply to `auto&&`?

Comment: Good explanation, but doesn't actually directly answer the question.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I think your answer is a bit like "the same as whether the Riesz criterion is true for any e larger than 1/4" to answer "is the Riemann hypothesis true or false?". It is useful but does not answer the question, unless you know whether the Riesz criterion is true for any e larger than 1/4 ;-) Still +1 because it taught me something useful, but without the answer by Benjamin I still wouldn't know the actual answer. :-)

Comment: @Boris that's a poor analogy because whether the Riesz criterion holds as such is not information readily available, while the template type deduction rules are. The first hit on Google for "template type deduction" is quite satisfactory.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The analogy may not be perfect, but I still think it is relevant :) My point is that your answer, while well-written and providing useful info, only answers the question indirectly. As a friendly note, I believe your own expertise makes you overestimate the ability of the average C++ developer to deduce the actual answer (`std::vector<something>`) from the cppreference page you link. I am personally not able to do so *confidently*, despite 8 years of C++ experience in the field of computer graphics. We're often blind to other people's non-fluency in our topic of expertise.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes (or more simply, my point is that prepending your answer by "The type of `childs` would in this case be `std::vector<something>`. Indeed, ..." would make it perfect. Providing the answer + the explanation. Not just the explanation without the answer, like you did, or the answer without the explanation, like the other answerers did ;) )

Comment: @Boris Fair enough. In my defense my answer was the last one posted, so I'm guessing that when I did so I did to add to the others and didn't expect it to become the accepted one.

Comment: That makes sense :) Now yours is truly the superior answer ;)

Answer (score 21):

It's an `std::vector<something>`.  If you want a reference, you can do this:

```
auto & childs = node->getChilds();
```

That will of course be a const reference.

Comment: C++ makes it SO EASY to accidentally invoke a copy constructor :(

Answer (score 3):

`auto` gives you `std::vector<something>`. You can either specify reference qualifier `auto &` or, alternatively, you can use `decltype`:

```
decltype( node->getChilds() ) childs = node->getChilds();
```