# how is auto implemented in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

How is `auto` implemented in `C++11`? I tried following and it works in `C++11`

```
auto a = 1;
// auto = double
auto b = 3.14159;
// auto = vector<wstring>::iterator
vector<wstring> myStrings;
auto c = myStrings.begin();
// auto = vector<vector<char> >::iterator
vector<vector<char> > myCharacterGrid;
auto d = myCharacterGrid.begin();
// auto = (int *)
auto e = new int[5];
// auto = double
auto f = floor(b);
```

I want to check how this can be achieved using plain `C++`

Comment: It takes the type of the thing on the right and puts it on the left.

Comment: It takes the type the same way as decltype() and use it instead of auto

Comment: Do you really want to know how it is implemented? I'm pretty sure that depends on the compiler.

Comment: Why didn't GManNickG and Geoffroy put your comments as answer?  :)

Comment: @AdrianShum: I was being 50.111605% facetious.

Comment: "*I want to check how this can be achieved using plane C++*" This **is** plain C++, if your compiler is recent enough. I.e., it's standardized, and thus not anything special or out of the ordinary.

Comment: @GManNickG except there are cv qualification, value/reference considerations.

Comment: @Geoffroy: auto and decltype are _not_ exactly the same, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869888/the-relationship-between-auto-and-decltype

Comment: Coincidentally Nawaz answered both questions. I would take his word on what `auto` is.

Comment: `I want to check how this can be achieved using plane C++` You can't "achieve" this with "plane C++"; it's a *language feature* of C++11, which C++03 lacks. I think Boost has some macro, but it's not quite as good.

Comment: "plane C++"? auto is part of C++, so you can achieve the effect by using auto in C++.

Comment: I think you are confused by standards terms: C++11 is the current C++ standard. C++03 is the past C++ standard. If you now say `C++`, it is the same as if you say `C++11`. In ten years maybe, the past standard might be `C++11`, and the current one `C++18` or so, which you will _then_ call `C++`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does roughly the same thing as it would use for type deduction in a function template, so for example:

```
auto x = 1;
```

does kind of the same sort of thing as:

```
template <class T>
T function(T x) { return input; }

function(1);
```

The compiler has to figure out the type of the expression you pass as the parameter, and from it instantiate the function template with the appropriate type. If we start from this, then `decltype` is basically giving us what would be `T` in this template, and `auto` is giving us what would be `x` in this template.

I suspect the similarity to template type deduction made it much easier for the committee to accept `auto` and `decltype` into the language -- they basically just add new ways of accessing the type deduction that's already needed for function templates.

Comment: Not quite. `decltype(function_that_returns_reference())` is some `U&`, but `function(function_that_returns_reference())` would deduce `U`, just like `auto x = function_that_returns_reference()`. It's `auto` that gives us the `T` in the template.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Yes, there are a few minor differences -- that's why I said "... **roughly** the same thing..." and "... **kind of** the same thing...". Templates precede `auto` by several years...

Answer (score 7):

In C++, every expression has *value* and *type*. For example, `(4+5*2)` is an expression which has value equal to `14` and type is `int`. So when you write this:

```
auto v = (4+5*2);
```

the compiler detects the *type* of the expression on the right side, and replaces `auto` with the detected type *(with some exception, read comments)*, and it becomes:

```
int v = (4+5*2); //or simply : int v = 14;
```

Similarly,

```
auto b = 3.14159; //becomes double b = 3.14159;

auto e = new int[5]; //becomes int* e = new int[5];
```

and so on

Comment: So what is the type of v[i], where v is a standard library container? My understanding is that it is an lvalue since it returns by reference. But is the *type* of the expression a reference, or is the reference removed? This has a bearing on the behaviour of auto, since auto x = v[1] takes by value.

Comment: @juanchopanza the type of `v[i]` in that case is some `T&` (or `T const&`). `auto x = v[i]` however, would deduce `T`, not `T&`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8797915/46642

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes right, so then `auto` does something a bit more complicated than just detect the type of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The `auto` keyword is simply a way to declare a variable while having it type being based upon the value.

So your

```
auto b = 3.14159;
```

Will know that b is a double.

For additional reading on `auto` take a look at the following references

[C++ Little Wonders: The C++11 auto keyword redux](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/03/15/c-little-wonders-the-c11-auto-keyword-redux.aspx)

[The C++0x auto keyword](http://sfmlcoder.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/the-c0x-auto-keyword/)

Answer (score 1):

It works like before :)

Have you never hit a compiler error telling you:

> **error:** invalid conversion from `const char*` to `int`

for such a code fragment: `int i = "4";`

Well, `auto` simply leverages the fact that the compiler knows the type of the expression on the right hand side of the `=` sign and reuses it to type the variable you declare.