# What exactly is an R-Value in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Could someone explain, or point me to some sort of explanation, of what R-Value is? I'm not really sure what it is, and my project has to incorporate it. Here is a demonstration of what R-Value is(First part is the r_string.hpp):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename CHAR_T = char>

class basic_rstring {
public:
    typedef CHAR_T  value_type;
    typedef CHAR_T* pointer_type;
    typedef CHAR_T const*   pointer_const_type;
private:
    pointer_type    _data;
    std::size_t     _length;
public:
    basic_rstring() : _data(nullptr), _length(0) 
    {
        std::cout << "Default ctor\n";
    }

    basic_rstring( pointer_const_type s ) 
        : _data( nullptr )
        , _length( 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "Literal ctor: " << s << std::endl;
        _length = strlen( s );
        _data = new value_type[ _length + 1 ];
        std::copy( s, s + _length + 1, _data );
    }

    basic_rstring( basic_rstring const& s )     
        : _data( nullptr )
        , _length( s._length )
    {
        std::cout << "Copy ctor: " << s.c_str() << std::endl;
        _data = new value_type [ _length + 1 ];
        std::copy( s._data, s._data + s._length + 1, _data );
    }

    basic_rstring( basic_rstring && s )     //move constructor
        : _data( s._data )
        , _length( s._length )
    {
        std::cout << "Move ctor: " << s.c_str() << std::endl;
        s._data = nullptr;
        s._length = 0;
    }

    ~basic_rstring()
    {
        if( _data )
            std::cout << "dtor: " << _data << "\n";
        else 
            std::cout << "NULL dtor\n";
        delete [] _data;
    }

    basic_rstring& operator = ( basic_rstring const& s );
    basic_rstring& operator = ( basic_rstring && s )
    {
        std::cout << "RValue assignment: " << s.c_str();
        if( _data )
            std::cout << " deleting...." << std::endl;
        else 
            std::cout << " no delete..." << std::endl;
        delete [] _data;
        _data = s._data;
        s._data = nullptr;
        _length = s._length;
        s._length = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    pointer_const_type c_str() const { return _data; }

};

template <typename CHAR_T>
basic_rstring<CHAR_T>& basic_rstring<CHAR_T>::operator = ( basic_rstring const& s )
{
    std::cout << "Copy assignment: " << s.c_str() << std::endl;
    pointer_type newData = new value_type [ s._length + 1 ];
    std::copy( s._data, s._data + s._length + 1, newData );
    _length = s._length;
    delete [] _data;
    _data = newData;
    return *this;
}

typedef basic_rstring<char> String;
typedef basic_rstring<wchar_t> wString;


#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "Rstring.hpp"
using namespace std;
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE move_test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

template <typename T_>
void old_swap( T_& a, T_&b ) 
{
    T_ hold = a;
    a = b;
    b = hold;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( stuff )
{
    String s("Bert");
    String t("Ernie");
    cout << "Old swap" << endl;
    old_swap(s,t);
    BOOST_CHECK( !strcmp( "Bert", t.c_str() ) );
    BOOST_CHECK( !strcmp( "Ernie", s.c_str() ) );

    cout << "New swap" << endl;
    swap(s,t);
    BOOST_CHECK( !strcmp( "Bert", s.c_str() ) );
    BOOST_CHECK( !strcmp( "Ernie", t.c_str() ) );

    cout << "\nDone." << endl;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does T&& mean in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-mean-in-c11)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: @Nicol: He's asking about an rvalue, not an rvalue reference.  So I like this question better.  But absolutely positively a dupe.

Comment: **I disagree completely about closing**. The OP, asking a basic question, will not be helped by the advanced discussion in the proposed duplicates. The questions are not at the same level. This question is about a basic explanation. Nicol's proposed duplicate is advanced and is just *vaguely associated*, it is irrelevant. Ben's proposed duplicate is for *language lawyers*, not for the OP. They are not duplicates. This question should not be closed. CLosing is not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> "Could someone explain, or point me to some sort of explanation, of what R-Value is? I'm not really sure what it is"

The term **lvalue** originally referred to an expression that could be the *left* hand side of an assignment. Correspondingly, an **rvalue** (although as I recall that term was not used by the C89 standard), was originally just the opposite: an expression that could not be the left hand side of an assignment, but that could only be the *right* hand side.

C++11 complicated this by adding several more nuanced terms, but let's concentrate on the C++03 meanings.

For example, if you have

```
int x;
```

then the assignment `x = 42` is OK, so `x` is an lvalue expression.

As a counter-example, the assigment `x+0 = 42` is not OK, so `x+0` is an rvalue expression.

And so is the expression `2+2`, it's an rvalue expression.

So, if the requirement is that your program should include an rvalue, then just write `2+2` or e.g. (more advanced) `6*7`, in `main`.

Original C didn't have `const`. In C++, with `const`, you have to disregard the `const` for the purpose of designating an expression as lvalue or rvalue. The critical point is then whether the expression guaranteed refers to an object in memory, an object with an address: if so, then the expression is an lvalue.

A reference type implies lvalue, because an expression of reference type is necessarily referring to an object with a memory address, i.e. that expression is an lvalue.

However, other than references there's no connection between type and lvalue/rvalue. For example, both `x` and `x+0` are expressions of type `int`, and they yield the same `int` value. But the former is an lvalue expression, while the latter is an rvalue expression.

As a general rule, if you can apply the built-in address operator, then it's an lvalue expression, and otherwise it's an rvalue expression.

Comment: The C standard's definition of "lvalue" has a checkered history; the C90 and C99 definitions both had serious problems.  C11 defines an lvalue as "an expression ... that potentially designates an object" (the "potentially" means that `*ptr` is an lvalue even if `ptr==NULL`).  <BRAG>C11's revised wording was my idea.</BRAG>

Comment: @KeithThompson: Are you aware that the link you have on your SO profile is dead?

Comment: @CamJackson: Which one?  The GitHub and Careers links both work for me.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf, thank you. I have a better understanding now. The project is to create a square-list data structure, which, I now think needs to suppose the C++11 && move semantics?

Comment: @KeithThompson The careers one. I'm logged into careers, but I get a 404.

Comment: @CamJackson: My profile is searchable by employers but hidden from public view. (Took me way to long to figure that out.) Thanks for the heads-up, though.

Comment: The C standard refers to the term "rvalue" only in a non-normative footnote: "What is sometimes called "rvalue" is in this International Standard described as the "value of an expression"."

Answer (score 26):

The term **rvalue** derives from its historical context --- it was something that could only go on the Right-hand side of an assignment, as opposed to an **lvalue** which could go on the left-hand side of an assignment. Thus a named variable (e.g. `x`) is an lvalue, but a literal integer (e.g. `42`) is an rvalue.

However, in modern C++ it is more nuanced than that.

In C++, an rvalue is an unnamed object or a member of such an object which is not a reference.

Some examples:

```
std::string s;

std::string foo(){ return "foo";}

struct X {
    std::string s;
};

std::string& bar() {return s;}

void baz(std::string const& x){}

s=std::string("hello"); // 1
s=foo();                // 2
std::string s2=bar();   // 3
baz("hello");           // 4
s=X().s;                // 5
```

In (1), the temporary `std::string` object created from the string literal is an rvalue.

In (2), the object returned from `foo()` is an rvalue.

In (3), `bar()` returns a reference so there are no rvalues.

In (4), the temporary `std::string` object implicitly created from the string literal is an rvalue.

In (5), the temporary `X` object is an rvalue, so therefore so is the `s` member.

Expressions such as `x+3` typically result in a temporary, which is thus an rvalue. However, if operator overloading has been used to change the return type to a reference, then the result is an lvalue.

Answer (score 2):

**Rvalue & Lvalue**

Before Explaining This two notation let's Check what is Called **Movable** and **Identity**

**Identity**:- In short anything that has name & we can point to or Reference to know that whether it is same value or Different Value

**Moving**:- In short anything whose content can be moved from one place or Memory to Other

**Lvalue** are those value that has Identity so we can point to it or Reference it, but cannot Move it These are called Classical Values

**Rvalue** are one that are movable (whether has identity or not) these contains temporary values or ADT that support move