# using std::swap instead of assignment with '=' operator

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, swap

I was going over some C++ source code [from a library](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/blob/devel/src/api/c/data.cpp#L261) related to a pet-project I'm working on and encountered something I don't understand. In a place where I expected a pointer dereference followed by assignment, the library authors use `std::swap()` near the end of the function to write the result:

`std::swap(*out, result);`

I expected to see something like this:

`*out = result;`

Note that `result` is a `typedef` of `size_t` and `out` is a pointer to that same type.

When it comes to "systems programming", my background is in C and C# but not much at all in C++. Is there any particular reason for this type of "assignment"?

Comment: If the value `result` is *not* used after the swap, the `std::move` may be a better choice. Also see [What exactly is a R-Value in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9406121/608639).

Comment: @jww, `result` isn't used after the call to `std::swap`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the value types are more interesting, say, a `std::vector<T>`, for example, it may make more sense to `std::swap()` a temporarily constructed object into place rather than assigning it: given that the temporary result is about to go away, avoiding an assignment and just changing pointers makes some sense. I don't see any reason to do something like that with fundamental types like `std::size_t`, though.

Comment: **+1** for the concise answer. Or, in C++11, can use move semantics to get rid of the assignment. I'd point out that the `swap` construction is frequently seen in the copy-and-swap idiom http://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/3093378, when you want to make sure you're not leaving objects in undefined states whenever you copy them due to exception throwing.