# lvalue required as increment operand error when using #define

Tags: c++

Whats the problem with the code below, and why I'm getting this error?

```
#include <iostream>
#define A 1
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout <<A++; 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout <<A++;` in your example, is equivalent to `cout <<1++; ` Do you see a problem in such statement?

Comment: Make `A` an actual int variable and then you will be able to increment it. The value 1 is an [rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406121/what-exactly-is-an-r-value-in-c) and cannot be changed. Also [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define A 1
```

A is not valid c++ left value, so gave us `"lvalue required as increment operand"`

```
int A;
```

is valid c++ left value and will work, also of other simple number type float, unsigned char etc

Answer (score 3):

`#define A 1` doesn't make a variable called `A`.

It tells your computer to replace all utterances of `A` with `1` before compiling.

So, your program is actually:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout <<1++; 
   return 0;
}
```

And you cannot increment the literal `1`.

You may read more about preprocessor directives in [your C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648).