# How can I return a local created object in C++?

Tags: c++

I am Trying to make an overload in "+" operator. The problem is I have to create a brand new object that will contain the sum, but when I try to return it, it gets deleted.(I think its because the object is locally created, so the system makes a shallow copy, and when it gets out of scope its content is deleted) How can I avoid it getting deleted?

The operator overload

```
Thing Thing::operator+(const Thing& thing){
Thing sum;
sum.attribute=this->attribute+thing.attribute;
sum.things= new int[sum.attribute];
static int k=0;
for(int i=0;i<this->attribute;i++){
    std::cout<<this->things[i];
    sum.things[k]=this->things[i];
}
for(int j=0;j<thing.attribute;j++){
    std::cout<<thing.things[j];
    sum.things[k]=thing.things[j];
}
return sum;}
```

The main

```
int main(){
    Thing one(1,1);
    Thing two(2,2);
    Thing three;
    three = one+two;
    std::cout<<"One"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<one.getAttribute()<<std::endl;
    one.showVec();
    std::cout<<"Two"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<two.getAttribute()<<std::endl;
    two.showVec();
    std::cout<<"Three"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<three.getAttribute()<<std::endl;
    three.showVec();
```

Copy constructor

```
Thing::Thing(const Thing& stuff){
    std::cout<<"Copy"<<std::endl;
    this->attribute=stuff.attribute;
    this->things = new int[this->attribute];
    for(int i =0;i<attribute;i++)
        this->things[i]=stuff.things[i];
    
}
```

The class

```
class Thing {
    private:
        int attribute;
        int* things;
    public:
        //constructors
        Thing(int=0,int=0);
        Thing(const Thing&);
        //destructor
        ~Thing();
        //operators
        Thing operator+(const Thing&);
        //getters
        int getAttribute();
        //functions
        void showVec();

};
```

My output

Default

Default

Default

Default

122Destructor

One

1

1

Two

2

2 2

Three

3

17002888 16974016 0 (The problem is here)

Destructor

Destructor

Destructor

Comment: In the first section of code, you are not incrementing `k`. (This is why your `three` array contains garbage after the first element.) Also, why is it `static`? You have not included the implementations of your constructor and destructor, so it's hard to say what else may be wrong.

Comment: A function always returns an [rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406121/what-exactly-is-an-r-value-in-c), which gets [move-assigned](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) to `three`, and then it is deleted. This is perfectly normal and nothing to worry about. To avoid your pointer being deleted, you overload the move assignment operator to prepare for this.

Comment: You are using the compiler-generated copy assignment operator, which is almost certainly not what you want. This operator will copy the pointer `things`, not the array to which it points. So, after `three = one + two`, the pointer `three.things` is a copy of the pointer `temp.things`, where by `temp` I mean the unnamed object returned by `one + two`. When `temp` is destroyed, its destructor presumably destroys the array `temp.things` was pointing to. Since `three.things` was pointing to that same array, it now points to garbage.

Comment: You haven't followed the rule of three as you have not defined a copy assignment operator.

Comment: Alternatively, use `std::vector<int>` and follow the rule of zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object returned by a function will *always* be an [rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406121/what-exactly-is-an-r-value-in-c). This object will be deleted when it goes out of use, which is usualy immediately. Your expression `three = one + two` takes that returned rvalue, and [move-assigns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) it to `three`. After that, the rvalue is deleted.

The problem with your code is that the rvalue deletes its pointer when its destructor is called, and because you have not overloaded the move assignment, it is shallow-copied to `three`. That results in `three` holding an invalid pointer.

To avoid this problem, simply overload the move assignment (and eventually other operators that are needed, like the move constructor) to reflect this.

```
Thing& Thing::operator=(Thing&& rvalue) {
    if(things) { delete things; things = nullptr } // delete pointer if any (it would otherwise get overwritten and leak)
    attribute = rvalue.attribute;
    things = rvalue.things;
    rvalue.things = nullptr; // zero rvalue's pointer so that the object cannot delete it
}

Thing::~Thing() {
    if(things) { delete things; } // first make sure the pointer is there
}
```