# Why r-value is not copied, when it passed to function by value?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl; }
    Foo(Foo&&) noexcept { std::cout << "Move" << std::endl; }
};

struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo foo) : foo(std::move(foo)) {}
    Foo foo;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << "Pass l-value:" << std::endl;
    Bar barL(foo);
    std::cout << "Pass r-value:" << std::endl;
    Bar barR({});
}
```

It prints the following:

```
Pass l-value:
Copy
Move
Pass r-value:
Move
```

How compiler understands that it may not copy r-value?

Comment: It's a temporary.  It does not have a life outside of that function call.  No need to copy anything.

Comment: you need to understand what is r-value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406121/what-exactly-is-an-r-value-in-c

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. What output did you expect instead?

Comment: @TimRoberts There is no temporary. There is only a constructor parameter of type `Foo` and a member of the same type.

Comment: @user17732522 When the second `Bar` is constructed it is passed `{}` as an argument, which is a temporary (i.e., an `r-value`).

Comment: [Adding logging to the default constructor](https://ideone.com/rbyRj7) shows that in the 2nd case the `Foo` instance is default constructed as the parameter and then moved.

Comment: @JamesAdkison ["temporary"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) has a very specific meaning in C++, and `{}` does not initialize a temporary (it is an rvalue where `Foo foo` in `Bar::Bar(Foo foo)` is the result object). (This is C++17 only, before that the copy from a temporary prvalue might simply be elided)

Comment: @Artyer Even before C++17 `{}` is not an expression and should just directly initialize the function parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{}` in your second call isn't just an rvalue, it's a *p*rvalue: a *pure* rvalue.  Prvalues don't act like objects so much as they do instructions for initializing an object.  Prvalues only get *materialized* under certain circumstances.  Those being primarily when they're used to initialize an object or when bound to a reference.

So when you call `Bar barR({})`, there's no need to copy (or move) the prvalue that you passed in, because it never gets materialized.  Instead, the `{}` is used to directly initialize the `foo` parameter of `Bar`'s constructor.

---

Note: Everything I wrote in this answer is valid for C++17 and later.  Prior standards didn't have the prvalue materialization/mandatory copy elision rules yet.