# C++ error of passing the error by reference

Tags: c++

The following code:

```
void fin(int Arr[],int& N,int& k,int& i,int& sum,int& count){
    if(i==N){
        if(sum==k){
            count++;
        }
        return;
    }
    sum+=Arr[i];
    fin(Arr,N,k,i+1,sum,count);
    sum-=Arr[i];
    fin(Arr,N,k,i+1,sum,count);
}

int findSubArraySum(int Arr[], int N, int k)
{
    // code here
    int count=0;
    int i=0;
    int sum=0;
    fin(Arr,N,k,i,sum,count);
    return count;
}
```

Gives the following compilation error:

> prog.cpp: In member function void Solution::fin(int*, int&,
> int&, int&, int&, int&): prog.cpp:18:22: error:
> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type int& from an
> rvalue of type int          fin(Arr,N,k,i+1,sum,count);

Can anybody help to solve it ?

Comment: [What exactly is an R-Value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9406672)

Comment: You cannot pass expressions like `i+1` which is an R-value as a non-const `int&` (an L-value ref). In your case since you don't change `N`,`k` and `i`, you can actually pass them as `int const &`.

Comment: So how do i pass the value of i and count to be able to change in the above recusrion code?

Comment: One option is to increment `i`. For example: `fin(Arr, N, k , ++i, sum, count); sum -= Arr[i - 1]; fin(Arr, N, k, i, sum, count);` Or just don't make it a reference. There doesn't appear to be a need for a reference there.

Comment: how do I pass a variable from one function to another function and by passing it the value of that variable changes.In the above code i tried to pass count to fin function to update the count and then if after the whole code run i print the count variable value it should returned me the updated value.