# Should template parameter T be resolving to T& when a function takes argument of T&& and is passed an lvalue?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to get my head around perfect forwarding in C++, and so I've written the following quick and dirty bit of code to test this.

```
class CValue
{
public:

    CValue(int i) :
        m_i(i)
    {
        printf("Default constructor called!\r\n");
    }

    CValue(const CValue& src) :
        m_i(src.m_i)
    {
        printf("Copy constructor called!\r\n");
    }

    CValue(CValue&& src) :
        m_i(src.m_i)
    {
        printf("Move constructor called!\r\n");
    }

    CValue& operator=(const CValue& src)
    {
        m_i = src.m_i;
        printf("Copy assignment called!\r\n");
        return *this;
    }

    CValue& operator=(CValue&& src)
    {
        m_i = src.m_i;
        printf("Move assignment called!\r\n");
        return *this;
    }

    int     m_i;
};

template <typename T>
void PerfectForwarding(T&& tValue)
{
    T tValue1 = tValue;
    tValue1.m_i = 10;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CValue v(0);
    PerfectForwarding(v);

    printf("%d\r\n", v.m_i);

    return 0;
}
```

When I build and run this code as a console application I get the answer 10, when I was expecting 0.

It seems that the line:

```
T tValue1 = tValue;
```

in the PerfectForwarding function is being resolved to:

```
CValue& tValue1 = tValue;
```

instead of:

```
CValue tValue1 = tValue;
```

So the compiler is resolving T to be CValue&, which I didn't expect.

I tried invoking the function from _tmain by explicitly declaring the template parameter type, i.e.

```
PerfectForwarding<CValue>(v);
```

but this fails to compile with the following error:

```
error C2664: 'void PerfectForwarding<CValue>(T &&)' : cannot convert
              argument 1 from 'CValue' to 'CValue &&'
              with
              [
                  T=CValue
              ]
You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

I can force the desired behaviour through changing the line in the PerfectForwarding function to the following:

```
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type tValue1 = tValue;
```

but I didn't think this should be necessary. By the reference collapsing rules the type of the argument (T&&) should become CValue& (as T&& & -> T&), but T itself should be simply CValue, surely? Is this a bug in the VC12 compiler's handling of rvalue references, or am I misunderstanding something about rvalue references and templates?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (VC12 compiler) in debug with all optimisation turned off.

Comment: In the linked dupe, scan specifically for "universal" (or "forwarding") references.

Comment: @sehe, I think http://stackoverflow.com/q/14302849/3093378 is a much better match for the dupe, even in terms of its title. The question is not really about move semantics.

Comment: See [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) Items 1, 24 and 28 : _... it's the only situation in template type deduction where T is deduced to be a reference_

Comment: @jrok, Yes, sorry I was expecting the answer 0, not 4. I've edited the question to correct this.

Comment: @vsoftco That looks quite helpful too! You can add it (I think?) (_I don't think that particular one would end up in a natural query to explain the answer to this question this OP has, I think, but yeah it is more concise in scope_)

Comment: @sehe, don't have enough reputation to add it in OP's post as a possible dupe. Will add it in my answer though.

Comment: @vsoftco I see I can un-mjölnar these days :L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the compiler sees just `T&&` it's going to try to deduce `T` to something that allows the function to be called with whatever you're giving it.  So you wind up with `T` being `Cvalue&` when called with an lvalue so the reference collapsing (as you've pointed out) can kick in.

This matters when you try to forward the argument.  `std::forward<T>(v)` will either forward the argument as an lvalue or an rvalue depending on what `T` is.  If it has been deduced to an lvalue reference, it will forward it as an lvalue, if it hasn't, it will be forwarded as an rvalue.  The type `T` is the only thing that distinguishes.

*By the reference collapsing rules the type of the argument (T&&) should become CValue& (as T&& & -> T&), but T itself should be simply CValue, surely?* 
If called with an lvalue it goes `(T&& v)` "okay, I can't bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue, but if I make `T` itself be an lvalue reference then this works."  `T` is deduced to be `Cvalue&` so that `(T&& v)` expands to `(Cvalue& && v)`.  Now the reference is collapsed `(Cvalue& v)`.  The type `T` must be an lvalue-reference type for this to work.

If you provide the template parameter explicitly then you're not really addressing the issue.  The first way around this is the `remove_reference` as you've found.  You could also use `auto` which makes more sense since this is generic programming

```
auto tValue1 = tValue;
```

In any case, the `auto` won't deduce to a reference.  For what you've provided, you'd be better off using a `const` lvalue reference which can bind to both lvalues and rvalues.

```
template <typename T>
void PerfectForwarding(const T& tValue)
{
    T tValue1 = tValue;
    tValue1.m_i = 10;
}
```

this doesn't allow for forwarding, but it's not a forwarding function as-is anyway.

If you wanted to handle lvalues differently you could provide two overloads

```
template <typename T>
void PerfectForwarding(T& tValue);

template <typename T>
void PerfectForwarding(T&& tValue);
```

When called with an lvalue, the former will be preferred.

Comment: Though it should be mentioned that `auto&&` is the perfect forwarding version of `auto`!

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: Then what's `decltype(auto)` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt whatever the rhs was declared to be.

Comment: @BenVoigt `auto` deduces the type of expression by the rules of template-argument deduction and `decltype(auto)` deduces through `decltype()`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Yes.... and isn't `decltype(auto)`, not `auto&&`, the perfect forwarding version of `auto`?

Comment: @BenVoigt `auto&&` will always bind a reference. but something like `int a; decltype(auto) b = a;` will not, because `a` is declared as an `int`, not a reference

Comment: @RyanHaining: Exactly, `auto&&` isn't perfect forwarding because it doesn't preserve the value category, it forces everything to be a reference.

Comment: @BenVoigt in the case of forwarding, isn't it really all about getting the right kind of reference to the object?  A forwarding function always binds a reference, it doesn't only bind in the case that the argument to the function was declared as a reference.

Comment: @BenVoigt "it forces everything to be a reference" - which is precisely what perfect forwarding does in functions. Depends on your exact definition of the vague term "perferct forwarding version of `auto`," I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is correct. Perfect forwarding is implemented by deducing an lvalue reference for the type when the argument is an lvalue.

You're saying

> By the reference collapsing rules the type of the argument (`T&&`) should become `CValue&` (as `T&& &` -> `T&`), but `T` itself should be simply `CValue`, surely?

But where would the `&` in `T&& &` come from if `T` was just `CValue`? The entire reason why `T&&` works as a forwarding reference is that the `T` becomes an lvalue reference, `CValue&` in your case, and then reference collapsing gets `T &&` -> `CValue & &&` -> `CValue &`.

The relevant section of the standard is C++11 14.8.2.1/3 (`P` is the function template parameter type and `A` s the type of the argument in the call, defined in 14.8.2.1/1):

> If `P` is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of `P`’s type are ignored for type deduction. If `P` is a
>   reference type, the type referred to by `P` is used for type deduction. **If `P` is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified
>   template parameter and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to `A`” is used in
>   place of `A` for type deduction.**

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does the right thing. In a line like

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param){}
```

`T` is being deduced as reference if you pass a lvalue, and a simple type if you pass a rvalue. So `int x; f(x);` deduces `T` as `int&`, and `f(1)` deduces `T` as `int`.

That's how perfect forwarding works. Basically, you have the following rules for reference collapsing:

```
& &   -> &
& &&  -> &
&& &  -> &
&& && -> &&
```

See also

[Syntax for universal references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14302849/3093378)

for more details.