# C++, rvalue references in function parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to understand `rvalue` references. I have seen how they are used in constructors, with things like `std::move` and `std::forward`, but I still don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
void func(string&& str)
{
    cout << str << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string s("string");
    func(s);
}
```

And this does:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T&& str)
{
    cout << str << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string s("string");
    func(s);
}
```

Why does it work with the function template version?

Comment: The latter version works because `T` is deduced to be `string&`. "When the function parameter type is of the form T&& where T is a template parameter, and the function argument is an lvalue of type A, the type A& is used for template argument deduction." Use `std::move` if you want the former to work.

Comment: This is a special case of template deduction, here (and only here AFAIK), `T` can be deduced to a reference type. Normally in template type deduction `T` is only deduced as a non-reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax for universal references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302849/syntax-for-universal-references)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like @Peter said, the type of `T` is deduced as `string&`, and C++’s reference-collapsing rule says:

> T& & ⇒ T& // from C++98
>   T&& & ⇒ T& // new for C++0x
>   T& && ⇒ T& // new for C++0x
>   T&& && ⇒ T&& // new for C++0x

So `func`’s instantiation is actually:

```
void func(string& str)
```

And it works.

Answer (score 6):

Some formal explanation in addition to @songyuanyao's answer:

`N4296::14.8.2.1 [temp.deduct.call]`:

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function
>   template parameter type (call it P) with the type of the corresponding
>   argument of the call (call it A) as described below.

`N4296::14.8.2.1/3 [temp.deduct.call]`:

> A *forwarding reference* is
>   an **rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter**. If P is a
>   forwarding reference and **the argument is an lvalue**, the type “lvalue
>   reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

The Standard also provides the following example:

```
template <class T> int f(T&& heisenreference);
template <class T> int g(const T&&);
int i;
int n1 = f(i); // calls f<int&>(int&)
int n2 = f(0); // calls f<int>(int&&)
int n3 = g(i); // error: would call g<int>(const int&&)
```

That's exactly your case.

Answer (score 1):

Because inside of a template `&&` has a different meaning, it's called **universal reference**.

a template function with a `&&` parameter (unversal reference) means the parmeter can be used as reference or rvalue-reference.

In your case the template is deduced as `string&` and that's why it works.

To work with the raw function you have to do this:

```
void func(string&& str)
{
    cout << str << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string s("string");
    func(std::move(s)); // move the string
    func(std::string("string")); // this is an rvalue and it is fine
}
```

A complete explanation about universal references can be found here:
https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers